# Where are the non-trivial PHP-questions lately?

Tags: discussion

When I look at the first page of open PHP questions, I find almost only bad questions. E.g. one person doesn't understand what a "Notice" error message is, and wants it to be fixed. Most questions have poor indentation. Posters don't seem to be motivated to proofread their own questions even once. They are asking poor write-me-the-code questions that are so trivial that you are wondering if these people will ever be able to make money by working as a programmer. (Like "how do I write a function that multiplies its input by two, but only if it is smaller than 95". These kind of "questions" are usually missing the question mark ("?"), because they really are no questions. Or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329285/function-to-output-something-if-date-is-between). Or using `file_get_contents` on a URL on the same webserver instead of just calling a proper function to get a value.) These questions are not the exception but the norm. There are almost no good questions.

Sorry for ranting...

I have a feeling that PHP questions should be flagged *by default*, and only un-flagged if there is approval from someone who can prove that he is able to get basic stuff done in the language. Well... I will probably stop answering PHP questions until this changes. When I have a question, I normally use Google and I find an answer. In the future I will probably use this site more for asking than for answering, at least regarding PHP.

Comment: I almost had to clean my monitor after reading the first sentence of the last paragraph.

Comment: I don't agree with the question needing to be flagged by default. They should be closed by default.

Comment: Maybe this explains a few things: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-php-singularity/.  In case you've missed it, the [PHP Tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) is a gold mine; a substantial percentage of questions asked in the PHP tag on a regular basis could probably be closed as duplicates of some question found in the "frequently asked questions" section of the Tag Wiki.

Comment: You don't have enough answers under your belt to post this.

Comment: I think that this problem isn't only existent in the php tag. There's too much to rant about this. Think about students that don't have an idea what they are doing, [developers by chance not by choice](http://whyjava.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/reasons-for-incompetent-software-developers-in-india/) or [helpvampires that got this far](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) by sucking blood from good developers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [Room 11](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) is trying hard to kill new duplicates or plainly said, remove crappy questions/answers, but unfortunately the force is weak compared to influx of aformentioned. Partially, it's Stackoverflow fault because it enables such behavior.

Comment: @TOOTSKI: I especially like the 9-star comment made by tereško in Room 11.  Is he a regular, or does he just like to shop for bicycles in a PHP store? :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, he's room owner too and he hates you. [Your](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=8480#8480) [argument](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=955054#955054) [is](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=2318227#2318227) [not](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=2320389#2320389) [valid](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=11267478#11267478).

Comment: The problem isn't *limited* to PHP, @HamZa... But I suspect they do get a bit more than their fair share of it.

Comment: Your highest voted answer is 3. Your average answer score is 0.6 over 37 answers... You can't say this.

Comment: @Will I know you're joking, but there's nothing you can't do in PHP.

Comment: [webcache for a 404 question in the first paragraph](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F23329285%2Ffunction-to-output-something-if-date-is-between&rlz=1C1CHMO_enIE525IE525&oq=cache%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F23329285%2Ffunction-to-output-something-if-date-is-between&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.854j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1)

Comment: Is this question of any better quality?  What is the question here?  The title is a rhetorical question, and the body as you admit is a rant is kind of difficult to provide a conical answer to...

Comment: @AaronLS s/conical/canonical/

Comment: @muistooshort How do you know I didn't mean "cone shaped answer"? ;) Good catch thx.

Comment: @AaronLS Would a hyperbolic, parabolic, elliptical, or circular answer apply? I can come up with a hyperbolic answer for anything :)

Comment: Sadly, these questions give a bad name to all the good PHP developers out there... all 3 of us.

Comment: and I want to say that PHP is not such a bad language, after all. i recently read that codinghorror article referenced above, and also the "fractal of bad design" article that is referenced there. it's true, that as a language, PHP is awful. intransitive comparison operators, left-associative ternery comparison operator, inconsistent and inflexible error handling, and what else. but: it is really easy to learn. it is really easy to get started. the documentation is awesome. most language documentation is crap compared to the PHP docs.

Comment: you can get a webhosting plan in PHP very easily and you will know how it will behave. it is usually bundled with MySQL and Linux. There is a standard software stack, and there are many open source packages that are really easy to install. also, you cannot easily translate a PHP-script that I write in 5min into a Tomcat-Servlet-App or ruby-on-rails-app. so, whoever wants PHP to go away has to create a new language that is similarily accessible and easy to learn, yet at the same time, *better*. As long as this doesn't happen, PHP will stay. And I will probably continue to use it occasionally.

Comment: @Jhawins I think its save to say that the reputation system is broken. Or do you want to explain to my, for example, why [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18184831/754705) gets 388 reputation, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23387715/754705) gets only 1 point? the first link is an easy answer on an easy question (no offence), the second one required some experimental research. I could find 100 such examples if I wanted to

Comment: @Michael those are simply edge cases. Be mature.

Comment: no, these are not "edge cases". simple questions will simply produce more traffic.

Comment: @HamZa your comment about "students who don't know what they're doing" got me thinking--is it just the time of year when students have class projects coming due?  Could that possibly be a cause of an upward spike in trivial questions?

Comment: @Jhawins He can say whatever he likes, mate.

Comment: @ajb Our current education system is flawed, at least the ones I've seen. I'm a student myself, there's so many things I've seen that are wrong. So for example, I've now got 4 projects simultaneously going on: a wordpress site (html, css, php); a website using nodejs, bootstrap, angularjs, mongodb; an iphone&android app with a website backend and a project where I need to simulate something with C and Java. I've got a couple of months to do all this besides my "regular" stuff. Now if we count the languages and technologies that I need to learn in this time it would be around 15.

Comment: I'm luckily a self taught developer so I already know some of the languages and I could easily dabble in others. But what about those students that have never programmed before, just a year of Java/C that they have learned at school and maybe some basic php/mysql that they used in a project. They are basically doomed, they aren't thinking about "best practices" or "security", they are just thinking about "how can I get it done?". So code is mangled together from here and there, vulnerabilities everywhere, horrible code and on top of that it gets approved.

Comment: So my fancy code that I wrote isn't really appreciated, it's cool, I get some points extra but I could just have done the same and honestly, with the current deadlines I might write crappy code as well.
So to resume, these students are lost, they don't have any basics, they are thrown into real projects that are too difficult for them and they are just thinking about getting it done as fast as possible no matter what. Oh and sometimes the teachers don't even know what they are doing... I could rant more about what I've seen, but I think that would be off-topic here...

Comment: @ajb I notice that it's usually the first couples weeks of the term, when they're absolutely lost with their first assignments (fair enough). And then the last couple weeks of the term, when they're still absolutely lost due to not doing any work during the term and hoping someone will finish the questions for them.

Comment: @Will, "When has PHP ever been used for non trivial tasks?". Sadly, often, e.g. Facebook.

Comment: Have you ever been to java-land? I feel like stackoverflow is 99% NPE-questions.

Comment: @Michael `NullPointerException`. Sry, that wasn't very clear :)

Comment: @Michael Stop by the vba tag sometime. I feel your pain.

Comment: The flagging by default seems aggressive but i agree a lot of bad programmers are asking stupid googlable Q's that can be solved by just checking some php docs or something but that's what the downvote is for and we can just close the q if its stupid. even if its stupid maybe this person just needs to be told to google cuz that will help them understand that next time they should google first then ask ~ this is just my opinion

Answer (score 62, accepted):

See also: "[Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/168868)", and [this specific answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/168868).  I'm a type 1 / type 4 hybrid, and it sounds like you're getting there as well.

Some of the problems you cite are not specific to [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php).  If you want to be truly frightened, take a peek at [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) mornings GMT.  The bad questions in [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) make me sad, but the bad questions in [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) make me *rage*.  I don't have enough closevotes to make it through the latest 100 questions...

Some of the problems you cite are not specific to Stack Overflow.  This has all happened before ... and will happen again.  The internet calls it [Eternal September](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September).  We're already shoving the community guidelines down people's throats and they still don't get it.  They're beyond any structured help.

Some of the problems you cite are [specific to a particular breed of programmer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217984/135887).  Again, they're beyond any structured help.

Some of the problems you cite are not specific to PHP.  All languages have newbies that ask stupid questions.

Some of the problems you cite are not specific to PHP developers.  All new programmers ask stupid questions and most don't know how to search and research.

It just happens that PHP has such an incredibly low barrier to entry that it attracts people both new to the language and new to programming.  This can make it *seem* like a huge number of the questions are mind-blowingly basic.  Becoming competent at PHP seems to also correspond to figuring out how to Google.  Correlation is not causation, mind you.

So, where are the good questions?  You can often find interesting ones under framework and library tags.  Advanced, complex modern libraries.  Like, *not* Cake or CodeIgniter.  Or Laravel, but I'm a snob.  Notice that sometimes they aren't tagged [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)!  This happens a lot.  Maybe they're embarrassed?

Sometimes these advanced questions aren't actually even on Stack Overflow.  By the time you're building an n-tier framework-leveraging enterprise-grade PHP application with all that this entails, you aren't going to be asking *PHP* questions that fit on SO any longer.  I have a draft in progress (that I probably won't post) that I can only fit in to [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) because it deals with software architectural concepts that will lead to opinion-based or experience-based answers instead of concrete facts.  Hell, it might even be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

The bottom line, though, is yes, there's a lot of crap, and no, that crap is never going away.  Use closevotes as needed and use downvotes with little discrimination.  PeeHaa was only serious about PHP questions needing to be closed *by default* nowadays.  **You might have only a limited number every day, but question downvotes are free and should be given out like candy.**

The citizens of [Room 11](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) have a [closevote recommendation system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120186/135887), if you'd like to come help filter the ocean of horrible questions using a hand-held water purifier...

Comment: Downvotes are free? You've only got 40 votes per day and they cost 1 rep per answer (free for questions though), whereas you have 50 close votes per day. But I never run out of votes, because by that time I would have run out of patience already.

Comment: We're not talking about answers though.

Comment: Hmm... it's been such a long time since I've *cared* enough to actually downvote **all the things**.. there *is* a limit, isn't there?

Comment: Same thing (or even worse) with [tag:vba], where people who never programmed ask you to write code.

Comment: Oh, I am running into my limit almost everyday. And half of votes are going into void, as Stack Overflow is full of kind-hearted nurses who are always ready to comfort a poor noobie. And I limit myself to a few sub-tags, mind you - almost never taking my foot onto raw [php].

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Lucky you, lol. If you were following the MySQL tag you'd be neck deep in the PHP slime. (And the Ruby on Rails and Django slimes are not much better on Postgres.) :-|

Comment: @Denis, I am not that lucky. Some time ago I've found myself a quiet refugee in mysqli tag - keeping me apart from many mysql questions... And then all of sudden treacherous PHP team decided to deprecate the old ext! Eventually directing all the sewage into my quiet backwater.

Comment: To summarize several of your points: PHP is effectively the new VB6. Many of the people that yesterday would have learned VB, today learn PHP. VB's half-hearted and broken objects system gives way to PHP's disorganized and poorly documented API.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Your `...And then all of sudden treacherous PHP team...` comment is the funniest and most spot-on thing I've read in a while.

Comment: @Denis I hear you on the Rails/PostgreSQL mess. Not only are most Rails people ignorant about databases but the culture encourages this ignorance. I tend to stay away from [tag:ruby-on-rails] these days to avoid the adolescent attitude. I suspect that soon we'll see thousands of "Rails is the new PHP" garbage apps kicking around, might be a good way to make money if you don't mind wearing a hazmat suit :)

Comment: It's just a matter of time before ElitistStackOverflow.com is up and running, where you need to have 10k rep to ask a question. Don't get me wrong, I'm all for it, once I get 10k rep.

Answer (score 23):

Yes. It happens once in a while.

The most funny fact is that **without a manually attached bounty a good question scarcely gets an answer at all** - the regular sewage flow is so fast, that good questions almost never have a chance to meet someone who can answer.

To me, *this* fact is a **foul shame** for a site that was intended for programmers but turned into online typo-spotting / trivial-code-writing service.

As of the general flow - don't forget *answers*: it is not uncommon, when a trivial question gets a half-dozen of answers, ALL of which are wrong. **Because of the same tolerant policy** - writing total rubbish costs you **nothing** but occasionally can bring some points from a fellow illiterate or a kind-hearted nurse. And even being forced to delete his answer, rep-whore keeps overall balance at zero.

---

The problem is that Stack Overflow has changed. And for a changed site one needs changed rules. There is always a balance between scarcity and abundance - one has to moderate them wisely, as the latter is no better than the former. When visitors are scarce, they have to be lured in with all the might. Yet, when they are overflowing, there should be some moderation.

Old man Parkinson once discovered that principle in his truly brilliant article "THE SHORT LIST, OR PRINCIPLES OF SELECTION", where he clearly shows how a position has to be **equally fitted with baits and spikes.**

I'll take the liberty to cite

> Wanted-- Acrobat capable of crossing a slack wire 200 feet above raging
>   furnace.  Twice  nightly,  three  times  on  Saturday.  53   Salary  offered
>   £25 (or $70 U.S.) per week. No pension  and  no compensation in the
>   event of injury. Apply  in person at  Wildcat Circus between the hours  of 9
>   A.M. and 10 A.M.
>
> The wording  of this may not be  perfect but  the aim should  be so  to
>   balance the inducement in  salary  against  the possible risks involved that
>   only  a single  applicant  will appear. It is needless to ask for details of
>   qualifications and experience. No one unskilled on the slack wire would find
>   the  offer attractive. It  is needless to  insist that  candidates should be
>   physically fit, sober,  and free from fits of  dizziness. They know that. It
>   is just  as needless to stipulate  that those nervous  of heights  need  not
>   apply.  They won't. The  skill  of the advertiser consists in adjusting  the
>   salary to the danger. An offer of £1000 (or $3000 U.S.) per week
>   might produce  a dozen applicants. An offer of £15 (or $35 U.S.)
>   might  produce none. Somewhere between those two  figures lies the exact sum
>   to  specify, the minimum figure to  attract anyone actually capable of doing
>   the job. If there is more than one applicant,  the  figure has been placed a
>   trifle too high.
>
> Let us now take, for comparison, a less extreme example.
>
> Wanted-- An archaeologist with high academic qualifications willing to spend
>   fifteen  years in  excavating the Inca tombs  at Helsdump on  the  Alligator
>   River. Knighthood or equivalent honor guaranteed. Pension payable but  never
>   yet  claimed.  Salary of £2000 (or $6000 U.S.) per year. Apply in
>   triplicate to the  Director of the Grubbenburrow Institute,  Sickdale, Ill.,
>   U.S.A.
>
> Here the advantages and drawbacks are neatly balanced. There is no need to  insist that candidates must be patient, 54  tough, intrepid, and single. The terms  of  the advertisement  have eliminated  all who  are  not.

I hope you get the idea.

**The same principle should be applied to the modern SO.**

1. First, number of baits can be reduced. Believe me, there are many people who are willing to share their knowledge just for sake of it, not for rep points or badges.
2. Second, number and size of spikes can be enraged. Say, current ratio 1:5 is embarrassing. Especially taking into account comforting upvotes (or solidarity ones, when two illiterates, got downvoted for their wild guess answers missing the point by a mile, happily upvoting each other). A comforting upvote will reward one fivefold! I'd make ratio 1:2.
   Incidentally, why not to make **an upvote** to cost at least a penny? It will make all the repwhores think twice before spending!

There are could be other measures. But it's no use to sit and devise them, unless some political will to the change will be shown.

Beside other benefits, it will give back value to the SO reputation, which has devaluated into soil.

Comment: Could you explain how that principle should be applied to SO?  Not sure I quite follow what you mean.

Comment: okay added some.

Comment: +1 for "without a manually attached bounty a good question scarcely gets an answer at all." Good questions become tumbleweeds.

Answer (score 21):

Downvote them... Seriously. You've 50 votes per day; use them to downvote 50 questions.

The "demonstrate a minimal understanding" close reason is no more, and the powers that be said "downvote" instead. So downvote.

Invite other PHP devs to do the same. With enough perseverance, people who should never have begun a profession in programming to begin with might stop asking. If not, at the very least you'll see giant walls of downvoted questions which you can ignore.

Comment: -1 for the imaginary practice. It doesn't work in real Stack Overflow for a multitude reasons

Comment: Any reference for *"the powers that be said "downvote" instead"*? I'd have guessed that *"This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem**. Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.*" could be used instead.

Comment: Well, it could work if we actually followed the advice you've just downvoted @YourCommonSense. So the advice itself doesn't really deserve a downvote. The fact that it's not applied in practice does ... but we can't (yet) downvote such general notions.

Comment: @Arjan: see discussions and comments related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215596 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211080 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216585

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Then again I'm not implying I believe it would work, hehe. But seeing the reactions I got when I actually cared much (e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178234), I'm at a loss as to what to hope for.

Comment: @dallin: I fail to see the point you're trying to make, then, if you don't wish them to post here either. When you post a question, you research it before showing up asking what you've missed -- and it shows. Contrast these questions with the smelly sewage spewed by random incompetents on the PHP tag and elsewhere. The part that makes *me* cringe is how many of those inept coders are actually working as programmers. Because I'm later tasked by clients with cleaning up the puke they left behind.

Comment: @Denis "inept coders with an IQ no larger than a shoe-size"? My point is you do not know their IQ, their proficiency, their area of focus, their circumstances, or anything. You don't know what they are trying to achieve. You don't know how long they've tried to learn programming. I understand you're frustrated with their questions that don't belong here, but telling people they should not try to become a programmer or that they're too stupid to without even knowing them is not an attitude we should have.

Comment: @dallin: I think we'll have to agree to disagree for now, and revisit this chat in a few years after you've dealt with your fair share of stinky code bases left behind by incompetent subcontractors.

Comment: @Denis lol, I agree to disagree as well. As a side note, I have dealt with a lot of incompetent code left by learning programmers and understand why it frustrates you.

Comment: @dallin; It has nothing to do with skill level. Beginners, by definition, have a low skill level. It has everything to do with *willingness* to learn and improve, as opposed to just dumping questions on us.

Answer (score 8):

Lack of administration will undoubtedly lead to more stupid questions.  Though it may feel wasted at the time, scorning people for bad questions will likely lead to a more refined question that abides by the criteria further down the road.  You just may not be there to witness it and see the result of your effort.

That's how SE started for me.  I discovered the site, asked a really dumb question, and people yelled at me for it.  You could probably see my inquisitions get better and more concise over the next 2 years.  Being scolded really made me feel like an idiot and drove me to want to be better.

Comment: I think that "scorning people for bad questions" is not really the right solution. It doesn't solve the problem because there is an endless supply of people with bad questions. I think we need to find ways to do a better job at stopping people from asking the bad questions before they do.

Answer (score 5):

Smart people who started using PHP have outgrown it, and are asking good questions about other languages and web frameworks instead.  Leaving just the people who don't know any better to stumble their way around PHP.

Comment: That's right, I don't think very highly of PHP.

Comment: [You're not alone.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-php-singularity/)

Answer (score 5):

Trivial questions get pounced upon, like a piranha feeding frenzy. Or downvoted/closed, before you can even type "Google it". If all that bothers you, stop looking at the recent questions page! Bookmark these instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50

Or if those are *too* hard, then try these: (a question has to survive a couple of days to have a bounty, so they should be worth reading)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=featured&pageSize=50

Answer (score -12):

I'm amazed by the fact that everyone just blindly agrees with this statement. And answers such as downvote everything, and close all by default have the majority's support.
I agree with the fact that a question should show sufficient effort of research trough use of Google at least. 
What I don't understand is why you doubt someone would make a living just because they lack knowledge of PHP. The person might not be interested in a career as a backend programmer but just needs help with a small partion of his/her webpage that requires PHP or some other language they never completely mastered.
Perhaps the person asking the question is a hybrid webdesigner/frontend developer. Do you expect them to hire a PHP developer for every trivial problem they run in to?

So, to summerize. I agree that questions that show lack of effort are to be downvoted, however when the OP takes the time to edit the question, remove your downvote accordingly.

Also, if the question shows effort but the OP does not seem to have the correct knowledge of terminoligy, try pointing them in the right direction with hints trough comment like: "Try Googling *random term*".

A little less negativity and a little more patience would help this community a great deal.

Just my two cents.

Comment: "Do you expect them to hire a PHP developer for every trivial problem they run in to?" No but we expect them to put in some minimal amount of effort before they post a new (duplicate/incomprehensible) question

Comment: If people aren't actually programmers then *this site is not for them*.  This is a site specifically created for *professional and enthusiast programmers*.  It is not a site for people who don't want to learn how to program to have programmers search Google for them.  If people can't even be bothered to do a minimum amount of research before asking a question, such as sticking their question into a search engine, then this site is, again, not for them.  The site expects question authors to have done some research.  If they are unwilling to do so, their questions don't belong here.

Comment: It is people like you who are encouraging these users that *the site has made very clear do not belong here* that is the cause of this problem here.  By encouraging people asking bad questions, they ask more bad questions.  That is *really* bad for the site.

Comment: Many a SO veteran wishes, as can be seen from the recent meta post related to SO negativity, that users hire a developer instead of posting questions like http://stackoverflow.com/q/17403265

Comment: the problem with stupid questions is that they do repell the "experts". and as soon as the noobs succeed in repelling the "experts", this site will become useless, because it then will be a site where noobs give advice to noobs. and by "expert" I mean everyone but the noobs, you know, people who understand the difference between a global variable, a local variable and an instance variable. a real expert (without quotes) will probably leave much earlier.

Comment: @Servy "the site has made very clear do not belong here" - and this is why a lot of experienced developers don't want to participate here anymore. Some people want SO to be some sort of exclusive club. Their motivation is something other than "helping people" - particularly those who close questions as "too specific". It's like a doctor saying too few people have this disease to be worth my while trying to find a cure.

Comment: How do you know they didn't Google it first? SO factors in the first 5 spots on Google more often than not for any programming question I ask. I would assume most/all newbies found SO by searching for their problem on Google. After getting to SO, they looked around, couldn't find their answer so they did what seemed logical... they posted a question.

Comment: @alcalde So it seems you're *not* familiar with the mission of this site, to which the founders have made quite clear.  It's *not* a place where someone goes to ask a question and have someone help them, to which some useless artifact is left around.  That's what the site's competition was for decades, and the SO founders were tired of it.  Rather than having the same questions asked day in day out, they wanted place to create a *repository of knowledge* in which each question creates an artifact for future visitors.  *That is why this site exists*.

Comment: @alcalde To stick with your analogy, consider SO the equivalent of a research hospital.  It's *not* here to just help the handful of people that can pass through its doors each day; its goal is to benefit the entire community through expanded knowledge.  There are non-research clinics where people can go for individualized care.  In the same vein; if someone wants personalized help with a problem that's *just for them*, then there are places for that.  SO isn't one of them.

Comment: @Servy, and because this repository has such great depth, it is the first place they'll come from a Google search.

Comment: @davidethell When I can take the title of a question, stick it into google, and get an answer to the question, I can be fairly confident that the OP did not do sufficient research before asking their question.  As one moves further along between obvious cases like that, and harder cases where I can only find the question because I happened to have already known the "magic words" to find it, there is a grey area.  There certainly is a degree of subjectivity as to what level of research is to be expected, and whether a given question meets that criteria.

Comment: @davidethell Okay.  Fine.  If they can find an answer from another SO question, great, if they can't they should still look elsewhere.  After all, SO is not a replacement for documentation, tutorials, etc.

Comment: @Servy, why post if not for personalized help? The only questions I've posted were because I was stuck on a personal problem. I didn't necessarily care if the problem was going to help N number of programmers down the road. I posted a question, hopefully well-formed, and almost always have gotten great answers. I'm sure several of my questions are edge cases or were fairly minor once the problem came to light.

Comment: @Servy, ok, I'll grant you those last two comments. I do agree that posting on SO should be after exhausting as many other options as possible. More Google searching is usually the better solution most of the time.

Comment: @davidethell Whether someone comes here for personalized help isn't really the issue. The whole design of the site is that someone comes here for personalized help, they get it, but in the process a useful and high quality artifact is created for future googlers. If the question is one that cannot, or probably will not, generate such an artifact, then it should be downvoted/closed.  The motivations of the asker aren't the issue here, but whether or not the question is of sufficient quality to be useful. Ironically, most questions people ask intending to create useful artifacts are low quality.

Comment: @Servy I think you've just hit the head on the nail about the problem.  Stack Overflow is NOT for non-programmers and NOT for newbie questions, but that's not communicated well to people currently.

Comment: @user25312 I hope this experience hasn't put you off from Stack Overflow. I had posts like these that got downvoted and attacked when I started. In all reality, there's an element of truth to what you say - Stack Overflow is too negative right now: http://goo.gl/3bPWZ8. The problem lies in a difference between what the founders are trying to achieve and the reality of having a popular and open site anyone can post to. A lot of people are bitter right now about the incredible number of poor questions that don't fit the site's goals, so they have a negative reaction like you noted.

Comment: @dalin not really, I was expecting these kind of replies. Just wanted to add my unpopulair opinion on the subject.

Comment: @dallin It's not that SO isn't for beginner questions.  The *difficulty* of a question is not an issue at all as to whether or not the question is welcome.  It's all about the quality of the question, how clear and understndable it is, and whether or not it can be solved through a reasonable amount of research.  Most basic questions can already be solved through simple research, but certainly not all.  Those that are basic questions to an expert, but that don't have discoverable solutions, are entirely welcome on the site.  Of course, once answered, it *becomes* a discoverable solution.