# Asking questions privilege should be severely limited for new users

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users

Inspired by recent hugely popular questions (mostly [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late), also [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow), [Where are the non-trivial PHP-questions lately?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252443/where-are-the-non-trivial-php-questions-lately?cb=1)), I think that the number of questions new users or users with bad questions history can ask should be severly limited.

A new user should start with a low number of questions allowed, let's say a quota of 2 questions per week. As their reputation gets higher, they should receive more questions quota. For example, 1 more question per week at 10 rep, 1 more at 25 rep and so on until they get to the current limit. They should get there at a relatively high rep, maybe 3,000 would be a good level.

This question quota should be visible to the user on their page to remind them that asking questions is a scarce resource that should be treated with respect.

In addition to the limit based on reputation, community should have a say and modify users' quotas. Receiving a negative score of -3 or less (i.e. even more negative score) would reduce the weekly quota by 1. There should be some limit so that the quota cannot become zero but it should be low, e.g. 1 question per 2 weeks. There should also be a notification to the user that their quota has been reduced to let them know that asking poor questions is not welcome. Receiving upvotes that bring the score to -2 or more on a bad question would remove the penalty.

The other way to get rid of this negative modifier would be to ask a good question. The score required to cancel one bad question would be an equal positive score on a different question, e.g. to cancel a modifier of -1 on a question with the score of -5 a user would need to receive a score of +5 on a different question.

All the numbers given above are less important than the idea and can be discussed/changed. My main point is that asking questions should be regarded as a scarce resource and users should learn to use it with caution.

Last thing: I'm posting it on SO Meta as the situation is worst here, I understand. This solutions can be applied to all sites though.

Comment: If the problem you're trying to solve is question quality on the front page, this won't accomplish that.  We are inundated by a small number of low-quality questions from many new users, not several low quality questions from a small number of users.  Users who persistently ask low-quality questions get question-banned pretty quickly anyway.

Comment: I agree with Robert. I also think that this is similar to an approach Shog9 was considering with potentially making the post ban more strict (as in faster acting) - but without the throttling by rep.

Comment: I'm trying to improve the situation. Solving this problem will take more than one measure, I think, and a number of improvements targeting different (but related) behaviours is needed.

Comment: That, I suspect, is the $64K question, @Robert: without a significant portion of these questions coming from folks who *come back*, there's no opportunity to teach, there's no opportunity to restrict those who won't *learn*, and there's really no *good* solution - we're left just throwing up blind barriers and hoping they block more bad than good. FWIW: 769K questions on SO during the past year from 460K users who've never asked a question scoring more than 0.

Comment: see, the real problem is that people who occasionally show up to ask a  question whether its poor or good don't give a f*** about reputation. It hits them hard once they receive a question ban but til then they simply don't care...all they want is an answer....

Comment: @mehow I agree, and I think that is why we need to work on the supply side. New users who have no plans on becoming regular simply don't care if they have a two-q-per-week limit, or whether their question was downvoted, or whether they got their answer in a comment. As long as they get _an answer_, they will be satisfied, and it seems likely that they will misuse the site in _exactly the same way_ if they ever need an answer again. We have to stop answering the poor questions.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I can accept the notion of not paying attention to poor questions, however I am not sure how would you go about answering the better questions if there is a flood of poor questions?

Comment: @posdef It is hard, especially right now, but I am convinced that the good questions exist. The world is still populated with professional and enthusiast programmers, and they still have questions. It is simply a matter of dredging the swamp in an attempt to find the gold. Eventually we'll find a way to keep the swamp from flooding again, but for now, we have to wade through the muck with two goals in mind: bail out the muck as quickly as possible, while finding the small treasures hidden here and there.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins sure, but the question still lies in "how to we get to better questions" if 1 in 20 of the questions displayed is "interesting" or "good quality" (how we define that is also subjective). I still need that there has to be some effort into decreasing the flood of duplicate, RTFM/LMGTHFY or debug-my-code questions.

Comment: But, if this were implemented, new (low-rep) users who wanted to flood the site with mediocre questions could circumvent the quota system by creating multiple accounts. Or would you want to tie it in to the ban mechanism, which looks at IP address?

Answer (score 6):

It was shocking to read the meta after a while and I have to say that I like the idea of implementing some sort of quota on asking questions. At the same time I understand the criticism and the valid points that were put forth (e.g. Shog9).

#### My perspective

I am neither a very knowledgable/experienced programmer nor a very avid user of SO, but I have been around for several years now and SO has been a lifeline for me on multiple occasions, the place to go when you don't have anyone around you who can give feedback or guidance when you are stuck, or when you don't *understand* the problem you are experiencing. I would like to see SO survive many more years with the quality it once had (and perhaps still has).

#### Shortcomings of the rep system

Although I like the idea of a quota, I am not sure coupling it to rep is the best way to go. I have **serious** skepticism regarding the reputation system in general:

1. it is a metric which, I believe, is often misinterpreted as to how reliable/advanced the information provided by the person is. Of course this is essentially how it should be but it rarely is since ...
2. as per #1 rep becomes a metric by which users can "grind" respect, renown and stature by jumping on every grenade that is bad questions/answers etc. It is sad that some people feel the need, but I am not here to judge...

For the reasons stated above I feel that reputation has become more than what it was originally intended to be. As we use rep to decide upon which users we bestow moderation rights, it also becomes something of a currency. The more you invest in gaining reputation (for instance by hunting down questions with few or no answers) the more you gain in this system.

#### Suggestions for implementing a quota

I feel that the only measure of the quality questions/answers you write is based on how good/bad your questions have been in the past. Thus I propose:

1. The first time a user tries to ask a question or write an answer; the user should go through the help/about page, especially about how to write good questions/answers. It *really* isn't trivial to write a good question/answer, and SE has a very specific code with regards to that. You might say that there already is such a feature, but I don't think it's as efficient as it could be.
2. Initiate a user with <= 3 question "tokens". Every time the user asks a question, a token is used. The same can essentially be extended to writing answers.
3. Tokens are earned by asking question that are deemed to be useful and of good quality, and by contribution over time (editing/answering etc).
4. For the love of all that is holy, please don't show reputation or number of badges when asking/answering a question. It promotes prejudice in people. What would be useful to see however, if a person has a badge for a particular tag, for instance if a user has got a gold badge in [java] tag then it would be useful to see, but having the gold "fanatic" badge has practically no use to anyone else.
5. Consider having a contribution/time spent quotient (or something like `rep based on questions`/ `# of questions`, analogous for answers) . Not everyone has hours per day to burn on a QA-site. While the people who do so, *with good quality contribution* are certainly appreciated, it would be good to see how people make use of their time on the site.

Not sure how feasible these are but I think it would definitely improve the situation to some extent.

Comment: You should post #4 as a proposal on Meta instead of hiding it in an answer

Comment: @DVK - That's something that's been a feature request before though. OP would at least need to bring some proof that being able to see rep causes harm if they were to duplicate it.

Comment: *[rep] is often misinterpreted as to how reliable/advanced the information provided by the person is. Of course this is essentially how it should be* - It shouldn't be a measure of how advanced the info is. Reputation is a measure of how much the system trusts you.  It's a measure of how good you are at using Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BSMP: unfortunately, "how good you are at using SO" also includes harvesting reputation by answering the most basic gimme-code and debug-my-code, and off-topic questions. That is *abusing* the system; it lowers the general "quality" (with any reasonable definition) of SO.

Comment: @Jongware - Still not a measure of how advanced the info is.

Answer (score 1):

Newbies asking more than 2 questions or some number a week sounds like doing homework not a user who normally uses his own resources and asks when he gets stuck.  I don't think it would necessarily be antagontistic or confrontational if users were told to limit there use to not 5 times a week as they start out.  Instead they should be searching stack overflow and finding the low hanging fruit.

Also this is ultimately not a teaching service. By that I mean you learn a lot here but a newbie should not work through his learning with daily questions but treat the service as a place to go after they have looked into the issues. I guess what's not wanted is here is todays question on the current subject i'm learning.

I don't know if it would improve question quality that much(arguably at least some) but it would send a message that it's not a homework service. Well it can be a place to learn and solve problems after some research.

Perhaps better expectations of what the service is could make everyone understand it better as opposed to ask away and then you shouldn't be asking that :) There is a natural tendency of new users to view stack as just another question and answer site and a place to shoot off any old question. I was guilty of that at first. But the system will not reward that.

edit(addition):

I was hit with a question ban(since lifted) about ten months after signing up. I didn't see the resource as particularly scare. The system will get them is never really satisfactory over whatever helps to prevent misunderstandings.

A question limit that can go up or down is better than ask away and but then the system could suddenly institutes a question ban

Mike

Answer (score -2):

I am actually a moderator on another site, and a frequent contributor to a third.  While I understand that there are far too many "takers" out there, the reaction to alleged "noobs" is borderline hostile.

I, for example may be new to this site, discovering it only this past month, but I have nearly 25 years in the industry.  I frequent this site because a stroke put me out of work for five years and I'm a bit rusty.  I've seen posts from others trying to move from one discipline to another and are asking 'noob' questions for that particular language/discipline and are getting blasted for it.

So, to those who want to limit the number of questions asked, I say, does that include good questions?  If I ask two questions that are up-voted to a rating of five, should I be done for the week?

EDITED:

To clarify for the comment.

I should have said "newbie" questions.  I've seen a bunch of questions down-voted that aren't bad questions, but Newbie questions that start with statements like "Well, I've been working with Excel VBA, so I'm not sure how to do this with access, here's my code.... (decent attempt at code).

And I see I've already gotten a few down votes for this, so.... kinda proving my point.

THIS question got a down-vote right out of the box, I responded with an upvote, as it's not a bad question, but it IS the type that's getting hit.

[Excel VBA: For Each loop returning Values not Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368488/excel-vba-for-each-loop-returning-values-not-ranges)

Comment: If they are asking noob questions, they deserve getting ousted. Or did you mean newbie-questions? The difference is that the latter try to learn, do their research, and are generally receptive to criticism. And newbie-questions are generally well-received, I think.

Comment: BTW: What *kind* of sites are you speaking of? Tutoring, encyclopedia, support-forum, private forum, social site, mechanical turk, debugging, contest, Q&A-site, stackexchange-site? Also, a few examples of newbie-questions which you think are decent but were downvoted would be useful.

Comment: Moderator at a Q&A Tech site, frequent poster at another. Q&A tech site.  I wasn't counting non-technical sites.  quite a few others, but I didn't think them relevant.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368488/excel-vba-for-each-loop-returning-values-not-ranges), but it doesn't look like it should be downvoted. Mind, I also don't see it especially deserving of upvotes either. Anyway, it only has a single down- and up-vote each, that gets booked under measurement-error.

Comment: I upvoted it to counter the down-vote.  There were a few others, all asked by people with reps of less than 30.  Similar questions asked by people of higher reps were not slammed.  THAT one stood out, so I remembered it.  There were a few others with negative ones that I up voted because they didn't deserve it either.  We were ALL newbies at one time or another.  It smacks of cliquishness and bullying.  Ironic IMO.  I know I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed since the stroke, but I know that I can still smell a rat.

Comment: *Never* vote to counter a vote, that's a very bad idea, and damages the worth of all votes far more than a few votes you just cannot understand or agree with. Look at the voting tooltip, that should be your only reason for voting, and it doesn't mention other peoples votes at all (nor does it mention rep, which should also be disregarded). Now, if you see a post which doesn't deserve a vote either way, if you can see a way to fix it so it deserves an upvote, *please* do so, if you have the time. Thereafter, it obviously deserves your vote, so feel free.

Comment: @Deduplicator [Is using an up-vote to balance out a down-vote wrong?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311408/839601)

Comment: From what I've seen in this thread and others (like the "Why has it gotten so negative") thread, and the voting circles, and the malicious down-voting one, it appears that there is a bit of a problem.  What I see is that there appears to be malicious down-voting of newer users.  This isn't my sandbox, so I have no say in what goes on in its governance.  What is clear is that someone with as many points to spend as you could frustrate anyone's efforts to crawl even to 15 rep points, keeping them from all privileges, with no consequences.  One down vote per week could do it, not that you would.

Comment: @Gnat I read that thoroughly, and apparently, the conventional wisdom is that a sympathetic upvote is terrible, while a malicious downvote is no big deal, with the dissenter's opinion getting 14 downvotes, all by people with reps of over 1000, effectively crushing him.  Also, since he was knocked down below 50 by the votes, the only way he can respond is through an answer, and not a comment, and thus exposed to more downvotes.

Comment: The one good thing is that since I'm already at the lowest reputation, I could, if I so chose, be a complete jerk and suffer no consequences, another flaw with the "dogpile on the newbie" attitude in here.  I wonder if my answer can get to -20.  I bet it will.

Comment: Ah, and another wonderful thing.  New users can be punished with down votes and never get the ability to vote themselves.  The anonymity of the down voters keeps them safe twice.

Comment: WHOO HOOO!!!! MINUS THREE!!!

Comment: And another new user targeted for down votes  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368488/excel-vba-for-each-loop-returning-values-not-ranges

Comment: Only minus four?  You guys can do better than that!

Comment: @RichardU: Not entirely sure how other site metas work, but on meta.SO, downvotes tend to simply signify disagreement. You're not being persecuted. :P

Answer (score -10):

I think SO should go a lot further, and deny or severly limit new users from posting questions until they have proven their ability to provide answers or demonstrated that they understand what a good question might be.

This could be done by requiring e.g. 50 or 100 rep points to post questions. Or by making all questions asked by low-rep users closed by default and subjected to a newbie question moderation queue before they can appear on the site until 50 or 100 rep.

Or perhaps, as A. Webb suggested in the comments, by subjecting new users to a quizz before allowing them to post questions, so as to ensure they're able to distinguish a good question from a bad one.

As a bonus, this would force hapless help-vampires to learn to use google or the site's search form before asking, since their sewage wouldn't be answered. And it would trim the close-vote queue, since discouraged help-vampires with no good questions would look for answers elsewhere.

Comment: You know, if you just dissolve the site, that will trim the close-vote queue too. Also, what's the difference with the "newbie question moderation queue" and what we have? As someone famously said ***SO has one unfortunate flaw: they allowed people to ask questions***

Comment: @sehe: the main difference would be that the front page would feature reasonably good questions only.

Comment: This "answer questions to earn points toward asking them" is one of the things Experts Exchange used to do; you can ask around and see what kind of results that kicked up. I already come across folks answering questions in an attempt to dig themselves out of a q-ban... Spoiler: if you can't write an intelligible sentence in your questions, you're probably not gonna do much better in your answers. Unless you resort to plagiarism. Which some do. So yeah... The results don't exactly improve as you tighten the screws.

Comment: I'd change this to "proven their ability to know the difference between good and bad questions". Do this with a quiz about the FAQ, or make them pass the audit tests of the review queues. All that is required is _some_ vested interest in the question asking process.

Comment: Did they really? I never bothered to use that hideous site. Any odds you remember how they implemented it, or if that actually had anything to do with their demise?

Comment: There are folks here who were actually quite active on EE back in the day; you're better off asking them. I recall lots of link-only answers and partial/tangential solutions; you're not exactly motivated to *avoid trying to answer crap* if the only way you can ask your own question is to grind away answering crap.

Comment: @A.Webb: I like that idea. Answer updated to mention it too.

Comment: @Shog9: Indeed, but if questions by new users were subjected to active approval before appearing, I'd imagine the number of low quality questions that one can grind rep on to drop significantly, no?

Comment: You might be surprised how far some folks' standards will drop when they find themselves fighting over a few scraps of bread.

Comment: @Shog9: Good point... That comment conjured up vivid memories of male engineering students drooling over the handful of female students around them.