# Information on and circumventing of limitation of number of questions asked per time unit

Tags: support

I just got learned that I'm not allowed to ask more than 6 questions per day. That was news to me so I wonder:

1. How can I learn the time left before I can ask again?
2. Is there a way to circumvent that limitation?
3. Is the x question per day meaning per today or per 24 hour period?

Comment: `Is there a way to circumvent that limitation?` You do realize that the limitation isn't there to be circumvented, right? You're doing the equivalent of asking a police officer what loopholes you could use to get away with arson. Any answer you get will immediately be followed up by someone patching that loophole, because it shouldn't exist.

Comment: I think that 6 questions is way enough, with all the already given resources on the websites

Comment: After asking 6 questions in a day, I feel a good way to spend the remaining time is to answer questions...after all its Q&A...not just Q :-)

Comment: Maybe it's related to this?: [No one likes quitting cold turkey](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230899/163250).

Comment: @ParthianShot Please don't be so melodramatic. It's not the same thing at all, unless you regard being prone to ask as equally bad as killing/robing etc. The comparison is ridiculous. I assumed that the limitation was to get one to think a second time if it's really needed to ask an additional question and if so, allowing it. Downvoting for that is plain pathetic, in my view, borderline bullying (and **that's** actually against the law). Besides none's actually answered the item 1 nor 3. This was far less helpful than expected. And far less polite.

Comment: @vico That's your opinion and, while I respect it, I don't feel the same way. We need to observe the fact that we work, think and lear in different ways. There's no "fit-all" approach. Besides, the question wasn't whether it's reasonable to have the limit at 6 but rather (which you seem to fail to see) how I can see when the limit is up. Thanks.

Comment: @Payeli What about the case when one's so new to stuff that their A's wouldn't do much good and the Q's is the best way to change that.   :)

Comment: @Konrad, we're actually [moving the opposite way](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251913/464709), and trying to make users aware that *posting questions ought to be considered as a scarce resource*. Six questions per user per day is already a lot, considering the scale of the time and effort we have to put into triaging and processing them. See also [Asking questions privilege should be severely limited for new users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252804/464709) for an example of a related viewpoint on the issue.

Comment: @Konrad, the comparison had nothing to do with "being prone to ask as equally bad as killing/robing", the analogy is completely correct. And did you just suggest that downvoting is borderline illegal?

Comment: @OGHaza Given the point made by Frédéric I'm prone to agree. However, it's pretty common to e.g. get an extension if something extraordinary happens and how has hard time keeping oneself to the fix limits. When it comes to arson, it's never OK. I disapprove of melodramatic comparisons (and I don't really see the need of such a hard donwnvote - it's to me equivalent to bullying). So I sort-of agree with you.   :)   Still, nobody has answered my question 1 and 3...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for a polite comment. Is there a way to see how long time I have before I can ask again?

Comment: @Konrad, I don't know, but if it works like the other limits in the system then it should reset on midnight UTC (roughly seven hours and a half from now).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi as well as the daily limit there's a monthly limit too - which while I can't remember the exact number is certainly less than 6 * 30.

Comment: I still can't believe the heavy downvote. -13 for a fully legitimate question?! I guess my measure of reason differs vastly from (at least) 13 other members. Sad...   :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Look at the timestamps on the oldest of your past 6 questions. 24 hours from that time, you'll be able to ask another question.
2. There are always ways of circumventing limitations. This one is rather hard to get around though, and since I don't want you doing it I'm not going to explain how. Go for a long walk instead.
3. It's per 24 hour period. See answer to #1.

Comment: So there *is* a way? Are you challenging us? ;)

Comment: For what it's worth, I do have scripts to detect this sort of circumvention, and will occasionally delete accounts I find engaged in it. Not always; but not never... And there are no warnings. FYI.

Comment: Err... Why leave a potential circumvention *bug* alone and work around it with *scripts* instead of fixing it in the first place? (with all due respect, sir.)

Comment: To minimize collateral damage, @Frédéric. This is similar to how we combat voting fraud: there are automated systems that handle the common cases and then moderators that review suspicious but not clear-cut cases.

Comment: Thanks, mate. That was all I needed to know. And just to clarify (because there seems to be a degrading consensus that any person asking something really will do something wrong unless stopped, which is depressing view of human being) - I'm way too lazy to try to hack around that. And I don't want to go against the rules. Besides, if I **absolutely** have to, I can borrow an account from a friend or simply register a new one. :)

Comment: Sadly, some of us have spent entirely too much time battling folks who will ask the same bad question a dozen times a day unless forcibly stopped, @Kondrad. So the reaction here isn't anything specific to you, it's just general weariness.