# Give high-rep users extra weight on close votes

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

As a person's commitment to the community increases, I think we should make it possible for high-reputation users to fast-track the closure of certain questions.  [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253314/102937) for some of my rationale.

Here's what I propose (subject to tweaking).  To qualify:

1. User must have 20K of reputation.
2. User must have a tag badge in one of the tags on the question.
3. Question must already have one close vote and a downvote.

If all of these conditions apply, I propose that the 20K user's close vote be binding (the closure takes effect immediately).

**My primary motivation**
If experts are being driven away by the parade of low-quality questions in their tag communities, I'd like to give them some better tools to address that.

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230882/169611

Comment: I would *at least* want to be able to opt out of it - to give a particular close vote "normal" weight.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Some moderators requested that in the past, and it was refused.  The rationale (more or less): If you don't have enough cajones to swing the mighty hammer, then you shouldn't be casting a non-binding vote either.  Either a question deserves to be closed, or it doesn't.  In some of my recent discussions here, I assert that we take too much time wringing our hands about whether or not to close, when we should just be swinging the hammer immediately and giving the OP time to improve their question.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say a tag badge, you want it to be *any* tag badge, meaning just a bronze badge, correct?  (I want to call this out as shog called out gold badges, and I want to be clear that your proposal is different.)

Comment: @Servy: "Subject to tweaking."  I'm not married to the details.

Comment: "Either a question deserves to be closed, or it doesn't." I completely disagree with that assertion. That's suggesting there's no room for nuance - that *every* right-thinking user will agree on *every* single close vote. I can appreciate the "just do it anyway, it doesn't matter too much if we'd disagree" but I definitely reject the black/white nature of your statement.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's why I've built a bunch of safeties into the binding vote.  Anyway, it's unlikely that the 20K'ers would be using this on edge cases.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are you proposing the binding reopen vote for users that meet these criteria, as Shog does, or not?

Comment: @Servy: Yes, it would have to work both ways.  In the same fashion, it would require one reopen vote from someone else (except for the OP).  I'm on the fence about an upvote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would first love to see how active those concerned high-rep users currently are where it concerns moderation. If they are truly concerned and actively try to address the problem but that doesn't work, then additional privileges might possibly make sense.

Comment: @Bart: Talk to the people in the PHP chat room, or the WhiteBoard. They run out of close votes on a regular basis.

Comment: @Bart Don't forget that a lot of high-rep users who do care have simply given up because they aren't equipped to deal with the problem.

Comment: I love this idea. I know I'm not a high rep user but even I'm being annoyed by the low quality of questions. Whether you agree with the assertion that this is why high rep users are dropping off it can't be argued that there are not plenty of questions in the VTC queue. Increasing the ability of trusted user to hammer down on these questions can definitely at least help keep that queue lower.

Comment: Could very well be @Mysticial. I'm just not entirely convinced by the >20k users == "good knowledge about what is off-topic" match-up. Might be worth a try, could surprise me. But some of the "concerns" raised in recent days had a lot of participants with very little visible moderation activity. Anyway, I'm not necessarily against it.

Comment: I would feel more comfortable if my vote only weighed 2.5 votes rather than was completely binding. Then if another 20+ user agreed with me, their 2.5 vote would satisfy enough votes to close.

Comment: @Bart There's definitely a lot of risk involved. So I'm not saying we should just "do it" as is written right now. I'm just saying that I've seen way too many 1's become 4's because they couldn't do anything.

Comment: @Kermit See the linked post at the top by Shog explaining why that's somewhat problematic.

Comment: Over the last 2 days I've seen mods stomp in and swing the mighty hammer several times. I support that - seems good enough for me.

Comment: @user3114046: Yes, that's all I'm saying.  I want to trickle down that power to some high-rep users, so we have a few more people swinging hammers.

Comment: What happens if the 20K user casts the first close vote (which is insufficient to immediately close the question) and then another sub-20K user votes to close? Will the super close vote be applied at the time of the second vote, or will the 20K user's vote continue to count as a normal 20%?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: The outcome is the same either way.

Comment: I feel like there's too much disagreement at the moment between high-rep users and mods as far as what is and isn't on topic for stackoverflow to give out this kind of power. There are many questions for example that I would prefer to see closed that i know many of the mods wouldn't agree with.

Comment: @KevinB: Example?

Comment: I'll have to look back to earlier this week, i've been somewhat away today

Comment: Things like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330444/ or the thousands of can i return from an ajax request duplicates that aren't exact duplicates (this is likely the one i see the most), or questions asking how to use a method that is clearly documented in the library's api. I understand if the api is hard to understand, but that's not the case for all apis.

Comment: @KevinB: I closed it as a duplicate of the proposed question.  If the rules I proposed had been in place, that question would have closed already.

Comment: To be fair the exceptions are rare, so i guess that wouldn't really be that big of an issue.

Comment: If we need more people insta-closing, why not elect more moderators?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Because electing 2-3 moderators in a long while wouldn't compensate the already 2000 20k+ users that would have this priviledge. It wouldn't be such a great advantage as the OP's idea.

Comment: Throwing more moderators at the problem isn't the right solution.  Greater community involvement is.

Comment: Perhaps it's time for hierarchical moderation. Each "branch" would be restricted to a certain sub-community and you can go down as many levels as you need. Each moderator is elected only within its branch and everything below it. But clearly the system isn't designed for this. Now you can scale to hundreds of moderators.

Comment: @Mysticial So basically different SEs. We would have to wary of crossover technologies but web (php, js, css) desktop (c++, c#, haskell), data (mysql, postgresql) can sit apart. and hey this oughtta encourage an end to questions tagged php-mysql (which shouldn't even exist)!

Comment: See also: [More effective closing / downvoting of junk questions to help with the signal-noise ratio?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252616/456814).

Comment: This might be minor, but I would suggest changing the title to "Give high rep users extra weight on close votes". "Super-close" reads as "very near" to me.

Comment: Instead of reputation, how about number of CV reviews? Or just the passed v failed audits?

Comment: Is there a way to draw some new attention to this issue without asking a duplicate question? The quality of questions is nosediving. I can close-vote 75% of the questions in my tags, but there are just too many people who only downvote without voting to close. All this rambling in poor questions... I'm at the verge of quitting.

Comment: `Please do this`

Answer (score 69):

Though this question specifically discusses high-rep users, I would not feel comfortable having my vote be binding. Instead, I would propose a tiered close vote system since close votes can be cast beginning with 3,000 reputation. This would also remove the tag or downvote requirement.

```
Reputation   Close vote weight
3,000        1.0
10,000       1.5
20,000       2.5
```

*These are completely made up and for illustrative purposes*

The minimum vote "count" could still remain at 5, but a combination of these users could satisfy a close:

```
1 @ 3,000  (1.0)
1 @ 10,000 (1.5)
1 @ 20,000 (2.5)
           -----
            5.0
```

Or

```
2 @ 20,000 (5.0)
           -----
            5.0
```

Or

```
5 @ 3,000  (5.0)
           -----
            5.0
```

Comment: @MartinSmith Because it was for illustrative purposes. I'm trying to see if we can get data on close votes and user reps behind them.

Comment: Okay, since the word illustrative means nothing, I've updated the weights.

Comment: I think this is essentially what @RobertHarvey is suggesting anyway, it just explains what would happen behind the scenes (supported by this comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253324/#comment-13003)

Comment: @KevinB: Yes, this would allow two 20K users to close, which would have benefited [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435534/mysql-select-lastest-unique-foreign-key?noredirect=1).

Comment: @KevinB I should add that this moves away from the need to have specific badges or the question having a downvote

Comment: I actually like this scheme.

Comment: I do too. I'm not entire sold on the tag requirement, as some of the tags are very inactive and difficult to get enough upvotes to be able to take advantage of this.

Comment: @Kermit, how do you see this reflected in the UI? Would we be comfortable with seeing things like `close(1.5)`? Should we translate into "relative" votes, something like `close(1.5->4)` for a 20K user who sees a question vtced by a 10K user?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's kind of what I had in mind. The value displayed would be the "weight count" as you described: `close(3.5)`

Comment: You don't need to display weights in the closing banner at all, just the close voters.

Comment: I think adding the rep count tooltip to the close banner would suffice, that way if there is any question you can hover over the names to see who has the rep.

Comment: @Robert, yes, the banner can remain unchanged. I was thinking about the vote to close link. What do you think about displaying both values (before, after), so voters are reminded how much their vote will weigh?

Comment: It doesn't matter how much your vote will weigh.  Either you think the question should be closed, or you don't.  There will always be some degree of community consensus; even with this scheme it still requires two community members to close.

Comment: @RobertHarvey which is much better than 5 and makes there a consensus required with 2.

Comment: @Robert, I understand that personally, but I was trying to cater to our "not wanting binding votes" citizens.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Honestly, if this is implemented, I don't want people to opt out of it.  The folks who are thinking "I want my vote to count for 1/5 of the total" are splitting hairs.

Comment: I'm not sold on removing the tag requirement. The users who are best able to determine about whether or not a question about a particular tag should be closed are the ones who have the most experience with that tag (e.g. gold badge  users). Those users will know a lot about what questions have already been asked in that tag, and should be able to have better judgement than another 20k user without a gold badge. I avoid voting on [tag:c] and [tag:c++] questions, because I have little experience with those domains.

Comment: I really like this schema.  Since nobody's mentioned it I'll add that reopen votes should be equally weighted - it should be as easy (or easier) to reopen a question as it is to close it.

Comment: This needs to be based on tag badges, if anything, and certainly not just on reputation, which is kind of a joke.

Comment: @JasonC Not sure why it needs to considering that close votes exist currently without being based on tag badges.

Answer (score 14):

I can see this being a significant tool to help some communities keep their little (or big) corner of SE clean.

However, a binding vote is a significant privilege, even with the limitations described.

There are only 17 moderators on SO and their actions are always extremely visible, so it is easy to notice and identify a moderator run amok (not that it would actually happen - just a hypothetical).

However, there are over 2000 (~2300 as of the time of this writing) users with >20K rep that could potentially earn this power.  It is much more difficult to keep tabs on a group that large, and much more difficult to get them to agree to a standard set of guidelines on what constitutes an on-topic question. As such, it will be much easier for one of them to abuse the power.

So if this, or a similar power were to be granted, appropriate moderation tools need to be created to:

1. Enable 10K or 20K users to see a list of questions closed or reopened with a binding vote, so they react accordingly if someone is abusing this power
2. Enable diamond moderators to revoke this privilege from users who have abused this power.  The ban can simply be a timed ban like those given to users who fail too many review audits or have too many rejected suggested edits, or it can be "permanent" ban that is only restored when a moderator manually restores the privilege.

Comment: You raise valid points. I believe special-casing binding votes like you suggest in (1) won't work properly with the weighing concept discussed in another answer, but we could keep relying on reopen votes anyway. I'm afraid (2) will be necessary, as two 20K users may very well be wrong at the same time, abuse or not.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the purpose of (1) was mostly to ensure that usage of the binding vote was specifically highlighted and easily visible.  I'm not proposing a review queue, more than I am just a list in the 10K tools.  2 20K users can easily be wrong, but the more users that see it, the more the law of averages should balance it out.

Comment: But with the weighing system, that would basically become a list of recently closed questions, wouldn't it?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi sorry, misread your comment, I thought you werre referencing the binding vote.  Yes, you are right, if the vote was just weighted and not binding, then I agree that (1) wouldn't be nearly as useful.

Comment: Oddly, I have never seen a close vote abused by 5. I have seen several abused by moderators in the last month. So I'm definitely opposed to giving diamond moderators any more power, and would love to see a "report abuse" button for them.

Answer (score 5):

> **My primary motivation**
>   If experts are being driven away by the parade of low-quality questions in their tag communities, I'd like to give them some better tools to address that.

Getting the questions closed is not the problem. The fact that so many have to be closed is the problem. This change would not address that.

Comment: [I agree thoroughly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Because questions are posted before they are closed, not the other way around.

Comment: Um, this isn't about keeping questions off the front page, it's about moving the bad ones off the front page.  People are going to ask bad questions; you can't avoid that unless you have a sentient computer that can screen them first.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not if you implement this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252443/where-are-the-non-trivial-php-questions-lately#comment7891_252443 :)

Comment: As far as sources of bad questions, that's being attacked from at least one direction: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230857/no-one-likes-quitting-cold-turkey/230899#230899 . I think those changes to the question ban (both on the early warning side and for the repeat offenders) will be a significant help.

Comment: One *big* thing that this does is it makes it a lot easier for low quality questions to be closed before someone can stick in a low quality answer.  When people stop getting answers for their very low quality questions they'll learn to stop posting them.  Currently, in many tags, questions get closed, but too many of them have time for an answer to barely slip in first.

Comment: Low quality questions are already closed very quickly: reducing that time by 10s isn't going to make a dent. Besides, although I appreciate the sentiment and I _certainly_ appreciate you searching for solutions, can you imagine a certain high rep user who famously fared poorly in the last mod elections wielding this sort of power? High rep isn't a good indicator for responsible behaviour.

Comment: The binding vote is the answer. Until mods say they can't cast their binding vote fast enough, I don't see why there should be a change.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I see a *significant* percentage of questions that get 1-2 close votes, then several answers, then get closed.  Usually it does take a bit more than 10 seconds, and even when it doesn't, sometimes those few seconds is fast enough to beat out the first answers.  I do agree though that there are potential concerns of abuse, which is why I'm still on the fence here.  I disagree that this couldn't be potentially beneficial, if used well, but I do agree that it could be very harmful, if not used well.

Comment: @Servy Well ok that's fair. Still, I can't help but feel like there must be a better solution than trying to give unelected people enough power to nuke questions in as short a time as possible, where by that we mean 10-15 seconds.

Comment: Maybe questions shouldn't be answerable until they have ---5 upvotes--- +5 score, and upvoting questions should require 2k rep :p Still prone to idiots being "helpful" and pity upvoting but it would be less abuseable *and* a very clear signal as to what is and is not welcome here. Y'know, something objective and concrete that we could link to in the FAQ.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit For the bikeshed questions, they'll get to 5 upvotes really fast; often faster than they can be closed.  For any question that's not a bikeshed question, it'll really struggle to get 5 upvotes.  You're basically killing straight out all but the most popular concepts.  catch 22.

Comment: @Servy At least in the C++ tag, real questions hit 5 quickly and crap questions so not. The problem here I guess is one of setting a threshold, and that's problematic because on SO we effectively now have separate communities. Heck, maybe they need splitting up.

Comment: If you really want to stop those quick-and-dirty answers to noxious questions, maybe prevent answers for the first minute and 1 minute longer for each close-voter?

Comment: @Deduplicator: That's not a bad idea. I'd start with 5 minutes, though.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t think rep is the correct way to drive this.

We know from the close review queue the users that tend to act in a way that is consistent with how other users review the same item.

Using some simple stats it would be possible to work out the set of users that if they were given a “binding close/leave open” vote, then the outcome would not change in 99% of the time.   I don’t know how large this set would be.    Assuming it is greater than 0, these uses could be given double “power” on their review actions.