# Is *Lacks sufficient information* really a close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There are many questions which lack sufficient information to be answered. However, this can be remedied by asking the OP to add data/information/log/code.

All that information should be included in the original post, but I feel that marking for closure for that reason does not work.

I find it is a complex/long/difficult/obscure process to close a question for lack of information, then get the user to edit it, then open it again, all that with the question having had a bunch of downvotes in the process, and it is not a surprise the users create new questions instead.

But may be it is also a protection against users who will not make any effort.

Comment: How can someone who's had the permissions to reopen questions for such a long time not know that questions can be reopened?

Comment: I know that questions can be reopened. I just don't see that very often, and usually I see users create a new question.

Comment: I don't see it very often either.  Not coincidentally, I don't see users actually edit their questions into good questions very often either.

Comment: What I was trying to express (may be the wording is incorrect) is, isn't it a tedious process to get the close votes, then get the user to understand that they have to edit, then mark the question for reopening? Not to mention that with close marks often comes downvotes, which results in a reopened question with a quite bad mark. Will the users who downvoted when the question was first asked come back to remove the downvote? will they be warned that the question was edited and reopened?

Comment: Solution: read the **mandatory [how-to-ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page**.

Comment: `then get the user to understand that they have to edit, then mark the question for reopening` The close notice itself already says "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment." If a user doesn't bother to read that, what else can you do?

Comment: @njzk2 Well, to begin with, as I have already mentioned, most users *don't* improve their questions, so it's a question of which you'd rather have, unasnwerable questions sitting open because people don't want to close them, or having them closed.  The latter has a *ton* of benefits.  As for downvotes, if someone is posting an incomplete and unanswerable question it *should* be downvoted.  That is a consequence of them not asking a complete and answerable question.  If you don't want downvotes, don't ask incomplete questions.

Comment: There is a nugget of truth here. I think on the whole we all need the ability to be more agile about closing and reopening things. Unclear question? It needs to be closed *right now*, just as it needs to be reopened immediately after it gets edited up to par. Reopening questions is clunky and slow right now, such that we're instinctively reluctant to close questions since that's a fast track to a slow death. tl;dr: [give us more voting power](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253324/give-high-rep-users-extra-weight-on-close-votes/253332#comment16454_253332)

Comment: @Servy `most users don't improve their questions` Agreed. I don't want them to remain open, too. So I guess simply closing and let the user decide wether they are ready to work on it later.

Comment: Many such users don't want to improve their questions, they just want SO contributors to work in parallel to debug their 'does not work' rubbish code.  First one to do so wins an accepted answer, the rest waste their time, but that doesn't matter since it's not the OP's time being wasted and they can go down the pub in the meantime.  Why bother with all that really hard 'debugging' stuff, noting down errors and values etc. if you can have the fun of writing the code and then get some other sucker/s to debug it?

Comment: @roippi By and large reopening questions *isn't* slow or clunky.  It was a few years ago before there was a reopen queue, but not anymore.  People don't close questions because they *fear* that reopening is clunky even though it's *not*, and the result is unclear/incomplete questions staying open and attracting bad answers.

Comment: 'I want to ask algorithm or code in C and I will be very happy if you help me :) Remember that I dont have much time and I should write this code tonight and give it to my friend tomorrow morninG'.  There should be close-reasons that contain swear words.  Yes, Imma closevoting this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789621/printf-doesnt-print-correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791561/error-in-reading-the-file-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Questions aren't reopened

That's because they aren't improved. If instead the new user creates a new question (obviously prohibited, if they bother read the FAQ linked everywhere), it will (rightfully) be received poorly and may lead to a question-ban (hooray).

## But 10 people must be involved…

So? There's no backlog on the reopen queue, questions are improved so rarely.

## So, people aren't being told to edit

No. The close reason and FAQ tell users to edit. Also, common sense.

Comment: Actually the 5 people that close the question can also vote to reopen it, so a minimum of 5 people are needed, not 10.  Not that it changes the meat of this answer.

Answer (score 9):

> until it is closed, at which point it is too late for them to do anything.

It's not too late for anything at all.  When their question is closed they can edit it to include the missing information, and then have their question reopened.

> Could the question be closed until it is completed, and then submitted for re-opening by the user once they have added elements?

That's exactly what *does* happen.  Questions edited while on hold are put into the reopen queue to be re-evaluated.

Comment: but then users simply create a new question. I would assume this new question would have to be closed as duplicate?

Comment: @njzk2 Correct, if they do decide to open a new question that's exactly what should be happening.

Comment: @njzk2 If they're duplicating bad questions, they will be question-banned.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "insufficient information to diagnose problem" means exactly what it says, but it's actually a symptom of a larger problem.

First of all, can we all agree that the purpose of closing is to *prevent answers from being posted while the OP improves their question?*  If there's never any negative consequences for posting bad questions, then what stops people from posting whatever they want?

Now then...

### Scenario One

1. User posts incomplete question.
2. Comments come in asking for more information.  Meanwhile, the post gets closed.
3. OP gets frustrated and either starts a meta conversation below the answers, accuses us of being mean, complains on meta, and/or (maybe about 5 percent of the time) improves their question.
4. Question is abandoned.
5. We're all sad.

### Scenario Two

1. User posts (mostly) complete question, but leaves out a few details
2. Comments come in asking for clarification.  OP provides it, in a timely manner.
3. Post may or may not attract some downvotes/close votes
4. Question is answered.
5. Profit!

Which is the better scenario?

Here's my point.  *The closing system is not the problem.* It never was.  Those who think the closing system should be streamlined in favor of the 5% that might get around to improving their question are looking at the wrong thing.

What do we tell folks?  Improve their question, so that it can be reopened.  That's the truth.  But the long term solution rests with new users: learn how to ask better questions.

Comment: All the more reason to make sure your question is a good one from the start.

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery That's a 2 year old mentality.  Due to the existence of the reopen queue, that's simply not the case.  The post doesn't even need to attract a single reopen vote to get the ball rolling, the question being edited puts the question into the queue, and gives it the eyeballs it needs to reopen it if the post really does merit being open.  That *used* to be a big problem, but that problem has long since been solved.

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery: He's saying that we didn't have a reopen queue two years ago.  The reality is that questions that get fixed generally get reopened.  Most of the time, they don't get fixed, for the same reasons that they were poor questions to begin with.