# Extending the gold badge rights to further close vote reasons

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, dupehammer

The gold badge now allows the holder to have binding close votes on duplicates. It was discussed in here:

[When did I get close-vote superpowers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers)

This is a nice thing for the site as well as appreciation for the experts.

Provided that the close vote queue number is still increasing despite the previous addition, albeit not that much as before, perhaps: are there any plans to extend it to other close reason in the not so far future?

Comment: We've made sooo many changes in the past few weeks to how close votes are weighed and reviewed, it's a bit premature to consider any further changes until we've seen how this pans out long-term ([Hawthorn Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawthorn_effect) is a pain to work around).

Comment: I'm opposed to a unilateral close-hammer for gold badge holders. Maybe counting the gold badge as 3 votes or something, but there's enough gray area that I would prefer at least one more person to review closing.

Comment: @chrylis: you can already reopen instantly with a gold badge if a closure had happened mistakenly, so that is not an issue.

Comment: offtopic no-repo/typo and "seeking debugging help" would be good candidates (where having specific domain knowledge helps).

Comment: I'd like to see gold badge users having an increased vote weight on all topics. 3 votes would be about right - two [gold badgers](http://stickerslug.s3.amazonaws.com/product-image/z-dh-4021-gold-alt00.jpg) needed to close, otherwise three people including a gold badge holder.

Comment: @Duncan: I would probably even extend this to comment deletion in the given area for gold badge holders. Sometimes moderators make wrong decisions about comment deletion because it is out of their league; experts should be able to make better decisions.

Comment: @Shog9 is the time ripe yet to consider further changes or is it still a bit too soon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Give high-rep users extra weight on close votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253324/give-high-rep-users-extra-weight-on-close-votes)

Comment: related discussion at MSE: [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/165773)