# Relax close vote requirements for low-quality questions

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, downvotes, low-quality-posts

We've had numerous discussions on question quality, and one of the issues raised is that people are answering poor questions before they get closed. I'd like to suggest a potential option which would make downvotes actually somewhat useful and help to get poor questions (as judged by the community) closed quicker. What I suggest is the following:

- For every X net votes below zero a question has (let's say five for now), the amount of close votes required is reduced by one.
- A minimum of two close votes is  but there must be a minimum
- If a downvote would reduce the amount of close votes needed to zero, one more close vote would still be required (so a downvote alone cannot close a question).

Let's provide a few examples to clear any confusion:

- A question has a score of -5 and has no close votes. Now only 4 votes are needed to close the question.
- A question has a score of -4 and already has 4 votes to close, but then gets downvoted. Now the question still requires one more vote to close the question.
- A question has 5 upvotes and 5 downvotes (i.e. a score of 0). Since the net score is zero, 5 votes are needed to close the question.
- A question has a score of -25. Two votes are still needed to close the question, despite the downvotes.

Would this not help to utilise the signal that the community already provides? I think this would help to get bad questions out of the way, while not affecting most questions which are of acceptable quality.

Comment: I would prefer giving gold badge holders insta-close powers, like we now do for duplicates, or a weighted system like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253332/102937).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm concerned about other close votes being more subjective than duplicates, where what one finds horrible might be perfectly fine for another. Downvotes make it more clear that the community *at large* finds the question poor-quality, not just one person.

Comment: That's why a [weighted system](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253332/102937) would be a reasonable compromise.

Comment: Could you please provide some specific non-duplicate examples of posts where this happened and the question was clearly absolute and complete rubbish? And also explain what the problem is with this behavior? So long as the answers aren't upvoted or accepted, [the question will be auto-deleted anyway](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/). Also, questions with -5 score are hidden from the front page, and are likely not going to get answers anyway so I can't see this being a significant hindrance as suggested.

Comment: @jmac Examples? Go the the low quality or close vote queue. Most stuff in the reopen vote queue too. Vamps will reward whores with accepting, preventing auto deletion a lot of the time.

Comment: I would add a precaution that always 1 close vote must be provided, otherwise a -25 score would be closed without any indication given to the user as to why it is closed (I would hope that the OP can tell why but you never know) - My only other gripe with this is it kind of gives users 2 close votes and may lead to further downvote negativity

Comment: This proposal is very complex and gives the power to 125 rep people which is dangereous, whereas more power to gold badge holders would solve this issue and even more. Weighted system is also bad because it gives power to people beyond-their-league which is harmful. We already see many questions closed mostly by irrelevant people, and the experts currently do not have the power to override them, and it is sometimes close to impossible to reopen certain questions due to the "Leave closed" trigger-happy reviewers.

Comment: I haven't had problems with questions not closing fast enough. I have had several problems with proper questions being closed in a trigger-happy fashion. This would not help that at all.

Comment: I love this idea. Combined with the insta-close powers to gold badge people, finally we *could* have a chance to battle the noise. People who are willing to help need to be given power. If they give up, that would be the final blow for SO. Mistakes, wrong closings happened, happen and will happen, but these can be solved easily.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I was already asking about more power to gold badge holders: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256537/extending-the-gold-badge-rights-to-further-close-vote-reasons I would love it come to reality.

Comment: No, No and again no.

Comment: @Sayse: it was already there, but I forgot to add an example for it (done now).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Ah of course, that was just a misreading on my part

Comment: I do like this idea, but do downvotes come faster than close votes ? I may be wrong but it seems to me they don't, and therefore it wouldn't fasten much the process... I guess it highly depends on tags anyway.

Comment: @Vincent People tend to think closing is a lot more permanent than it is, so they hold off on closing quite a bit (but I guess they also do this with downvoting). Also, low-rep users can only downvote, so 5 low rep users can essentially cause a similar effect as a close vote.

Comment: @Dukeling I don't know for other low-rep users but I or one extremely rarely use downvote. Most of the time, I'm not quite sure about me really perfectly getting what the community expects from a question and I often prefer to reserve my judgement. The questions I downvote are unquestionably bad and are highly downvoted. Do you think low-rep users really downvote so much ?

Comment: @Vincent No, I think too few people (low-rep or otherwise) downvote or vote to close, in general, but I don't really see us solving that problem. There's some merit to the basic idea proposed here, but we'll need some stats before deciding that it's a good idea.

Comment: related discussion at MSE: [Empowering tag-badge holders part II - let's look at silver?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240700/165773)

Answer (score 7):

**I agree about the main concern, but I think it is suboptimal to give more power to low-rep (125) users instead of area experts!**

The real solution to your issue (and to much more) is IMHO to give more power to gold badge holders as per the following question:

[Extending the gold badge rights to further close vote reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256537/extending-the-gold-badge-rights-to-further-close-vote-reasons)

The moderators and site owners do not seem to be against the idea overall, so it might come to reality a bit later.

That would be also simplier compared to your rules where one needs to concentrate "hard" to get all the "sub-points", too. It is a bit complex how it sounds to me, but this is just a side-note, not really the main issue.

If we start giving more powers to the contributors, it is better to start with the experts to have more weight on the happening of the questions in the desired tags.

Last, but not least, 125 rep users may well include puppets as well, unfortunately.

That being said, I whole-heartedly agree about your concern with regards to the answers sneaking in for clearly off-topic or otherwise inappropriate questions. I think we do need to solve that issue because it is semi-severe.

Comment: You can't downvote until you reach 150 rep. Besides, it would still take a least two confirmed users for the question to be closed so I don't think that's really giving much power to newbies.

Comment: @Vincent: 1) [It is 125, not 150.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) 2) It gives powers to "newbies" as well as puppets instead of experts.

Comment: You're right, my bad ! Still disagree with you though, I guess it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: I think this is a nice idea, which seems legit to me. I don't think this is giving too much powers to newbies and as for me, the proposed limitations are quite wise. However, I'm not sure about the actual effiency of this proposal : would to-be-closed-posts be voted down fast enough to significantly fasten the process ? I'm not sure of that, in spite of my liking of the idea.