# Provide Gold Badges with Close for "can no longer be reproduced"

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I just came across this (nothing special about it): [Rails 4, not sending email using sendmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338718/rails-4-not-sending-email-using-sendmail). The author answered himself with a one-liner fix.

Would it be possible to allow gold badges to close this type of question without the need for community reviews?

My apologies if they have it. I can't tell if they have the power from [Help Center > Badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), [Gold Badge Tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold), or [Extending the gold badge rights to further close vote reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256537/extending-the-gold-badge-rights-to-further-close-vote-reasons) (or linked questions).

Comment: It appears to have been closed for the right reason.

Comment: @0xdeadbeef - yes, agreed. That's not the point of this post.

Comment: I'm confused, you want any user with any gold badge to be able to close questions unchecked?

Comment: To be fair, we already can-  we just have to lie about the reason and claim its a dupe.  It sounds more like he wants gold badge privlidges to include a few other close reasons, such as typographical error.  As much as this shocks even me for once I kind of agree with him-  I don't think we should have it for all close reasons but this one sounds reasonable.

Comment: @Gabe - if you don't have the power, then I believe you should. For a trivial reason like "No Longer Reproducible" and "Simple Typo", the site might even consider delegating to users with 5000 or 10000 points. "No Longer Reproducible" and "Simple Typo" are usually easier to determine than dups.