# Reward for close voters finding appropriate duplicates?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, duplicate-questions

I'd like to discuss, if it's considerable worth it, awarding users for finding good duplicates for a question that is upvoted though being marked as a *duplicate*.

As a premise: Duplicate questions can be very helpful for future research, and I have upvoted several of those, to improve a dense network of Q&A oriented network, as SE claims to be.
I've also downvoted many questions (and promoted close voting as duplicate), coming along a real duplicate by just missing to research the obvious answers given in the SE site as well.

I'm nagging about those upvoted ones, that are closed as a duplicate, but still have value for future research.

Here's a sample I have at hand, and that inspired me to ask this question here:

> *"[How to build a map were the key is an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533518/how-to-build-a-map-were-the-key-is-an-enum)":*

Well, finding appropriate duplicates for a question isn't an easy job on SE, and might be awarded with some shared rep along the marked question, at least when the duped question is upvoted.

<strike>I'm pretty sure this request will receive downvotes or being declined as a feature-request. Though I'd like to see the discussion points.</strike>

Obviously this question turned out much better achieved, than I expected.
Is there any hope some reward in form of badges (I really like [Chris Spague's idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280653/1413395)), or reputation might be implemented in future?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226016/reward-duplicate-closing-5-for-the-first-voter

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52530/are-duplicates-creating-broken-windows

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230507/duplicates-mark-ii-canonicals-more-aggressive-duplicate-prevention

Comment: @Pekka웃 Oh, well! These are good links about that topic. Let me have some closer look.

Comment: One more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116087/another-take-on-canonical-answers-add-a-canonical-vote

Comment: Pekka's the leading thinker on this topic.

Comment: @Josh A fat lot of good it's done me though! I'm the #1 asker in the `status-declined` tag. Ah well. :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Seems I woke s.o. with similar thoughts ;-P ...

Comment: There are a lot of questions on this topic already.  The key points that need to be addressed for this to work is that the incentive needs to not result in abuse (flagging non-duplicates as duplicates just for the reward) and also not be more work than just providing an answer to very easy questions.  That's a very hard problem to solve.

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's kind of a neat honor.  I don't think I'd ever have thought to check tag leaderboards for meta.

Comment: @Servy We can't perfect everything from the start. I think the easy questions are already abused enough that there's no way this will be abused as much.

Comment: @simonzack If you reward people for voting to close every single question of some loosely related but clearly not a duplicate question then you end up causing a *lot* of harm.  Way more than duplicating answers to common questions in many places.  So no, you do in fact need to ensure that the system won't cause significant amounts of abuse before putting it in place.

Comment: @Servy I was actually asking about the good and appropriate choices for marked duplicates, but still getting  good acheivement or interest in the original answer.  The reward should appear along with the questions' upvotes and being achieved as useful.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's not what your question says though.  It specifically talks about rewarding people for finding and closing duplicate questions, not for having your question closed as a duplicate (although that it open to some abuses as well, i.e. the creation of intentional duplicates by sock puppets).  If that's really what you're interested in, you need to make that much clearer in the question.

Comment: @Servy But without actually trying it out in a beta there's really no way to know is there? Closest example I can think of is the current edit system, which has a small rep gain, and imo isn't abused much. I think there is a balance between the amount of rep gained to close vs the amount of rep gained to answer the easy question and get upvoted.

Comment: @simonzack Suggested edits are abused *plenty*, and that's even with a built in mechanism to prevent abuse (namely that the edits need to be approved by reviewers).  While you may not necessarily be able to know for sure what the amount of abuse there will be is without trying it out, you should absolutely be prepared to provided evidence for why the abuse of any new feature will be sufficiently small, or what tools will need to be in place to prevent/mitigate abuse.  If you can't, then clearly the proposal isn't ready for a beta.

Comment: @Servy Something similar which can be done here is to only award rep when the question is actually closed. From personal experience I *really* haven't seen that much edit abuse, a lot of them are formatting & grammar fixes which I think are helpful. Proposals may need refining, but there's no way to tell whether the negative impact will be "sufficiently small" without a trial is there? Going through with a small beta & A/B testing is already enough to limit any possible damage.

Comment: @simonzack This has all been discussed quite a lot in the duplicates, I refer you to past discussions.  I am merely saying that along with this proposal there needs to be a plan for how to prevent abuse, because of the many variations, a lot are very open to abuse.  As far as suggested edits, I've seen *lots* of abusive suggested edits when reviewing them.  Sure, there are plenty of good edits to, but to say that there is no (or even very little) abuse is just not true.  You also need to consider all of the edits submitted and rejected when considering potential abuse.

Comment: related (_not_ a duplicate): [Rewarding overzealous users for answering duplicate questions is undermining the site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265165/839601)

Comment: Soooo much irony in requesting a reward for people to find duplicates instead of posting the same question again, being a topic that has like a dozen duplicates already. I am amused.

Comment: @neminem Meta is entirely different to SO when it comes to duplicates. In SO, if the duplicate answers your question then theres no need to post another. In meta, lots of feature requests are never acted upon, and this shows the community's frustration.

Comment: @simonzack That does make sense, I suppose - that constant new posts express a lot more annoyance/interest than just upvoting old posts. It's still funny though.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you missed one http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198958/217863

Comment: It all depends on what the end game actually is. If you consider the points system on SO the reward you want to maximize, then quickly answering obvious questions before they are closed works better than helpfully directing the user to the same question and the answers attached. If you are afraid of abuses from people who would overzealously mark questions as duplicates, then at least remove the points awarded for questions that are closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give a rep incentive to users for finding accepted duplicates](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323728/give-a-rep-incentive-to-users-for-finding-accepted-duplicates)

Answer (score 54):

I believe any non-trivial reputation gains (in my opinion larger than 2, or maybe even 1), might encourage "witch hunts" of sorts. For example, after a question has been downvoted once or twice, and the first comment on the question is `Possible duplicate of [some question]`, users may instinctively flag it as a duplicate on the basis that others will similarly notice that "duplicate of ..." comment, especially if it's got upvote, and have the same mindset.

If the allure of a reputation gain overshadows the effort on the flaggers' part to *really* absorb the question and information detailed in (a) the question that is to be flagged, and (b) the potential duplicate(s), this could result in

1. An influx of duplicate flags that are reviewed and later declined, wasting the flaggers' and the mods' time, and,
2. Perfectly valid (non-duplicate, or at least unique and acceptable with a few edits) questions being instinctively dupe-flagged for the sake of reputation, and actually being closed due to the sheer number of flags that are raised on them. In other words, good, non-duplicate questions being closed because they *look* like they're duplicates, but the flaggers didn't take the time to confirm that it is genuinely a duplicate.

I'd gesture to amend the proposal to have moderation badges unique to duplicate flagging, instead of reputation gains, e.g.

[image: beautiful mspaint badge ideas]

I think limiting rewards to badges would better recognize users for dupe-flagging without enabling more rep-thirsty users to abuse the system.

Yes, this may enable the counterpart "badge-thirsty" users, but at that point it is a matter of, again, allure. Would you rather get +2 (etc.) for being the first to successfully identify a duplicate, or would you rather get just another checkmark in your progress towards a shiny new gold badge recognizing your moderation contributions? The more important question is, which do you actually deserve, if either? I think the badges are more fitting.

Comment: I would set it in sync with other similar badges, like question edit or helpful flags, so the gold badge would be **500**, not 300, but yeah, it is similar to that kind. You do not get to get reputation points for editing questions  either above 2000 rep or flagging posts. The "Beside Myself" reads quite silly though. I am still unsure why duplicates would be handled so special. I am equally annoyed when people answer primarily opinion based, broad, unclear, etc, questions instead of close voting.

Comment: @lpapp Sure, the name and number of flags required to get each badge could be discussions of their own, these are just examples I made to get my point across. If it was unclear, credit towards badges could double-count, e.g. 1 "point" towards Clone Wars would also be counted as a point towards [Deputy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/70/deputy)/[Marshal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/marshal).

Comment: Chris, did you ever post this on Meta.SE?  I think it's a great idea.

Comment: @JAL Thanks! I did not post this elsewhere. I've actually never posted in meta SE, in part because I'm concerned I might do something wrong. If you think it's a good idea, you're more than welcome to post about this there in my stead.

Comment: I think the correct name for the bronze flag would be **De**duplicator. Duplicator is the OP, the deduper is the first dupe flagger/closevoter.

Answer (score 19):

I believe this is a good idea and will result in a cleaner SE, a SE closer to the ideal one where you can always easily find the answer you're looking for.

I'm tired of seeing so many poor questions where there is already another one being asked in a perfect manner and has been answered! But I have to walk through a pile of duplicates to reach the answer.

I personally try to downvote or report it as a duplicate but **Adding a reward** will result in a **massive movement** to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: The downside is the misuse of this so that people start marking questions with "canonicals" that are actually not even dupes. That could turn out to be a scary movement, too, giving further power and opportunities for rep whores. I mark many duplicates, but not for reps and badges, but because I think it is fruitful for the site. Giving extra attention would not help me with working more on it.

Comment: A user can mark 100 posts as duplicates per day and gain 200 rep. Is it same as 10 upvotes?? (or 20 upvotes, if it is a question)
). Think about it.

Comment: @TheLostMind, come on guys! we could have smarter process than just simply gain rep for clicks, well the rep could be given if question gets more than five dup mark or if another high rep users verify the dup mark or ... I mean we could think of something

Comment: furthermore, think about the few number of decent people who try to make the site better and if their number is enough for all those dupes!! and compare it with a nicely-planned race between users to make site better!!

Comment: @lpapp Do you know how many duplicates I flag that get answered before they can be closed?  A *lot*.  It would be one thing if they were answered by low-reps that don't know the rules yet, but I see this behavior from users who have closing privileges.  What's worse is when users copy/paste the answer from the possible duplicate indicating the other question helped them.

Comment: @cimmanon: that is already partially solved by dupehammar as a "reward". There are discussions around about extending it, but then again, this reward is already in there. Giving rep for helping with such an important role is calling for trouble. It should be done naturally by trusted people and they will do it because they like the site, not for reps. [Moreover, this dupe thing is just a small slice of a bigger systematic issues](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256537/extending-the-gold-badge-rights-to-further-close-vote-reasons) about close votes. Let us fix the big problem instead.

Answer (score 1):

When I was a new SO user (and developer in general), one of the biggest challenges to finding answers online was knowing how to phrase my search query. Once I learned how to identify the meat of my problem and phrase it in key terms, I could usually find what I wanted.

When determining whether a question had already been asked, google was usually pretty good at it. On occasion, the SO similar-questions feature would help me find the information I needed that a web search didn't already find. In these cases, asking a "duplicate" question indicates a lack of due diligence.

But sometimes the "duplicate" information is from a question that doesn't look similar from a search perspective. In these cases, identifying the question as a duplicate is a consequence of advanced familiarity with the topic conversation within SO and not a consequence of negligence on the asker's part.

One approach that might address both of these scenarios is to reward marking a question as duplicate **when the asker of the question accepts the duplicate flag**. In essence, if the asker says "you are right, this is a duplicate, and the question you linked solved my problem", the person who provided the needed information is rewarded.

This approach avoids the influx of arbitrary duplicate marking because **the reward is dependent on peer review** and uses the same reward mechanism that makes question-and-answer successful. And, this approach also makes it possible to reward SO users that are taking the time to triage questions and have invested sufficient effort to recognize the duplicate information.

I believe that most people prefer to do a search before asking a question. Inasmuch as the ask-a-question path has several hints that you should be searching around first, if the user ultimately asks a question, it is because finding the answer was beyond their experience and skill level (with exceptions, of course - we are humans).

**TL;DR**
I think the key difference between the current system and what I'm describing is that a question would be closed as a duplicate when the **asker** confirms the status, rather than relying on moderator consensus. By allowing the asker to confirm the (implicit) answer, you can use the familiar, proven reward system that drives the rest of the site.

Answer (score -11):

Frankly speaking, the term *appropriate duplicate* is kind of relative. I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540045/when-exactly-i-should-go-for-inner-classes) question today. I've closed this - *not as a duplicate* but as *too broad* and I know that there are several duplicates of this question on SO. Now the question is **why?**. Because I didn't find the *answers to other questions directly answering what the OP wanted*. Lets just face it, we all (and that includes the *moderators* as well) are busy folks. We can't look into each *question* and *each answer to that question* and say - *Hey, this answers the OPs question*. Believe me, nobody wants to do it *every time*. I'd rather see [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) , [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant), [Martjin Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) answering questions than looking for duplicates. The OP can find duplicates on his own but certain *questions can be answered best by the above mentioned people*. 
Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) have been asked [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus?lq=1) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995918/java-comparison-with-of-two-strings-is-false?lq=1). Believe me, there are *several hundred* duplicates of this question. For questions like these, the duplicate can be found easily, but for questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540390/cannot-open-file-using-runtime-getruntime-exec-when-file-name-contains-special), the duplicate will be difficult to find. If found, the answers could be *inappropriate*. 
There is a reason for awarding *badges* and not *reputation points* for activities like close votes, delete, flagging because they reflect your *involvement* on the site. Rep reflects how many *questions / answers* were good. 5 down-votes are not same as an up-voted answer.

So, If it were up to me, I would reject this request.

Comment: `there are several hundred duplicates of this question` -> heh, "fun".

Comment: @lpapp - Believe me.. I see atleast one occurance of that question every day.. :P