# Award some points for marking question as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Currently there is no intensive for marking a duplicate question as a duplicate. I mean the following:

You see a question which is a clear duplicate of another* and now you have two possible ways to handle it:

1. Mark as a duplicate.
2. Copy the answer (may be not copy, but write something similar)

Clearly first solution gives you nothing, whereas the second can potentially give you some points. Not surprisingly a lot of people select the second solution.

So why not to award some points when the person correctly marks the question as a duplicate?

*) You do not need to know this beforehand, but you know it is a standard problem, you almost sure the duplicate exists and searching for a few minutes you found a duplicate.

Comment: Dupe on MSE: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5) and [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226016/reward-duplicate-closing-5-for-the-first-voter). Dupe on MSO: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280568/reward-for-close-voters-finding-appropriate-duplicates)

Comment: @Andy thank you. I have to award you some points for this. But the only thing I can is an upvote for a comment.

Comment: @Andy as far as I understood, nonetheless of almost a year and high amount of upvotes, no one from SO moderators had their say regarding this initiative.

Comment: Personally I think there should be points deducted for answering a duplicate question. There are many many people who basically look for easy to answer duplicates to get easy rep. The question will be answered and marked as answered before it gets closed as a duplicate. And once questions have an accepted answer they seem to no longer be looked at as a duplicate. Need to remove the incentive to answer.

Comment: @kjbartel I totally agree with you. I also think that the points should be removed for answering really bad questions, because they promote asking this questions.

Comment: Yep, even if there's no deduction for answering a duplicate as long as there's no gain. If a question is marked as duplicate then no reputation for answering. Which also means that questions with accepted answers should still be reviewed as duplicates. It would get rid of so much crud on the site.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions