# How is "duplicate's search" motivated by rating or badges on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Who are people who flag duplicate questions? How are they motivated to do this (highly helpful) job?

I'm asking because I do not see how the review system and provided tools could motivate anybody to search for duplicate questions (e.g., in the First Posts queue)...

Even more, I have collected all available, for me, eight Reviewer badges and could say that "duplicate" flags (in Close and Reopen queues) are easier to skip than evaluate, since evaluation of "duplicates" requires twice the energy.

Even to write an answer on a question is an easier choice than searching for duplicates (and potentially more profitable in sense of rating growth).

What don't I understand?

Comment: Closing questions as duplicates saves us from wasting the energy necessary to write the same answers over and over again. Oftentimes there’s a canonical question with The Definitive Answer™; in that case there’s really no need for thousands of other answers attempting to answer a duplicate question. I also just like similar questions linked together, if they’re asking the same or a related question. You’re right, though, that there’s no real incentive reputation- or badge-wise.

Comment: In addition to what @Xufox points out, I would also note it is easier to propose duplicate targets for questions in tags one regularly watches, as opposed to those found in the queues, as that makes one more likely to know of potential targets, and puts one in a better position to evaluate them.

Comment: After a while, you get a "feeling" whether a certain question might have been asked before. If entering the exact title into the Search box yields a satisfying result, I vote-to-close .. and downvote for "blatantly obvious no research was done". There are no benefits.

Comment: "... potentially more profitable in sense of rating growth ..." because More Questions == More $$? Having the same questions over and over again is good for the Company (per eyes*$ calculation) and good for the users who ask (because, hey, this is even better than Google!). But it is bad for the *site*, as good questions will be swamped by the low-quality stuff that everybody is always asking.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes I already _know_ “If I enter `site:stackoverflow.com ⟨specific keywords⟩` in Google, the specific question I’m looking for is within the first three results”. Sometimes what I’m looking for is within the type-ahead suggestions in the close-as-duplicate dialog or my browser history. You may have to know some Google-fu. I don’t waste a _lot_ of time searching duplicates.

Comment: I don't personally search for duplicates. But being on the site for a while and keeping up-to-date on the questions in the Android tag, as well as having done my own research for my own problems, I can usually either know a question is already a dupe or I can tell that it probably is. It's not really an active process for me.

Comment: [An unexact query showing the ones closed the most posts as dupe.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/947315/initiated-most-closures-as-dupe)

Comment: @peterh: thanks for that – and I am happy to find Wiktor Stribiżew in your top-20. He provides answers to *tons* of GREP questions, but is also very diligent with closing-as-dup.

Comment: @usr2564301 another query to show for the last 365 days : https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/425986/close-stats-for-top-dup-hammer-users

Comment: Related: [It's time to reward the duplicate finders](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394048/674039)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, there is no gamification reward on SO currently for finding duplicates.

- there is no reputation reward
- there is no badges that I know of that would encourage continuing to find duplicates (or even first one)
- searching for duplicate and possibly commenting on your closure generally takes significantly more time than providing answer essentially making negative reputation for duplicate closure.

While topic of encouraging duplicates is hot on meta [Reward for close voters finding appropriate duplicates?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280568/reward-for-close-voters-finding-appropriate-duplicates), [Remove the incentive for FGITW to answer well known dupes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes) (for more - search [rewards+duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=reward+duplicates) ). Unfortunately so far there was no clear proposal on how to make such encouragement without at least obvious issues. Also company itself never shown particular interest in the topic making it less likely to change in the future.

Comment: "there is no badges" isn't it contribute to "raise useful flag" counter?

Comment: @talex I don't know - maybe before one can actually cast close votes it would count...

Comment: @talex the useful flag only applies after someone also cast a close vote.

Comment: you can earn review badge by closing in the close queue, though

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sure, but I would not call that particularly encouraging search for duplicates. Something better than nothing I guess, but it is only for the easy part - "yes, correct duplicate". At least for me close reviews is mostly to validate existing votes rather than changing to duplicate.

Comment: me I have configured the close queue to see only python & c duplicate so I can hammer them. Efficient.

Comment: Sometimes the (proposed) duplicate is a question that you asked or answered, hence it comes to mind easily. There are ways of finding them fairly quickly, e.g. searching for `user:me is:answer [navel] foo bar` will find answers you wrote with the `navel` tag and containing `foo` and `bar`. The result _might_ include a reputation reward if your question or answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There are no direct "rewards", but sometimes you can get side upvotes when closing a question, because it gives OP (*original poster of the question*) the solution anyway, and some can reward you by visiting your profile and voting some posts (I *know* that it's *bad*, well, it happens) or on the linked question if you by chance had answered the same question at some point.

Note that you can be "rewarded" by downvotes too when OP sees closure as a punishment (which is why I usually comment on the side to give a solution when I can)

You also get more respect from established members by doing this than by answering duplicates just for easy reputation. Maybe they will comment next time you'll post a wrong question or answer instead of downvoting right away...

Apart from that it's just driven by the will to maintain the number of obvious duplicates low and keep the site searchable and clean.

Comment: I've never seriously considered that close-voting a question might attract votes (up or down) on my unrelated questions or answers.  Certainly that's inconsistent with our conventions and expectations, but the idea having been raised, I'm not naive enough to suppose that it never happens.  Nevertheless, in no way is that going to affect my close-voting decisions.

Comment: of course it shouldn't change the decisions. And if you're not abusing it, it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 5):

> Who are people who flag duplicate questions?

I am.

> How are they motivated to do this (highly helpful) job? I'm asking because I do not see how the review system and provided tools could motivate anybody to search for duplicate questions (e.g., in the First Posts queue)...

Well. I do not cross on red. I wear a bike helment when biking. I use toilets instead of wall-corners or parking garage staircases. I look/know basic dupes and tag as such. Why would I not flag?

My motivation? I wan't to leave a place better then I found it ~ or at least not worse. Flagging dupes makes SO a better place, easier to search, more conceise - that should be enough reward.

Same for flagging - it was nice to get some rep when starting it but I still flag even without rep.

> How to find dupes?

I would guess (for python, python-3.x and python-2.x) about 80%-90% of the errors are 'beginner' errors of which I know that duplicates exists - it' is simply searching and posting them.

> How do you learn what dupes exist if you are new to a tag?

I started reading the first 2-4 pages (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=votes&pageSize=50) or so of highes ranking q&A on the topic that I am active in (all 3 of them to be precise) - my guess would be this to be a good starting point for *any* language. Then you collect 5-10k points working through beginner questions and patterns emerge.

Python has typical beginner errors:

- scoping: [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)
- immutable vs mutable, ref vs value: [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)
- slicing: [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)
- classmethods vs staticmethods: [Meaning of @classmethod and @staticmethod for beginner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/meaning-of-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner)
- etc.

Searching dupes faster then other can also be a game - even without `rep` - you can read about [intrinsic motivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivation#Intrinsic_motivation) - that is far better (in the long run) then *rep*-points.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt if Stack Overflow and the rest of the Stack Exchange communities would have been half as good a resource as it is, if personal gain was the only incentive.

Duplicates are flagged by reviewers as well as by all users, basically, since users track the tags and technologies closest to them, they remember similar answers, and collectively we have read enough to know what's available, plus searching is simple and efficient.

(By the way... I did not search for duplicates before answering here...)

Comment: Searching (for duplicates) is simple and efficient?

Comment: It is surprisingly difficult to find duplicates by search, even if you already know a particular one exists (and thus already know a few exact search words).