# How to be a fair duplicate close voter

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reputation, vote-to-close

<sub>Note: I don't want to talk about [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question); I'm describing it only as an example. My question is general.</sub>

I just saw a question which is a duplicate, found a good duplicate target, and voted to close. A high-rep user (>25k rep, full privileges, gold badge in this question tag, so he won't win anything from answering) answered this question with an answer that is a duplicate to the accepted answer from duplicate question. He did it after several minutes after `Possible duplicate of ...` comment was added, so I'm sure he saw it. He got +9/-0 and accepted. I got nothing.

So, I was just trying to be a good guy and follow [SE guideline for duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/495643). But I feel discouraged by this kind of behavior. Maybe you can tell me the reasons to be a fair duplicate close voter until [this feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280568/reward-for-close-voters-finding-appropriate-duplicates) for rewarding reputation and/or badges is implemented?

EDIT: I agree that my question is duplicate but Shog9's answer isn't really answering it. I hope there could be some better explanation. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but the question can be rephrased to "Why should I close a question as duplicate instead of answering it? I get rep, the OP get answer (also +2 rep for accepting and possible upvotes while people don't know it is a duplicate), everybody is happy. Maybe it is better to mark as duplicate a day after it in order to make the network stronger associated?"

Comment: You've done your part by not answering the question. There will always be other users here who are not as responsible as you and there's not much more you can do about it beside gently pinging them. If they aren't receptive to prodding, then I can guarantee you they aren't making many friends here.

Comment: Technically there is no rule against answering any question, and no one is _required_ to vote to close anything. It's just better for the community if users don't answer duplicates and do vote to close. There are also cases where application of the solution proposed in the target may require more explanation or modifications in the context of the duplicate, in which case answering alongside voting to close is acceptable.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "But I am discouraged". Do you mean someone else is actively discouraging you from doing this, or do you mean you *feel* discouraged by what you've witnessed?

Comment: @TylerH I feel discouraged. I feel that there is some kind of "conflict of interests": it is better for community to vote to close and not give an answer but it is better for _me_ to give an answer.

Comment: It makes you look like the villain when your actions are repeatedly contradicted by other users who are "helping" instead of curating. I don't see a way around that problem other than not not curating, you're never going to look like you're doing the right thing vs the other person who is "helping"

Comment: @cs95 "If they aren't receptive to prodding, then I can guarantee you they aren't making many friends here." In my experiences regurgitating duplicate information over and over again gets you *way* more friends than closing questions as duplicates.

Comment: @TinyGiant If you feel that the other answers in the existing question(s) on the topic do not adequately answer the question asked then no, you should absolutely *not* vote to close the question as a duplicate and answer.  You should simply answer.

Comment: @Servy yes, with HVs and other FGITWers, those don't count.

Comment: @Servy I disagree, sometimes it's a duplicate but the asker of the duplicate doesn't understand how to apply the solution to the problem. It is absolutely acceptable to leave an answer explaining how to apply the solution in the duplicate to the specific application. Besides, what harm would it do? Likewise it is not against any rule to answer any question, so your argument is moot.

Comment: As with most things, it's not all black-and-white. For instance, do we really need another answer to a *typical* Java NullPointerException (NPE) question, one where the solution is to learn the steps in how to debug the problem and which is outlined well within the accepted answer to the canonical question? On the other hand, there *are* NPE questions that are unique and are worthy of separate consideration, same as for other common duplicate questions, but which are the deserving ones must remain an individual judgment call.

Comment: There is no reward of any kind for closing as duplicate. This is covered well in duplicate... and there are other discussions trying to suggest [rewards for duplicate closures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280568/reward-for-close-voters-finding-appropriate-duplicates) as you pointed out... without any success. Either find your own reward for closing as duplicates (better be strong one) or just relax :). https://www.xkcd.com/386/

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: heck there's no "reward" for reputation points either TBH. I've yet to find a coffee shop or pizza parlor that will accept them as payment. Yes, I've got some T-shirts and coffee mugs, but those don't really help me get going in the mornings.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels :) +10 virtual points is way more visible reward then "you **** could have helped and instead downtroaded my post by duplicity" comment for 10 minutes you spend searching for good duplicate.

Comment: @TinyGiant If there is another question that doesn't actually solve the problem at hand then it's not a duplicate.  Either the other question does solve the problem, in which case there's no reason to answer it, or it doesn't, and you should not be closing it as a duplicate.  The question can't both be answered by another question and also require you to answer it because the other question doesn't answer it.  The harm is either claiming another question answers it when it doesn't, or duplicating content already answered, but either way, one of the actions is wrong.

Comment: @Servy You're completely misrepresenting what I'm saying and arguing against your own representation. Regardless your argument seems to be directly counter to all guidance I have ever seen regarding duplicate closure. My point stands. Have a nice day.

Comment: First, you are not alone. A lot of users are still playing the dupe game.
We switch our gamification system from "Rep Race" to "Race the High Rep". 
When you get gud at this game you will be able to predict if your favorite 5k,25k,100k is going to answer this dupe question. 
And you will take your reward by seeing Good high rep using their hammer, to close dupe based on the 3 dupes links you just drop.
Ultimate win is when HRep delete his answer and swing the hammer using your link.

Comment: @TinyGiant How am I misrepresenting what you're saying?  What guidance have you seen that's counter to what I'm saying?  Why does your point stand?  You've made an assertion and provided no evidence to back it up, and instead just said that you're right because you say so, which doesn't actually make your point stand.