# Should any one person (or two) be able to close a question as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

When a question is closed as a duplicate, you see this;

[image]

Usually, I see multiple names here. However, a question I was looking at today was closed with only two names. Specifically, this one;

[Trying to generate all permutations from array but only getting a small subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770410/return-all-possibilities-in-an-array-in-javascript)

There is some debate about whether or not this is actually a duplicate. However, because it's been closed, it seems to be getting very little attention and therefore seems unlikely to be re-opened.

It has an equal number of upvotes and downvotes. That seems to be indicative of a divided opinion.

I can't help but think that to close a question, a community consensus should be formed - i.e, at least 4 or 5 people should have to agree **before** the question is closed as it is unlikely to receive the necessary attention **afterwards**.

Maybe this doesn't happen enough to be an issue, and I guess that users can post here to have their question re-opened if they disagree.

**Edit to explain *why I believe* this is not a duplicate (irony)**: The proposed dupe target is asking for the results of the evaluation of Mjölnir after its initial introduction 5 years ago. It's also 4 years old.

My question has a very specific focus - when there is an equal balance of opinion, should one user be able be able to make a unilateral decision to close it as a duplicate?

Comment: [Related post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298807/7296893). The dupehammer apparently is a _resounding success_ in the latest evaluation (4 years ago), so I'd say yes, single persons should be able to close questions as a duplicate.

Comment: @ErikA Fair point. However, the top comment on that post essentially summarises my point - and many people seem to agree. As you note, that post is 4 years old and was a resounding success *at that time*. However, I guess if it’s worked for that long... Perhaps they should be able to close the question with only one vote if after 5 minutes, it still has negative reputation.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that in the *rare* case where a gold-badge holder makes a *mis-judgement* the OP merely has to refine the question to say **why it is not a duplicate**.

Comment: One point of the dupehammer is to be able to shoot down low-hanging fruit that's been asked over and over again with speed and precision. Those kind of questions can sometimes have 2-3 answers in the first 5 minutes, if one becomes accepted the question won't get cleaned up, so I would say that's not a great suggestion.

Comment: @yivi I don’t necessarily want to turn off the dupehammer. It seems like a good thing to have for questions that are “clearly” duplicates. In this particular instance though, there is a divided opinion amongst people who have interacted with that question (two votes for, two against) - which has been overruled by the gold badger. I won’t bother with the feature request - as you say, it works.

Comment: Up/Down Votes are not related to closing questions so that's not relevant.

Comment: @Paulie_D I think they mean the question has two reopen votes. Which is related to [this other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386474/is-a-question-asking-for-help-fixing-a-bug-a-duplicate-of-a-question-on-solving)

Comment: Ironically, no "divided" opinion here. If it works, it works.

Comment: @yivi It specificly states in this question: _It has an equal number of upvotes and downvotes. That seems to be indicative of a divided opinion._ OP shouldn't even be able to see how many re-open votes there are based on their rep.

Comment: Yes, you are right @André. Thought about that later.

Comment: People are aware that the dupe hammer has the potential for abuse. However, I don't think anyone ever saw clear abuse from it. Misguided choices/mistakes made? Sure. But it can be solved with the community voting to reopen, or another badge holder reopening

Comment: @Patrice I just want to **_make it very clear_** that I was **not** accusing Jack of "absuing" his dupehammer - I just wanted to raise the point that if as many people think it should be open as they do closed, should one single person be able to override this and close it? Which has been answered pretty emphatically by the comments above. In response to Paulie_D regarding votes not being tied to closing a question, while true they seem to go fairly hand in hand (a user who upvotes a question probably won't vote to close it) hence why I thought it was relevant to mention.

Comment: @lewis no no you can question. Rep != Always correct. The point is just that the high rep badge holder has proven they understand the subject matter at hand, so they are given a bit more power. Realistically I think people know it could lead to abuse, but haven't seen enough issues with the usage of the dupe hammer to warrant changes (and I didn't mean to imply you said there was abuse here. I was replying to your 'if it works, it works').

Comment: I have actually upvoted a number of duplicate question. A duplicate doesn't automaticly mean it's a bad question. Sometimes it's simply a great question that just uses different names/explenation/whatever.

Comment: @Andre If you really believe that it's a dupe, you probably shouldn't upvote it. From the upvote tooltip, "This question shows research effort..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the dupehammer (Mjölnir) still being evaluated, and if so, what is the current outcome?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298807/is-the-dupehammer-mj%c3%b6lnir-still-being-evaluated-and-if-so-what-is-the-curren)

Comment: @Lewis - ??? There are cases where pretty much no amount of research would get you to duplicate *unless you know the answer*. These are exactly the questions we want to upvote as "useful signpost" but keep closed as duplicates. Thus question can *show* research just fine (and hence avoid initial downvotes) and get a lot of visits/votes later due to being useful on its own (despite closed as duplicate).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the Mjölnir only worked in the presence of a 2 or more close votes to constitue some kind of "majority", it would be very ineffectual.

The dupe-hammer is there to allow to close dupes quickly. Both to help the OP and to impede other users posting fast me-to answers to already answered questions.

To be effective, Mjölnir needs to work even if it's the first close vote casted.

Re-open votes come **after** the post is closed, so they could not impact the working of the dupe-hammer.

Question score is irrelevant. A question can be highly upvoted and still a duplicate. Score and close votes are independent, and should remain so.

<sup>Tangentially, the idea of having an additional *"Silver Mjölnir"* for silver badge holders that counted as "three dupe votes", and would thus require two additional close votes to work, I find more interesting. Although I'm sure it has been proposed already.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your patience Yivi. I guess that makes sense. Although in an ideal world that would work fine, eyeballs tend to drop on questions that are closed as reputation is unlikely to be gained from them - meaning getting enough people with either the vote open privilege or a gold badge user to see it becomes difficult. I now understand that this is mitigated somewhat by the review queue so it probably isn't as big an issue as I originally thought it was. The idea of a Silver Mjölnir that you mention would be the sort of counterbalance idea I was hoping for.

Comment: I think this "silver badge counts as 3" is a very nice idea, if it wasn't proposed until now (resulting a dupe :-) ), it should be.