# Create "near-moderators" who are solely focused on "ordinary" review queues or tag cleanup

Tags: feature-request

Now that it's moderator election season, it was occurring to me: most of the moderators seem largely focused on handling flags, chasing down sock puppets, etc. This makes sense because these are things that the community can't necessarily do itself.

It was occurring to me, though: it would be exceptionally useful to have "moderator-like" powers (e.g. "insta-close") for tag cleanup and burniation.

In addition to "regular" moderators, can we appoint people who have "moderator-like" powers in very limited contexts (e.g. in tags that are subject to cleanup or burniate requests)?

Comment: Well, those with 10k+ have some moderator-like functionality, as do those with 20k+, and of course those with gold badges in a tag can dupe close with Mjolnir. There have been a number of requests to expand those powers to help with burnination and the like, but as far as I know, no successful ones. For instance, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256537/215552 for gold badges.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That's true, but no one has Mjolnir for minor tags, and the problem with a lot of tags in need of cleanup is an overwhelming number of off-topic questions.

Comment: We simply need more community involvement in the moderation process. Pushing that off to a select few "near" moderators isn't going to make a big enough dent. How do we do that *without* gamifying it?

Comment: How about if we just granted more powers to people with gold tag badges in that tag? *Why haven't we done that yet?!?*

Answer (score 1):

The only times I can recall moderators stepping in with a large tag burnination cleanup/tag cleanup was to handle the stuff that the community *literally* couldn't handle on its own, such as removing locked posts.  Everything else, in large enough numbers, can be handled by the community.

We don't need *more* moderator firepower in this capacity, since:

- Burnination *can* and often is largely handled by the community-at-large
- Moderators need only be called in for those special situations, like actual exception handlers
- Adding more users to the election to be given moderator-lite powers would serve to complicate the system of elections for lateral (if any) gains

Comment: ... also, community consensus is important with large scale efforts such as burninations, especially when deletion is involved. I'm not sure it would be beneficial in situations where there is a lot of borderline content or content that would require any amount of domain knowledge to determine on-topicness.