# How can I not use my instant close privilege?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I have recently gained a gold tag badge which allows me to instantly close C# questions without needing the usual five close votes. Sometimes I think it probably wants to be closed but would be more comfortable waiting for consensus via the five close vote requirement.

I have noticed on a question that Jon Skeet seems to have voted to close without actually forcing a close (*[Convert a hexadecimal key to decimal key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591707/convert-a-hexadecimal-key-to-decimal-key)*), so I assume this is possible - I just can't see where there is an option for this...

So how can I vote to close a C# question without instantly closing it?

Comment: *"I have noticed on a question that Jon Skeet seems to have voted to close without actually forcing a close"* - He voted to close for a different reason than "duplicate".

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253324/give-high-rep-users-extra-weight-on-close-votes#comment12953_253324

Comment: @Peter: I understand the edits to change c# to C# and 5 to five but I'm curious why you decided to italicise the link - I wondered if there was some kind of style guide but the link and text were generated by just pasting the url so if there was a styleguide I'd have thought it was auto implemented. So I'm curious - why the italic edit?

Comment: The only logic I can see behind italicizing the link is following style guides that recommend italicizing titles of publications. Of course, that's only for lengthy publications, like books, so it wouldn't even apply to a SO question. And there's no "house" style guide that recommends this. Entirely up to taste.

Comment: @CodyGray: Cool. Thanks. Things like spelling out numbers and correct capitalization of C# made sense as objectively more correct. I was just surprised by somebody editing personal style preferences into somebody else's post. Though for much the same reason it surprised me it was done I won't bother actually editing it back. Mainly I was just curious. :)

Comment: Peter is a *very* prolific editor, and I'm pretty sure he uses an automated script to help him out. This is probably just something he has programmed into the script. I wouldn't think too much of it. He really does improve the overall quality, even if it comes as a bit of a surprise to many, especially on a relatively small site like Meta.

Comment: @CodyGray: gish yes! I hope I didn't come across as complaining! The other edits were minor but I was definitely happy to see them and think they made the post better, even if just in a small way. It was genuine curiosity and the automated script would make a lot of sense (especially on a site full of coders). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a dupe hammer. **You can use it to close question as duplicate only**.

For other close reasons you don't have 100% weight (only moderators can close questions in other reasons with one vote).

Quoting @RobertLongson

> you can dupe hammer questions where the tag is added later as long as you weren't the one adding the tag

Comment: you can dup hammer questions where the tag is added later as long as you weren't the one adding the tag.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson answer updated

Comment: Ah, it seems I had misunderstood what the privilege allowed.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that Jon Skeet hasn't voted for a duplicate, but the other close voters.

If a question is closed as duplicate, it shows every close voter in the list (even if this person has voted for another reason).

If I recall correctly, there was a feature request against this behaviour, but I can't find it.

That said, to my knowledge it is not possible to disable the dupe-hammer.

Comment: The dupe hammer is actually not that bad - I am usually pretty confident if something is a duplicate compared to whether I think something is unclear, etc.