# How can I give up my dupe hammer?

Tags: support

Similar to [this other Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354771/how-can-i-not-use-my-instant-close-privilege), but I'm specifically asking how I can *completely* revoke my own privilege to unilaterally mark a question as a duplicate.

I don't want this level of power - I am often wrong, and if I mistakenly close something as a duplicate, or specify the wrong thing that it's a duplicate of, then other users cannot correct me without a lot more effort.

Is there some way for me to not have this power, and go back to just having a single duplicate vote?

Comment: The normal Answer is: NO. But there is 1. The hard way: Get under the 1000 net upvotes that gave you the badge. 2. The easy way: Just place a comment on the post about the duplicate, but don't close vote. 3. The hack: Remove the tag that gives you the power, place your close vote. Then add the tag back. 4. The sock: Create a new account and use that instead of your current one. (Be careful to not double up/down vote or accidentally vote on your own stuff with that. Stay away from any posts that this account came near)

Comment: "then other users cannot correct me without a lot more effort" Is it really that much effort to @ mention you in a comment and for you to reopen?

Comment: You can always *manually* add a "Does this answer your question? \[Title\]\(URL\)" comment.

Comment: What happens if you *flag* as a duplicate? Does it automatically gets converted to a *close* vote and closes the question unilaterally?

Comment: @Tomerikoo You can't flag as a dupe once you have the close vote privilege https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269745

Comment: @Tomerikoo Users with the [cast close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege cannot close *flag* a post. They can only close *vote* a post.

Comment: @Scratte your comment should be an answer

Comment: Fundamentally I disagree that this is a good mentality to have about this.  You have a **gold badge** in a subject matter.  You've answered a lot of questions, and have answered them well.  There are a myriad of other gold badge Python holders who haven't been shy about using their powers for either direction, and you should be able to lean on their support in some capacity to help you out.  If you're confident enough to close a question as a duplicate with *one* vote, you should be confident in doing it with a single binding vote.  Otherwise, just don't close questions as duplicates.

Comment: @HereticMonkey If OP did not comment on the post then commenting `@GreenCloakGuy` into the void to has very low discoverability; almost non-existent. There is no hint which makes this obvious and even if you do know that it exists then you have to get over the confidence hurdle of not knowing you did it right. If I recall correctly then I must have hit 10k rep before I discovered you can ping people who did not comment. That ability is just an after-thought masquerading as a feature. Also, I believe low-rep users don't even know who closed their question unless they check the activity history.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The discoverability of the feature is not something I can do anything about (and SO has so far been quite quiet on the subject), and is not related to how much work it takes to use it. Anyone can know who closed their own question by looking at the blue box that appears on the question when closed; it lists all of the people who voted to close the question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Something has changed. Here is one of my questions that got closed a few years ago: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QCms.png so if you see something different at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706922/visually-follow-item-as-it-moves-in-a-list then let me know.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0JHF.png is what I see. I assumed, since it says "viewable by the post author and..." that authors saw the same thing. If I'm wrong, I apologize.

Comment: @HereticMonkey They recently enacted some change in which you have to have enough rep to see the names of users which close-voted a question but I believe there must be a bug if 17k rep is not enough. At any rate, I have to view the timeline at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29706922/timeline and see that Barmar closed it. Getting to the timeline isn't exactly the most prominent button either...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yeah, that's kind of dumb if you can't tell who closed your question. I'm not a big fan of quite a number of the changes they made to the close messages. Except the blue, I like the blue ;).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Don't get me wrong, I understand the desire to hide close-voters names and hinder discoverability of the `@editor/closer` but given this fact I don't think it's realistic to say "Is it really that much effort to @ mention" because the reality is: Yes, it can be quite difficult.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the "viewable by the post author and..." [only applies to the reason, not the close voters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354305/241919).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't not use your dupe hammer.

Because you have the gold tag badge the system thinks you know enough about the subject to be trusted to close duplicates alone.

If you're "often wrong" (in your own words) then just don't vote to close as a duplicate unless you're 100% certain that the question is a duplicate. Perhaps restrict yourself to looking at questions that already have one close vote to see what other people are suggesting. Then if you agree you can use your vote to close the question. If not then just move on to the next question.

If you are unsure you can, as Scratte mentions in [their comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405088/how-can-i-not-use-my-dupe-hammer/405089#comment823616_405088), just leave a comment to the proposed duplicate. Others can then review your suggestion that way.

None of the other close votes take your gold tag badges into account so remain unaffected.

The only way to not have the power is to lose the tag badge.

Comment: I agree and it saves a lot of other users time. Many users ask questions without putting any effort in finding the solution (sometimes google "error message" gives SO topic on top of the search results).

Answer (score 3):

I heartily agree with [ChrisF](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/)'s comment in the third paragraph of their [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405089):

> Perhaps restrict yourself to looking at questions that already have one close vote to see what other people are suggesting

I have my filter on the Close Votes Review queue set to duplicates in the tags I have hammers in. That way I *only* see posts that other users have already voted to close as duplicates. This allows me to be really efficient with my close votes, but it is still surprising how many times I hit "Leave Open" or "Skip".

And just as I use "Skip" a lot in the review queue, I do the same on posts that I see outside the queue, unless they are an obvious duplicate (frequently that I have seen many times before).