# What can I do in common, to avoid getting "revenge downvotes" for comments / close-, down-votes

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I frequently experience kind of *revenge* or even serial downvotes in response to down or close votes I applied to a completely unrelated post. I'm asking myself (and readers of this post), ***what I can do*** to avoid such negative reactions.

I know these will be usually automatically reversed whenever detected as unusual behavior. Though I want to improve my own behavior to prevent this at all. IMHO usually I'm commenting comprehensively on my down/close votes, if they're worth it.

I have the feeling that some people asking likely feel dumb and being exposed as being such, after comprehending such comments. That's usually not my intend, but I can't help much :P ...

But what would you suggest, I can actively can do better, to prevent this in 1st place?

I'm still not willing to give answers (I rather tend just close voting) for either

- Poorly asked questions, that don't show any efforts to resolve obvious problems
- Questions that already contain the solution of the problem, but the pointers gathered are simply misinterpreted
- Questions that can be solved by just reading the commonly accessible documentation

**UPDATE:**
Yes, after attending to my recent comments again, taking the other kind of glasses, I have to admit, I'm tending to be **sarcastic** in numerous comments without explicitly stating this. That's may be not the best idea!
THX for the answers so far! I'm honestly looking how to improve (even though this might involve a psychotherapy, which I'm not willing to go under, as I prefer I am just what I am and I know well!).

**Another update:**
Improving my behavior seems to work best when I'm all out of my up-/down-/close- voting fu. I really should get more in charge what I'm doing/saying here (IMHO that doesn't involve a psychotherapy, and I think I can behold and get more calm on this just disciplining myself).

Comment: Don't leave a comment, perhaps?

Comment: I always leave plenty of comments when downvoting and / or closing, but I rarely receive a serial downvote. What is the *tone* your your comments? What type of posts do you find downvote or close-vote worthy? How do you interact with those that express disagreement with you?

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes, not disclosing yourself might be a strategy, but that doesn't seem to be really helpful :-/ ...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think I'm pretty friendly most of the times, unless I find some really annoying or rude responses :P ...

Comment: A quick look over your recent comments shows nothing out of the ordinary, certainly. :-) Sorry, had to ask, you'd be surprised at the sense of entitlement some people have.

Comment: Other than *pick your battles carefully* (e.g. learn to recognise the kind of poster where feedback is not going to make any difference), I cannot offer anything other than *shrug it off*. Serial voting is reverted, as you already stated. If you receive a regular serial voting spree, see if there is a pattern in your commenting behaviour that can be adjusted.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I often don't comment when I downvote.

Comment: Ha, I was just on the other side of this. Someone sarcastically left a close comment on my question. When I, also sarcastically, called them out on not understanding the question it started one of those nerd back and forth that I hate stack overflow for. Today, surprise, surprise, I've got 2 unrelated posts that have been down-voted. I blame it on discouraging people from saying hello and thank you. When you actively discourage common courtesy and try to dehumanize the user-base, you get a dehumanized user-base.

Comment: @spinlock _"Ha, I was just on the other side of this. Someone sarcastically left a close comment on my question."_ Not by me at least? Or do you have a proof? I've changed that behavior, at least after digging the answer here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Oh no, I didn't mean to imply that it was you. I don't even mind the sarcasm. But, as I was reminded just this friday, irony doesn't work on the internet and we should all try to be conscious that others might misinterpret our jokes as being more mean spirited than we intended.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In general, the only way to truly avoid revenge downvotes from people angry about being downvoted or having their questions closed is to avoid commenting on them. Revenge downvotes happen, because some people take votes rather personally.

That said, you have been a little abrasive with some of your comments lately, and we've been picking up flags on a number of them. I pointed one of these out to you recently. If a question is bad, downvote, vote to close as appropriate, and move on. There's no need to be impolite on top of that, and by doing so you make yourself more likely to be targeted by revenge votes.

In particular, I have been a bit concerned about the comments you have been leaving on several answers to questions you deemed unfit for the site. You have downvoted and left rather negative comments on helpful answers left to bad questions, and I would prefer that you stop that. Non-deleted examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341918/how-to-determine-the-duplicated-number-in-c-program-what-is-the-code-for-that#comment37632184_24341992), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272262/i-need-to-swap-out-two-values-in-a-string-for-one-c/24272778#comment37501303_24272778), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272262/i-need-to-swap-out-two-values-in-a-string-for-one-c/24272778#comment37500385_24272364). I've personally removed several others.

I've [stated this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255782/shouldnt-we-revert-reputation-gains-for-answers-to-closed-questions/255805#255805), but going after those answering what you feel are bad questions is ultimately counterproductive. People mostly answer questions because they want to help, and because doing so is a fun challenge. The last thing we want to do is chase away subject matter experts because they were helping the "wrong" people. Driving experts away from bad questions won't stop those questions from being asked, in the end, because very few people think they are asking bad questions. Bad askers will keep asking on Stack Overflow as long as it sits atop the search rankings, and it won't matter if similar questions get answers or not. Insulting experts who answer these questions only will sour them on the site and deprive us of their expertise.

Comment: You don't have any option to stay anonymous if you cast a close vote. Or am I missing something? The names of the people casting the votes are shown in the light blue box under the question with the "put on hold as..." message.

Comment: OK, thanks! That's a really comprehensive answer, I can take on to improve my behavior in the future! As stated, I hate feeding help vampires, though this might not be a reason to react negatively on giving answers for them.

Comment: I have decided to change my [profile statements a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96), because of this answer ...

Comment: @brad-larson OK, [that one's an extreme sample (maybe because I was thinking to talk to a lady)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393633/how-i-can-get-through-this-errors-in-c-simple-program-with-json?noredirect=1#comment37731326_24393633). But I think I'm going to improve, you see? I'll keep your advice in mind for future. Working on the close voting queue is a tough task, I see! I'm not working directly on it but sending many questions to be closed specifically being tagged [tag:c++] (which is my main feed used on SO).

Answer (score 20):

I have to say, this doesn't surprise me.  I've been cringing at your comments; they are not fun to read, not infrequently missing the mark, and often very unconstructive.

This does have side-effects; they always do, regardless whether it is right or wrong. Programmers behave like people, and they can't always keep the professional attitude turned on consistently. It isn't uncommon in the [c++] tag; I've seen the experience described funnily as "falling in the C++ shark tank". But it has never once ended well for the users that do the shark a lot. They've all stopped visiting. You'll have to tone it down, if you can.

Comment: As you're one of my most favorite people here, I probably should seriously consider what you're saying :/ ! Yes, at least some of my very last comments seem to improve this. I'll try to adapt my tone to be more positive and constructive.

Comment: And I can convice what you're saying about the _' [tag:c++] tag'_ shark tank. I have to commit I've being one of these  _'sharks'_ from my [very first day appearing at the c++ forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/de.comp.lang.c++). I always required questioners to sort out, and being clear for _"microsoft c++"_ and standard c++ compliance. You tend to serve them smoothly, with deep knowledge about the commons and the actual differences. I admire this, but can't do myself (I'm too much distracted of thinking about M$ solutions being helpful to standardize may be).

Comment: That would be another example, covered well by [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/is-m-for-microsoft-allowed-considered-ok).

Comment: I'm not really using `"M$"` to invalidate solutions in general (I'm not that _'childish'_), they're just tend to miss being very well compatible with the c++ standard solutions. And that was well from the beginning. MFC had it's world and flaws, and ATL was better but had also flaws (and wasn't that widely adopted). So I always had my reasons to argue ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I remember coming across some of your comments as well, and perceiving them as unusually blunt, or sounding borderline rude. It's not even what you are saying, just the tone of it. For example, scanning through a few pages of your most recent comments, most of them end in an exclamation point, and quite frequently "!!" or "!?!", which makes it sound like you're shouting at people. I know that SO encourages communication to be clear and concise, but I believe you can get your point across just as clearly without sounding as confrontational as you sometimes do.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Interesting, how people perceive this particular interpunctuation! Yes, I'm doing so frequently. I use _"?!?"_ to mark, _'go rethink it!_ mostly, or a simple _"!!"_ when I think there's something obviously missed. Thanks, I'll consider this when commenting in future.

Comment: @RetoKoradi And I'm using this particular interpuctuation also to urge an OP to respond. Yes you are right, I'm looking for confrontation in most of these points, but it rarely helps :( ... It's may be the same bad as asking for getting asnwers _"ASAP"_.

Comment: @RetoKoradi At least your comment looks being another answer to this question here. I'm really willing to improve my behavior and want others being able to find how to as well. I'm not whining with this question, but just want to have some more insight what's going on ...

Comment: Improving your English skills might help. It looks like you often type the wrong words or leave words out: "I can convice what you're saying", "I have to commit I've being one of these", "your comment looks being".

Comment: @AndrewMedico I'm not a native speaker, do you refer to just simple typos, or more serious errors? Usually I'm experiancing to communicate with even native english speakers pretty well and fluently. I seriously doubt, that all this should be the final source of confusion :-/ ...

Comment: @AndrewMedico I meant _'confirm'_ instead of _'convince'_ of course, consider this a _typo_ please! The other error samples aren't that clear for me ...

Comment: Without seeing the context... `I have to admit I've been one of those` (or `I have to admit to being one of those`), `your comment looks like`

Comment: @Basic THX, I see, yes!

Answer (score 7):

The obvious solution is to stop communicating with the vampires.

While I cannot prove it, I strongly suspect that the sort of person who would make the pointless gesture of revenge of a downvote is the sort of person who is probably posting crap in the first place.

So, don't engage. Don't comment unless you are really looking for clarification. Don't bother to offer helpful advice to someone who clearly couldn't be bothered to read the FAQ.

Or, on the other hand, note that these 'little smatterers' (to quote Isaac Newton) can't do any real damage to your overall rep, and shrug it off.

Comment: Seems that I'm still a _'too friendly'_ person! Though I hate help vampires, and usually don't leave any comments there. Anyway the typical _'help vampire'_ doesn't have enough fu to downvote me ;) ...