# Why are so many people abusing the IDE tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

> Use for questions about using Android Studio, an official IDE targeted at Android development. ***Do NOT use for questions about programming for Android in general; instead use [android]***.

But so many people violate the rule in bold. Lots of programming-specific questions are tagged with Android Studio. Shouldn't this be taken into more consideration? I keep editing the tags, yes, but I think people should consider using this tag properly.

Comment: The XCode tag suffers the same fate.

Comment: VisualStudio as well.  Some people apply every tag which might possibly apply.  it's an every day problem that will absolutely not go away.  Learn to live with it, unfortunately, is your only solution.

Comment: Lots of new programmers think that visual studio et all is *part* of the programming language they are using rather than a tool to facilitate it

Comment: tl;dr people don't know tags

Comment: That text is hidden away in an obscure corner.  Given that people do not read the text that is shoved in their face (the how to ask a good question text), why would you expect them to read this?  It is just another piece of ignored text.

Comment: Can I answer 'because people don't like to read things' and knock off for lunch?

Comment: Related [People don't read the tag excerpts because we don't swat them into their faces](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114)

Comment: A lot of Android questions get tagged "xml" as well, when the question has nothing to do with XML per se. It's so pervasive that it's very hard to put a stop to it.

Comment: @Sayse Visual Studio is more than IDE though, it's a collection of compilers as well. In that sense is it is "part of the programming language they're using", or at least the specific variant of the programming language they're using. For C++ questions at least, it can be very important to know which C++ compiler is being used.

Comment: @RossRidge - Its been a while since I last installed visual studio but I believe the compilers are optional pre-requisites that you install separately, they're not built in to visual studio. Either way if that were the case and part of the issue then the asker should be tagging the compiler

Comment: @Sayse The fact that you have control over what compilers you can install doesn't change the fact that "Visual Studio" as a product is more than just an IDE. The fact that the tag [visual-studio] is only supposed to refer to the IDE part of Visual Studio is inconsistent with reality.

Comment: @RossRidge "The fact that the tag [visual-studio] is only supposed to refer to the IDE part of Visual Studio is inconsistent with reality" well, your face is inconsistent with reality! More seriously, that's why we have tag excerpts, but [People don't read the tag excerpts because we don't swat them into their faces](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114)

Comment: @Sayse: There's a `[visual-c++]` tag for Microsoft's compiler and language extensions.  As Ross points out, that compiler is part of the default setup for the IDE, so it's easy to understand why confused beginners or lazy taggers use `[visual-studio-2010]` or something for questions about the compiler or language (or even for questions that aren't specific to MSVC, but the OP either doesn't know that or isn't sure and tags with their environment just to give more information).

Comment: @PeterCordes Common practice seems to be to use [visual-c++] in common with a version specific [visual-studio-20xx] tag to indicate the particular version of Visual C++. The [visual-c++-20xx] tags don't get much use. I don't you can blame that on confused beginners or lazy taggers.

Comment: @RossRidge: I was talking about cases where the `[visual-c++]` tag is omitted entirely, or where it would be better to just state the version they happen to be using in the question, instead of tags.  I didn't even know there were tags for specific MSVC++ versions.

Comment: I didn't expect this question to become this popular :|

Comment: Apparently hate topics are the best :P

Comment: I even reject edits once in a while where someone will come along and try to add an IDE tag to a question where it clearly isn't needed.

Comment: Welcome to planet Earth...

Comment: The ones that annoy me the worst are generic language-agnostic algorithm questions that have a sprinkling of random language and IDE tags to get maximum views.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The main thing to do about cases like this is to **remove the tag** if it genuinely doesn't apply to the IDE itself.  This isn't a new problem; this happens a lot with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions which also happen to have either [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) or [netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans) or [bluej](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluej) or [intellij-idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) or some miraculous combination of all the above in the tag list as well.

Since you're < 2K rep I would discourage you directly from trying to just edit the tags, but if you do see this *and* you can improve the rest of the question, then that is one more improvement that you can make.

Comment: A little question, usually edit that only move some tags are supposed to be considerer as too little change to be accepted in a review. So as a > 2k rep user, if i see a really relevant tag to be added/removed should i just add it ?

Comment: That should be fine.  Be careful about adding the wrong or unnecessary tags since that introduces another problem.

Comment: Eh, <2kers shouldn't be discouraged from small but good edits. Full stop. It's very hard getting them to edit later on, so discouraging them now is not a good course of action.

Comment: @Braiam:  Editing a tag is minor enough that it often overlooks other, more serious issues with the post.  I would trust that a 2K user should be able to just edit the tag (although if they did see other things, editing that would be a win too), whereas edits that are being actively *reviewed* would also fix up other parts of the post.  What would be *worse* is if an otherwise valid tag edit was rejected because other parts of the post were left in a bad state.

Comment: If you're under 2k rep, editing questions to make them better is *exactly* what you should do, and fixing tags is part of that. It's less glamorous than asking/answering questions, but it builds reputation just as well and improves the community as a whole. In short, yes, fix tags, but do it while improving the question.

Answer (score 8):

There are many tags abused that way to try *flying under the radar* of the major sharks of particular language *shark tanks*.

And yes, that seems to be a problem, since many crap questions made it to get just through (for a while).

I'm trying to overcome that, checking almost every question coming in from the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) newest queue, while I'm active. Regardless of very specialized additional tags.

Also don't hesitate to propose edits removing these tags as they are recognized irrelevant.

---

If that tag you're referring to appears in the tag wiki info, you can restate it in a comment.

Such is annoying to do over and over again, yes. But there are tools (like [AutoReviewComments](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/bcfoamnigomkoaaiceppbbdlembpeejc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)), that may come in handy.

Comment: I'm going through all the Android Studio new questions and trying to clean it. It gets annoying.

Comment: @AbAppletic Go forward become a ***shark*** for your favorite tags. If you're annoyed bite, and flag/vote. If you're even not annoyed bite. Leave comments why such stuff is crap (beware not becoming rude). Support other sharks upvoting their comments.

Comment: Beware the shark.... <(((">

Comment: please define sharks and shark tanks in this context

Comment: @Almo The term is pretty common: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261274/what-can-i-do-in-common-to-avoid-getting-revenge-downvotes-for-comments-clo/261280#261280

Comment: I've never heard it until today.

Comment: @Almo: it's a [metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor). Here it means "a person behaving like a shark." But, like jokes, being explained kind of ruins the effect.

Comment: *"Go forward become a shark... beware not becoming rude"* - you mean this [shark](http://dreamworks.wikia.com/wiki/Lenny)?