# Am I right in removing the [github] tag from (some) [git] questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm asking this question, because I might be doing it wrongly - or not - depending what the answer to the question is.

I sometimes remove the [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github) tag from Git questions where it does not matter that the project is hosted on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub). Sometimes they are just Git questions where the OP added the GitHub tag (novices tend to understand `Git` and `GitHub` being the same; they don't know the differences), so I remove the tag and add the [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) tag. Some other times however, these are questions about Git which *are* hosted on GitHub.

Let's take for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037476/fork-not-in-sync-with-local-clone) question. The question - even though his source is hosted on GitHub - has nothing to do with GitHub whatsoever. The source could be hosted on any other Git service and the question would be exactly the same. So I removed the [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github) tag (he re-added it shortly after I removed it). So now I'm asking, am I right in removing it?

Comment: Programmers use github, news at eleven.

Comment: It's even sponsored.

Comment: So what if it is sponsored? If the question is not about Github, it should not have the tag. No?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure. I thought OP is asking if we should have that tag (previous title: "*What is the [github] tag for*").

Comment: That example of yours may well be github specific, though, @tkausl. The OP is mentioning explicitly that they are using github. I would not remove the tag from a question like that.

Comment: My title was a bit misleading - I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @Pekka웃 It's not, thats the point. You'd have the same problem with any other service. Pulling from github isn't any different than pulling from somewhere else. The problem is, that he has unstaged changes locally and can not merge in the remote branch, that the remote is github in this case does not matter at all to the question/answer.

Comment: @tkausl yeah, I understand, but if the OP is *explicitly* mentioning github then I'd leave it. It's a grey area and I'd let them have it if they insist (but maybe leave a comment explaining that it's not a github specific thing)

Comment: It probably doesn't hurt to use *both* tags.  If it's only tagged `git`, eventually someone is going to ask the question of whether this is hosted on github or not.  Maybe not for this question, but it's not uncommon for questions to have implementation specific answers.  (ie: *Oh, well if you're hosted on github you can do X, which is a bit easier, otherwise generally just Y*)...

Comment: Related:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326237/1079354

Comment: @J...:  The point is to determine if it helps.  If you're asking a question about Git and you just so happen to use GitHub, but your question has *nothing* to do with GitHub, why are you including that extra bit of information?

Comment: @Makoto - because often when you don't know the answer to a question, it can be difficult to determine which factors are relevant and which aren't?

Comment: @Jules that's easy to know: if you replace X for Y, do the problem nature goes away? Nope? Then neither X or Y are relevant.

Answer (score 114):

Yes.

[github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github) tag should only be added to [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) questions if it asks about something specific to GitHub. The fact that OP hosts their Git repository on GitHub is not a reason to use that tag. Similarly, you won't use [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) tag for your question just because the code you're asking about was written in Visual Studio.

Comment: *"Similarly, you won't use visual-studio tag for your question just because the code you're asking about was written in Visual Studio."* [\[citation needed\]](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38055017/2)

Comment: s/won't/really shouldn't/ @Braiam.

Comment: @Braiam By "you" I meant "a sane person".

Comment: @Gothdo: So, just you and me?

Comment: @Deduplicator Who told you that I'm sane?

Comment: Your analogy doesn't work in practice. Half the [java] specific questions are tagged [eclipse]. That's why I remove this the same way like the OP, when the problem doesn't relate to the IDE at all.

Comment: @Bananeweizen errr... he was just using a example. His logic is flawless.

Comment: @Braiam: Sorry for being unclear. I'm with Gothdo here. I meant to express that also within the visual-studio or eclipse tags many people are doing it wrong, which is why the analogy might not be a convincing argument for those people.

Comment: @Bananeweizen if course it would not convince them, they are not sane

Answer (score 19):

What if GitHub provides a one click solution to the problem/or provide a one click solution to the problem in future where it would take manually executing multiple Git commands to solve otherwise?

The fact that OP is using GitHub service seems to be crucial for me. So that the answerers can provide a simpler answer pointing to GitHub UI when there is one. Of course they can also provide Git — only answers since there is a Git tag as well.

Is GitHub tag doing any harm? Is it wasting the time of Git experts opening the question to provide a Git based answer? No.

I wouldn't suggest removing the GitHub tag if OP is using GitHub. That removes the possibility of simpler answers based on GitHub UI being posted (Maybe not available now, but in future).

Comment: It seems to me that the appropriate way to indicate that OP is amenable to an answer utilizing GH features would be in the content of the question itself, rather than as a tag.

Comment: I'd agree with this. You'd tag a SQL question as SQL Server or MySql etc. so people have some context to answering. I'd bet there are many questions that have a different answer given further context.

Comment: @SLC That’s very different. SQL has different dialects so knowing the platform is actually crucial in what syntax you can use. But Git is just Git (unless the question is about a specific other tool). And just because there *might* be a possible GitHub solution at some point later that does not mean that we should keep every question open ended in that direction. Don’t let GitHub become the new jQuery (“I heard you have this Git problem, just use that button on GitHub!!!”). Also, Git being a distributed VCS, having to rely on a web service is not a good solution imo.

Comment: @poke We're not talking about adding GitHub tag to all Git questions. If OP adds it when posting a question, this not a good enough reason to go and *remove* it. If OP adds it, that means he is happy to accept a solution via Github UI as well. Removing that is effectively removing useful information from question.

Comment: @TJ I disagree. Especially beginners very often don’t even realize that Git and GitHub are different things (if you spend more time on the Git tag, you see this happening *a lot*). And no, just because OP chooses a set of tags those tags are not necessarily correct. We, as “veteran users” who look out for improving the quality of the site, should always attempt to clear up tags and not keep tags on questions just for the sake of it but only if they are actually relevant.

Answer (score 16):

> Am I right in removing the [github] tag from (some) [git] questions?

I would ask the question backwards: the fact that you are using github changes in any way the question? If the answer is no and using github is just incidental/tangential to the question being asked, then I see no reason to add the tag, as I see no reason to not remove it.

Now, if the fact that you are using github is critical to the question asked, ie. if your question was instead about gitlab you couldn't reproduce the same behavior, then adding/not removing the tag is encouraged.

Tags aren't *keywords* to questions, but categories. If you can change Github for BitBucket or Gitlab or remove it altogether and the question still makes sense then you can remove the tag (and possibly the word from the body). Remember we like **Minimal**, Complete, Verifiable Examples. If there's information that doesn't belongs to the problem it distracts from the problem and can obscure the solution.

Answer (score 7):

Git is a *distributed* version control software, and most of Git happens *locally* on the developer’s machine. So if the question is about anything that is done locally, then the hoster of *one* remote repository is not relevant at all. As such, [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github) and any other source control hoster tag should be removed.

Once you reach a question which covers actual interaction with a Git remote, then you should look closely whether the issue is specific to the specified hoster. If it’s e.g. a random *“No supported authentication methods available”*, then of course this is not really relevant to a hoster but rather a configuration problem on the client. But if there’s a different issue with maybe provider specific errors, then of course the tag is very relevant and should stay.

And of course, you should attempt to find a close target for duplicate questions. Due to the nature of Git, there are actually a lot of duplicate questions hiding under a different situation.

Answer (score 4):

When someone asks a question on stack overflow, they don't always know what the issue is. It becomes obvious when there's an answer posted, but until there's an answer, the user still has no idea.

Have you ever had an issue that you thought was a programming issue that later wound up being an environment or OS configuration problem? When you got started, did you ever wonder why your shell script wasn't doing anything, and then find out that the code was perfect, but you hadn't given your user execute permissions for the script?

I think that modifying tags is incorrect, not because the tags can be misleading, but because they indicate the perceived stack. Until the solution is found, the problem could be in any part of the stack. So you should leave them, but add comments to the people asking questions so that they can edit them later as they learn more, or help clarify which parts of the stack the issue really belongs with.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that modifying tags is, not incorrect, but *dependent on accurate expert knowledge of the subject*. Some edits are as technical as answers.

Answer (score -4):

The repository is on GitHub but the question is pure Git — if OP already has [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github) — leave it alone, removing it won't improve anything.

When a question is about Git but OP tags it with [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github) only — add [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git). That will get it in front of the right eyes.

Comment: Removing technically-irrelevant tags doesn't improve anything? TIL!

Comment: For OP the tag is relevant and factually correct. If a tag is irrelevant for an *answer* - it's not a reason enough to remove it.

Comment: A tag is *relevant* to a question only if it *materially affects the answers that must be given*. Same as *the entirety of the question*, by definition. The question is only there *to get the right answers*. Anything that doesn't contribute to that? **Gone**. Purge with fire.

Comment: I do not believe we tailor questions (or their tags) to an answer, it's the other way around.

Comment: I said "answers", plural. We certainly *do* tailor questions to the set of valid answers they could receive! That's the only thing we tailor them for! So if a tag is not going to be relevant to *any* answer… it's gone.

Comment: The only thing I have to offer at this point is to agree to disagree.