# Editing a question when its useful answers technically don't answer it

Tags: discussion

This question: [Obtaining the equivalent to printf or String.Format in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233701/is-there-an-equivalent-of-printf-or-string-format-in-excel), asking about a function callable from Excel which can format strings, ends with the sentence:

> Is there anything like this built in to Excel, or can I call out to
> CLR **without writing a macro**?

*(emphasis my own)*

In Excel land, a "macro" is generally synonymous with VBA, so that sentence reads to me as "no VBA". However the top voted and accepted answer uses VBA, so clearly most people landing on the page are okay with a VBA solution. I'm wondering if I should edit that pesky sentence out of the question so some of the answers (including my own) are on topic, and also add the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag which would greatly improve this question's discoverability IMO.

Comment: "so clearly most people landing on the page are okay with a VBA solution" - aye, probably because Google kicked them directly to the answer. The text in the question really won't affect anything this long after he fact. You should have probably done what Braiam has done and just edit it and nobody would have blinked an eye ;)

Comment: There are zillions of SO questions where the OP has accepted an answer that's either technically incorrect, or doesn't answer the question as most people would read it, or doesn't satisfy all the requirements stated in the question. If you're going to sort all that out, you've got a lot of work on your hands. However, I'm generally very reluctant to edit a question in a way that changes its meaning, and I think you should be reluctant too.

Comment: If the requirement isn't hard (ie. just a preference) it can be either edited to downgrade it, or remove it. There's no problem with removing irrelevant bits from questions. A preference that the OP doesn't understand if it makes sense fit that bill.

Answer (score 32):

Adding the [vba] tag is fine, in my opinion. However, I don't think removing the sentence is called for. The OP essentially asked "Can I do X without using VBA?" and they got an answer saying "No, you can't; but it's simple enough to do with VBA and can be used in a formula. Here's how...". Then, they accepted the answer. So, removing that sentence, in a way, changes the original question.

Comment: Adding VBA when the OP doesn't show a preference for it, makes no sense. Is like adding flask when I ask for managing sql queries in python, because the answer I liked the most uses it. I could just do with sqlalchemy. We tag based on the information of the question, not on the answers.

Comment: @Braiam I disagree. When most answers are using VBA, it only makes sense to add the tag. That helps future visitors who are looking for VBA solutions find the question. When someone asks a question about string manipulation in C#, then, they get an answer suggesting a Regex solution, and they accept it, I take it upon myself to add the [regex] tag to the question.

Comment: @Braiam Additionally, I'm not sure why you decided to _also_ remove the [excel-formula] tag when the question clearly mentions (and shows usage of) formulas.

Comment: Well, you can disagree, the help center should dismiss that argument: Tags are a means of **connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer** by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories. Nothing there says that you should use answers to tag questions.

Comment: Because the excel formula isn't the problem, that was added years after without need since experts were able to find the question just fine with the excel tag. Tags are about the question, the question asks "how to do this in excel?" it doesn't say "how to do this with excel formulas?" nor "excel vba". The only preference expressed is that the OP tries to avoid VBA, but even then that preference isn't a hard one.

Comment: I never said that tags should be added/removed based on answers. However, the fact that the OP has **accepted an answer providing a VBA solution** implicitly makes the question VBA-related. Again, tags are used to categorize questions (that's even mentioned in the text you quoted) and make them easier to find. Adding the VBA tag helps users find that question which is (almost all) about VBA now. I'm not exactly sure what _harm_ does it do to put that question into the "VBA category"!!

Comment: So, if it accepts an answer about python it should be taken that it was asking about python? That argument gets silly in a hurry. Accept vote is just the answer that OP liked the most, and nothing else. The latest change on the pinning mechanism should reinforce that view.

Comment: You seem to always want to jump to the extreme case. No, no one is saying that if a javascript question gets a python answer, it should be retagged. It shouldn't; even if the OP accepts that answer. I'm (obviously) talking about cases where the additional tag can work (and is often used) with the main/original tag. Especially when most or all answers are about that tag.

Comment: The last thing I will say is: if you fundamentally disagree with this answer, feel free to post your own and allow other users to vote on it. That way, we can see the direction of the community's consensus with regards to this.

Comment: I don't need to. This answer already does what I say and contradict your answer fundamentally. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326884/792066 BTW, "community consensus" is just a short term for "whoever is awake at the time the meta post was up and active"

Comment: That answer has nothing to do with what we've been discussing here. I agree with it 100%. I've said (and done) the same thing myself before.

Comment: Well, if you can't see how that answer invalidates your point, then there's nothing to discuss.

Comment: I guess you could also read that as "no there isn't one built in but you can implement one" rather than "no you can't implement one without VBA". If the former is the intended reading (and on re-reading I think it actually is) then removing the stuff about not using a macro doesn't change the answer at all I don't think.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the "without writing a macro" part of the question would be significantly changing the spirit of the question, which is generally a bad thing to do.

> Some common reasons to edit are:
> ...
>
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Maybe future versions of Excel will be able to do what the question asks without VBA. Maybe someone already knows how to do it, but won't post with your changes because now the question expects VBA to be used.

In general, it's a bad idea to change a question to fit the answers. Not only does it look like history is being rewritten or censorship is happening, but it also makes people think that only questions that can be answered are the only proper questions to be asked here. There's plenty of argument here on Meta about what should and shouldn't be asked, no need to feed the fires of "only approved questions should be asked". I mean really, how do you know a question is "approved" without asking it and getting feedback (unless it's obviously off topic or spam)? I go into the topic of "good question vs bad question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411512/why-do-we-reward-users-for-answering-bad-questions-and-would-it-be-a-good-idea-t/411546#411546), so I won't repeat myself. Suffice it to say that what's good or bad is highly subjective and trying to "fix" questions that are already acceptable to be "more acceptable" is ludacris.

Besides, it's always been understood that an answer of "no, you can't do it that way, but you can do it this way" is acceptable. I'm not one for saying or agreeing to "we've always done it this way", but in this case there's no other possible way to run a Q&A site than to accept that answers may be contrary to the question. If not, Skeptics, Politics, Law, and many other Stacks would essentially cease to be useful.

Comment: Yes, I concede that just removing the "without macros" line does make the accepted answer a bit nonsensical. There's still a bit of a clash even with it though - OP says "can this be done without VBA" suggesting they already know / at least imagine it can be done with it and they want a workaround. Then the answer is "no it can't be done without VBA, but it can be done with VBA like this". It seems a bit like a circular argument, slightly redundant don't you think? The question should instead be "is there an existing way to do this in Excel by default" and the answer then makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Greedo, no a circular argument is to say, "VBA has to be used because VBA is the way to do macros in Excel and this 'has' to be done using a macro because we're using VBA". Someone asking for a solution without using VBA is trying to get out of that circle. And circular arguments are redundant almost by definition. Asking to get out of the circular argument isn't redundant. And asking for a solution "in Excel by default" is likely going to get only VBA/macro answers, since that's the default for many people. I think the original question is fine and specific enough as is.