# Little itches that don't trigger the voting reversal script

Tags: discussion

Every now and then I'm receiving obvious *revenge downvotes*, where the user was intelligent enough to undergo the serial voting scripts radar:

[image]

The downvotes are applied to generally well achieved answers, and just less enough not to be captured by the serial DV script.

Not that I'm really caring about the the lost rep, but its annoying and probably indicates some inappropriate voting behavior of a particular user I've been pissing off.

Should I flag such for mod attention, such they could do a deeper investigation?

Comment: Use the contact us link at the footer.

Comment: You certainly can, if you feel that there's a reasonable likelihood of abuse.  I wouldn't expect much (either because it might not actually be abuse, even if it seems suspicious to you, or it there's likely not going to be sufficient evidence to act).

Comment: Also see [When does downvoting get "serial enough" to be worth reporting?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308632)

Comment: @JoshCaswell THX. I wouldn't have found these right now.

Comment: Sure thing! Also also see, on MSE: [Undetectable micro serial downvoting: what is it? What to do? What the heck!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227845)

Comment: Beyond what Shog9 says there, it can be difficult for moderators to pick out who might be behind this for a 50k user like yourself. The sheer number of posts you have means that statistically some number of people will naturally end up with a decent number of downvotes or upvotes towards you. Unless you have a smoking gun in the form of a recent argument or close vote, the only people who might be able to see anything about this would be SE employees. If you feel it's a problem worth acting on, you might be best off contacting the company directly.

Comment: My favorite thing about investigating serial voting issues for high-rep users is imagining how much work I'm putting the live database through by running queries on *all those votes*.

Comment: I should add that the first suspect I would have had for this is not capable of these recent votes, given the long time away from the site they were awarded after the last time this happened.

Comment: I'll keep that question as a duplicate signpost.

Comment: You [already asked this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261274/17034).  Same answer.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, sorry. I've gotta find a way to deal with my  Alzheimer disease here :/

Comment: @HansPassant I well know meeting me at the main site rarely is fun, that's intended most of the time.

Comment: You didn't really have to explain that, it is the basic reason why I don't answer questions in [c++] anymore.  Not just you.  Let's call it the olaf-factor, the exemplary user that is relentlessly hostile to questions he doesn't know the answer to and never minds sharing that little tidbit.