# So what is the purpose of downvoting an answer?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I have read the post on downvoting questions and understand the logic there. But I'm interested in the meaning of downvoting answers.

I assumed it was to help the OP and anyone following wade through the sometimes multiple responses.

Just today I read several answers that were technically incorrect. I downvoted them. And to be what I thought was polite, I explained why.

On one, the person seemed to immediately downvoted my answer in retribution.

On another the person called me a "hater".

So is it more polite to just say "hey ... this is not right" without downvoting? How do we prevent "retribution" downvotes?

I'm a relatively new contributor and still trying to figure out appropriate etiquette.

Comment: The tooltip tells you everything you need to know, and your experience is exactly why you don't have to comment to do so.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the OP, it is a signal to the next ~thousand programmers that read the question.  Basic message is "if you do this then you'll lose the next hour of your life".  But sure, it does also get used to tone down the kind of guy that walks into a watercooler conversation, has no real idea how the conversion got started or what it is about but knows that everybody is getting it wrong.  Voting is anonymous intentionally, like it is in any democracy, never hesitate to take advantage of that.

Comment: You also shouldn't have really announced that you downvoted them.  [Despite pleas to the contrary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question), it's seldom constructive, and can subject you to abuse of most kinds (verbal, serial voting, etc).

Comment: Lesson learned!

Comment: You can also lie. First, downvote; leave the browser tab open; minutes later, make a comment *"I didn't downvote but <give tips>"*

Comment: ..or just give them the tips. Best to leave the lies to the OP's :)

Comment: @MartinJames The problem is timing. DV followed by comment can/will be attached to you :) Got my fair share of "you hater" if I don't do that. Another option is to do both things with very different timings

Comment: **Don't comment on your votes**. You can comment on content, and you can vote on content, but commenting on votes will only ever end in drama. The fact that you voted and how is **completely irrelevant** to your suggestion of how the post can be improved, or your explanation of why the post is just flat out wrong (cannot be improved without replacing the answer with a different answer). In fact—in order to avoid drama—I will often lie and say I didn't vote.

Comment: 99% of the time, the person calling you out as a "hater" has no evidence of this, and is just taking their frustration out on you. If you were a downvoter then don't worry about it, and re-educate the OP about the use of the word "hate" if you wish, but know when to withdraw. I disagree with Tiny Giant's strong assertion that you should not comment on your votes - do if you wish, but bear in mind that replies are not always constructive.

Comment: "This just in: New Form of Hate Speech Seen on Stack Overflow's Downvoting Answers" - Twitter folks

Answer (score 24):

Revenge downvotes are an unfortunate reality of commenting your downvotes. See e.g. [What can I do in common, to avoid getting "revenge downvotes" for comments / close-, down-votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261274/what-can-i-do-in-common-to-avoid-getting-revenge-downvotes-for-comments-clo)

Usually the best thing to do, rather than not *downvoting*, is not *commenting*. If you don't comment, the answer may well not improve, but at least it's clearly indicated to everyone else that there is a problem with it, and you risk no revenge downvotes. But if you don't downvote, bad answers will not be appropriately marked for computers (or skimming humans) to process appropriately. It's better to make sure answers are sorted by usefulness than to make sure authors know precisely how to improve.

That said, I personally do occasionally comment in situations where I don't expect a strong risk of revenge voting.

Comment: As a relatively new contributor here ... I have been frustrated at the number of down votes with no comment. I then have no way to know how to improve or on other people's posts/answers, what is wrong with it. But now that I am on the other side of this (and with your help) I see why people don't comment. I completely agree ... but find it a bit sad. Newbies struggle to understand what they did wrong.

Comment: @DeborahK:  Newbies would struggle if they believed themselves to be 100% correct.  In my experience, they've corrected themselves by either revising their answer or removing a bad one.  I haven't had to comment in either of those situations.

Comment: The problem with not commenting is that downvotes are essentially invisible if there are upvotes countering them. One big reason to comment on downvotes, besides the actually pretty common possibility that the answerer will understand their error, is to make it more likely that other voters will realize what's wrong and downvote too.

Comment: A downvote with explanation has a much better chance of burying a wrong answer instead of being lost behind clueless upvotes.

Comment: @user2357112: That's true, but [just because one vote can't determine a post's score on its own is no reason not to vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260604/how-can-irrelevant-answers-that-dont-answer-the-question-be-removed/260612#260612), so while it's worth considering commenting, it's *not* worth considering not voting. Commenting is often a good idea but ultimately more optional.

Answer (score 15):

[Downvotes are an important part of ranking things](/a/252740/5764553), and it is sad that many people neglect to use them, so good on you for doing it.

Official people have been saying [over](/a/285777/5764553) [and](/q/277314/5764553) [over](/questions/310741/comments-cannot-contain-that-content-dont-comment-on-your-downvote#comment273787_310741): *don't comment to talk about your downvote.*

> Explaining votes is almost pure noise, meta-conversation and punditry. Your votes are your own to do with as you please; you owe no one an explanation, nor is a discussion of your voting habits likely to be helpful.
>
> What is helpful *is* constructive feedback:
>
> **Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved.**

<sup>[Source](/a/285777/5764553)</sup>

With regards to the feedback that you got:

If someone accuses you of downvoting, *don't respond to that*, even if they are correct. [Votes are supposed to be private.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/318307) If someone gets rude because they think you downvoted, **flag the comment**.<sup>1</sup>

This sort of aggressive/confrontational behavior is **not** acceptable. Stack Overflow has a [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy. If you see somebody violating it, don't hesitate to flag their comments/posts for the moderators to look at. Keeping that in check makes the site better.

<sub>1. Even if they aren't rude, most discussions about votes—if they have nothing else useful in the comment—should be flagged as "no longer needed".</sub>

Comment: I upvoted this answer because I completely agree.

Comment: Huh. I _did_ restrict it to talking about downvotes, didn't I... :)

Comment: Ugh, the "lost keys" post. Doesn't really square with your leading sentence,  which I completely agree with: votes _have meaning_ and _should be used with purpose_. Tim's downplay of them with "dont worry, LOL my cats r votin" does a disservice to voters and votees both.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's not exactly how I interpret Tim's post (unintentional). He was replying to all the people who get downvoted and overreact. Tim's basically saying "Cool off and stop trying to blame somebody." I see it more as a cover for private votes. If somebody gets downvoted, I blame Tim. But to the people _doing_ the downvoting, please have a reason.

Comment: Well, maybe I read it too much in the light of the way it gets used in comments, which seems to be to say "there's no way you could possibly know why your post was downvoted, it could be for any reason at all".

Comment: @AndrewMyers I'm quite sure that Tim understands that votes have meaning, people should have a reason when casting them, and you should assume people have a reason when they cast their votes.  Sadly, Tim's post is often misinterpreted by others as giving them an excuse for assuming that downvotes on their post are meaningless and that they should ignore them, rather than considering that they might have merit.

Answer (score 8):

> So is it more polite to just say "hey ... this is not right" without down voting?

No, a downvote should be applied if the content of the post isn't helpful or even incorrect.

You may warn the OP with a comment and encourage them to clarify, before downvoting. But if your concerns aren't covered with edits within a reasonable time frame, just downvote unuseful or misleading content.

Comment: Great idea ... comment first; use down vote as a secondary response. I like it. Thanks!

Comment: @DeborahK Well, I'm at a short _time framing_ doing so ;-) ...

Comment: A perceived possible future version of a post should never change how you're going to vote on that post. Vote on the content in it's current state. If that state later changes, feel free to change your vote. Counting on yourself to come back to every low quality answer you've commented on after a given period of time to downvote if there haven't been any changes is not always a reliable course of action.

Comment: @TinyGiant but if you plan to downvote commenting while there are no downvotes is safer choice in relation to revenge votes (assuming post is rarely visited, otherwise there is good chance of being blamed for someone else downvotes :)).  Some people may be organized enough to actually follow through on coming back and voting (I personally not counting on myself to come back and would just downvote and not comment)