# Increase the downvote penalty for downvotee on answers from 2 to 4

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes

I'll start by saying that I don't know if my proposal is good or not, I'll expose my pro & cons arguments (this isn't a feature request, just a discussion).

Simple math (that you know already):

- upvoting a question: +5 for OP
- downvoting a question: -2 for OP

but

- upvoting an answer: +10 for Answerer
- downvoting an answer: -2 for Answerer

That doesn't seem very proportionate at first glance. The reputation points gain/loss between users disapproving and/or approving the post is different between questions and answers.

That seems pretty balanced for questions. The question is okay, someone upvotes it, someone sees an issue and downvotes, the asker still get reputation. Someone else sees an issue, downvotes, there is still 1 point left. A third user downvotes: now a question with a -2 score is *costing* the user 1 rep point. Good.

But for answers (as many of us know how easy it is to get a *first* upvote from a gullible user, or the OP, happy to see an answer), undoing the reputation gain, forcing the answerer to edit or delete their post, is much harder:

- upvote: 10 points
- downvote: 8 points
- downvote: 6 points
- downvote: 4 points
- downvote: 2 points

The answer has a score of -3 but still gives reputation to the poster. And there are bad answers that luckily gathered 3 votes before someone notices that it's *wrong*. You make the count! Most people just give up downvoting in those cases.

**Proposal**

I'm proposing that downvoting an answer should cost 4 points to its poster instead of 2.

**Pros**:

- Answerers are more compelled to delete their answers, because the score is negative after 3 downvotes.
- The up/down vote ratio is the same as the one for questions.
- You cannot (theorically) flag a wrong answer to put it in the review queue so it's difficult to be followed by a mob of downvoters for a wrong (not bad or LQ) answer, but downvotes have more power to coerce the poster to delete their answer.

**Cons**:

- Why do this when power users can vote to delete the answer when the score is -1 or less? (Well, it's not so easy to reach 3 votes to delete)
- Why do this when there's still a penalty for the badges? (if I'm running for gold badge, I'll delete posts that hurt my tag badge score without caring for reputation), so high reputation users running for badges would have deleted the answer anyway
- This would reduce the reputation points of most users (but statistically the same for everyone, I personally NEVER keep answers with a negative score, even if it still gets me points).
- The reputation count will have to be recomputed for all users unless the measure could be made non-retroactive, which would probably be better but more complex. (It has already probably been done when downvoting questions ceased to cost reputation, I dunno, wasn't there at the time).

I was surprised that noone proposed it already. I (of course) searched all over the internet (and beyond :)) and found nothing like this, so I'm waiting for your 0-point penalty meta upvotes & downvotes as well as your input.

Comment: [Someone *definitely did* propose it before...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7322/175248) and it was shot down.

Comment: I would love to see the "penalty" be the same as the "reward".  I hate that a sympathy up vote counters 5 down votes on a answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver but there's tactical downvotes. -4 is better than nothing IMHO.

Comment: Loss aversion means this is a non-starter. The powers that be want people to continue contributing and any system imposed deterrents to contribution are extremely difficult to get implemented due to the fact that they run counter to the goal of getting more people contributing.

Comment: @Makoto "Shot down" meaning "declined by SO," in spite of popular support from the community.

Comment: @TinyGiant if contributing means posting crap, then it's not contributing.

Comment: @Nathan all of these requests are bound to accrue meta support (those who frequent meta would be the users who would "benefit" from this). That _does not_ mean that they are popular with the community, but rather popular with the segment of the community that is concerned about the low penalty of answer downvotes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Tell that to the powers that be.

Comment: @TinyGiant I hope they'll be reading this :) note that it must have been the same issue when downvoting questions became "free". Being more downvoted didn't deter people to ask questions :)

Comment: @NathanArthur:  The lesson here is, regardless of how popular an idea or concept is, if it doesn't mesh with what Stack Overflow wants to do or the direction they think is best for the site, they're not going to do it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  I think it was just a matter of using the right words in the search query.  Honest mistake.

Comment: @Makoto: yes, I did the same kind of google search as when I'm looking to hammer a dupe... "weight" didn't come to my frog-eater mind. Also, my proposal is more precise. It proposes to double the downvote penalty...

Comment: @Makoto I'm under the impression that modifying the site behaviour is 99% of the time a non-starter, because of the fear of breaking the delicate balance of the mechanics, and also because it must be difficult not to create bugs when changing such a complex machine. Let's not complain too loud, SO/SE network sites are 100 times better than all the crap LOL forums in the world.

Comment: @TinyGiant Sorry, when I said "the community," I was referring to the meta crowd.

Comment: @Makoto No disagreement here. Was just clarifying what you meant in your comment, as on first reading it I took it to mean it had been generally-strongly-opposed on Meta by community members, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The downvote penalty on questions was removed *very* early in the site's lifetime; before it had really become widely successful.  It was also a change made by Jeff, who hasn't been with SO for quite some time now, and he was one of the major champions (with the clout to actually get them implemented) for more radical changes designed to improve site quality.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  If you can come up with strong and reasonable rationale as to why this decision would be *in the best interest of the site*, then you could see movement in that direction.  Right now...I see an attempt to weaponize moderation tools.  Worse, you're thinking of applying this retroactively...and that'd cause a *problem*.

Comment: Meh, I disagree with the pros here. Users remove posts with negative votes because it usually is accompanied with an explanation of technical inaccuracy. This feature request is too short sighted. Long term posts do not collect downvoted answers, and when they creep in they tend to get deleted as a result of the higher views. Solving a problem with low view, low traffic, recently asked questions by potentially breaking the rest of the system is a non starter. Especially without any research shown aside from prose.

Comment: Although I kind of like the idea, I fear that this would also increase the damage from those revenge downvotes we can't do much about.

Comment: you cannot make downvotes _on answers_ count more without making revenge downvotes _on answers_ cost more.

Comment: @TravisJ this _isn't_ a feature request. And who decided to put 2. Why not 4? It's just a _setting_. who said it will break the rest of the system?

Comment: If you tagged a bug report as discussion, that doesn't make it a discussion. Just the same here. This is a feature-request, because you have included no research, nor have you included a platform to discuss the impact, implications, or facets of what changing the downvote penalty would incur. You flatly state 4. It *is* a feature-request. And stating that the reputation lost from a downvote is "just a *setting*" is downplaying a very serious aspect of the site.

Comment: I was just comparing the DV/UV ratio on questions to the one on answers. It seemed natural that they should be the same, because in the current system 1 upvote is very hard to cancel, so people don't even try. You're right, I should do some research and since I suck at SEDE scripts I won't.

Comment: This topic is interesting enough but I believe its been looked at in depth in the past. There Has been a lot going back and forth about this topic in relation to the fairness of costing the voter more points or the effects of revenge down voting being a big problem with more points at stake. I think there might be a middle ground like many have posted to raise the amount removed from the down-votee to -5 and the down_voter to -2. This seams like the best balance going forward but as said its already a topic that has been reviewed and denied.

Comment: @NathanArthur _"declined by SO"_ It was also  [_proposed_ by Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/7322/1). Jeff was running the site/company day-to-day at the time.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Good point. I hadn't caught that.

Comment: Force the downvoter to add a comment.  Then the downvotee can make an informed change to their question/answer.  It is very frustrating to get downvotes and have no idea why.

Comment: @MichaelPotter I'm voting to close your comment as a duplicate of [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250177), [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285081), and [this more recent discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355553)

Comment: @Makoto _**Shot down??**_ It was suggested by Jeff Atwood himself, the question got 219 upvotes and the top two answers (which supported the suggestion) got a combined score of 356 upvotes. I fail to see how you came to this conclusion.

Comment: @Clonkex:  So you missed the big ol' "status declined" tag on the question.  I see.  Common mistake.

Comment: @MichaelPotter Hard to do. A lot of downvote comments would just be "This answer will not work for the reason described by @Smartie". This could be implemented in a manner similar to the automatic comment upvote for a duplicate question close vote, but that would be a non-trivial increase in complexity.

Comment: @Clonkex JeffAtwood himself shot it down.

Comment: @Makoto I didn't miss it. "Shot down" implies "strongly disagreed with". As you can clearly see, most people agreed with the suggestion. Just because it was declined by one person doesn't mean it was "shot down".

Comment: @Clonkex: I refer you back to [Nathan Arthur's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356164/increase-the-downvote-penalty-for-downvotee-on-answers-from-2-to-4#comment511199_356164).

Comment: Rather than increasing the rep penalty, I think there should be stricter penalties for repeat offenders, because those are usually the types who need to be penalised more for poor quality on the site.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, but fraudulent voting patterns are hard to detect

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I thought the point of this post is to discourage poor quality (which would attract downvotes which would mean more penalty), and not to discourage serial downvoting. But this could impact both.

Comment: I re-read that [ancient decline justification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42763/165773). 6 years ago it made good sense for there was a risk of repelling answerers because of rep losses. Nowadays risk of them repelling is still there but main reason seems to be [proliferation of garbage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601). If '2017 version of this request is to be re-declined then justification would better take that new risk into account

Comment: ...OTOH I wouldn't be surprised if this gets implemented. Requiring registration to ask, showing deleted posts to authors, retracting close votes, Programmers.SE rename - there are plenty examples of things that were (fairly reasonably) declined in the past but were (also reasonably) reconsidered and implemented few years later

Comment: @gnat way to go: things that were true and justified years ago may not be so justified now that the site and its exposure changed.

Comment: I want to point out that in your example you take into consideration, that the answer got an upvote. What is with answers, which doesn't get an upvote, but collect a massive amount of downvotes in a short time?

Comment: This request seems to falsely assume that the reputation penality from receiving downvotes is the driver behind correcting incorrect answers. There’s no evidence supporting this, and I would personally say that the *downvote itself* is a much more important part of the process.

Comment: "I personally NEVER keep answers with a negative score" -> I'd like to think you keep or delete an answer because you believe it's correct or incorrect based on explained feedback, not just score. If you genuinely believe your answer is right despite the votes of the community, you should leave it in place.

Comment: This _feature request_ makes absolutely no sense. Not only because it breaks one of the most crucial mechanics of the Site, which has been working well for years, but because the way described here is not the way the downvotes work.
The reputation penalty is **not** the point of downvote. What matters is the number of downvotes, thus  _UV/DV_ ratio, which indicates the there's something not okey with the answer.
Playing randomly with numbers like that would've made people **stop using downvote whatsoever**. I don't think it would mean anything positive in the log run...

Comment: I'm not even saying about the absolute lack of research or any signs, that any change is required, not considering answers with 0 upvotes, issues with further moderation etc etc.
As was said before, "_This feature request is bluntly short sighted_".

Comment: And as regards to "deleting own downvoted answer", forcing user to delete it is not improving anything. I think [Shog made a nice summary here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263048/4241435)

Comment: @Skipper users delete their answer with -1 or -2 already (or delete-edit-undelete quicky enough so downvoters retract/upvote). The risk is that they don't delete it to keep the rep if there was one bozo upvote first. Shog post doesn't contradict my proposal.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So are you saying that an answer that was downvoted one or twice is always *wrong*, and that downvoters never make mistakes while upvoters do?

Comment: @poke I think downvoters are more careful. It costs 1 rep point (ok no big deal) and also it personally hurts the poster. An upvote may hurt the site but not the poster. Steal in supermarkets, they have plenty of items.

Comment: Sounds like you have an answer you want to post, @Skipper.

Comment: I don't think all downvoters are more careful. I got downvotes within seconds after posting a question that tells me some ppl just start reading a question and downvote it before they finished reading it. I would suggest that downvoters must enter an explanation for their downvote. Receiving downvotes with no explanation makes a question owner not smarter.

Comment: Requiring to explain the downvote IS a non starter. And this concerns answers not questions. After a few months or years on the site you recognize bad questions in a glance, example: wall of code c questions. Dont forget that downvoter can retract dv, they often do if the post is nicely edited

Comment: @Jonny: Please look at [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356164/increase-the-downvote-penalty-for-downvotee-on-answers-from-2-to-4#comment511333_356164), higher up in the comment chain here.

Comment: As some have already said the ratio UV/DV or the even just the number of UV and DV, is much more interesting than the actual total points. So maybe just showing the actual number of up and down votes (for example if you mouse over the total points) could be a lot of help. But then as a SO user I don't see this isn't a big problem.

Comment: showing UV/DV is a privilege but you have it. Try clicking on the score you'll see red/green UV/DV ratio. New users don't have that, even for their posts (they have to compute that). 500+ unlocks it AFAIR

Answer (score -44, accepted):

An alternative approach:

If an answer has more up votes than down votes, each down vote counts as a -10, until the number of down votes are more (or equal) than the number of up votes, in which case the current system with -2 applies.

This would mean that 1 confused up-voter does not weigh as much as 5 down-voters, which is the main problem with the current system.

Comment: Maybe we should add a rep penality for upvotes too, to avoid “confused upvoters”?!

Comment: @poke By "confused upvoter" I mean a scenario where someone posts a factually incorrect answer. The first person who reads it is a newbie, who up votes. Then other users reads it and down vote. The next newbie who comes along is less likely to up-vote, because there will now be down votes and comments. This is a quite common scenario.

Comment: sounds like a good idea, which would cover the problem I had in mind when I wrote my question. However it looks complicated to implement/avoid bugs or infinite questions about "how come that my rep is x it should be y...". Also, if I implemented this, I would implement the other way round: first downvote: -2, then corrective upvote: +2 instead of +10. Maybe there would be more corrective upvotes, and "pity" corrective upvotes wouldn't bring too much rep

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think the site would have to re-calculate how much rep each vote should give as soon as a vote is cast. But indeed this might have the side effect of a lot of reputation changes that are hard for the user to understand.

Comment: unless this could _not_ be retroactive. But then "enter bugs and meta-questions" :)

Comment: Well I seem to be in the minority who likes this answer. I have accepted it because it reflects my opinion most. Tinygiant answer is also very good but too conservative for me. Anyway glad that everyone is mobilized around this subject. Hot meta post, cool.

Comment: This would only serve as a greater incentive for tactical downvoting on competing answers.

Comment: Seriously, tactical downvoting? Who does that ? A few bozos. Never met one in 2200 answers.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: Lucky you.

Comment: @BoltClock seriously? there are still people enjoying that? any meta post you could direct me to?

Answer (score 59):

The perfect answer to this question (in my opinion) was [already posted to a similar proposal on Over Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42763/288751) by [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) (also the OP of the proposal this was posted as an answer to):

> Having had a few months to think about this, I'm no longer sure it's a
>   good idea, for two reasons.
>
> 1. Downvotes were always essentially cosmetic, with an extremely minor effect on reputation. Despite this, received downvotes are taken quite
>      seriously by users. Almost too seriously. If we raise them to -5 they
>      are no longer cosmetic but can be wielded as cudgels on other users.
>      This was never the intent of a downvote, so we would be twisting it
>      into something ugly. Users are far, far more attached to their
>      reputation scores than I ever could have predicted, and I believe more
>      than doubling the weight of a downvote will cause a *lot* of new,
>      additional angst in the community over the occasional received
>      downvote -- to the point that only users who want to hurt other users
>      will cast them. **Downvotes go from being cosmetic and psychological
>      to weapons of war.**
> 2. If we amplify the effect of a downvote, in all fairness, we must also amplify the cost to the casting voter as well. So what was -2 to
>      the post, with -1 to the casting voter, will become -5/-2 or even
>      -5/-3. The only reason we had downvotes cost -1 was to make people really think about using downvotes in moderation, only when
>      appropriate. For such an extremely minor cost, users with 20k+ rep are
>      still hesitant to cast downvotes for fear of losing reputation! Our
>      goal is *not* to prevent people from casting downvotes, and it seems
>      that given the current observed behavior (that is, very few people
>      cast downvotes -- though a tiny select few cast a lot) **we would be
>      causing the majority of users to cast *even fewer* downvotes than they
>      do now**. This is, in my mind, a HUGE downside to this proposed
>      change. We would be effectively nerfing downvotes into oblivion
>      because they're now twice as "expensive" to cast.
>
> The real problem I want to solve here is ["shore, there is always
>   gold"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold).
>   I am no longer convinced this is the right way to do it, but I am open
>   to hearing ideas on that thread on other ways we could do it.

Comment: I still don't buy this. On point 1, questions are downvoted by the dozens with little care for whether the askers get stressed, and not just 1-rep askers whose rep scores are unaffected. I don't think people *really* care that much about whether their vote stresses someone out; what matters is the cost to the voter, in such forms as direct rep cost, internet arguments, and revenge votes. As for point 2, there is no need to amplify the downvote cost for "fairness".

Comment: @user On point one, you're making a sweeping generalization based on _your_ view. I know for a fact that there are many users out there that simply do not downvote because of the perceived negative psychological impact they would be dishing out on the user. I know this because they have said this, whether it be in chat, in response to my comments on posts here on meta, or just in comments on posts in general.

Comment: @user On point two, there _is_ a need to increase cost if you increase effect. Tactical downvoting is already a thing, and if you make the downvote mean more without making it cost more, you risk discouraging the victims and encouraging the tactical downvoters.

Comment: I'll rephrase my response to point 1, then. Looking at how many downvotes questions receive compared to answers, I don't believe perceived psychological impact is the primary motivator for the low downvote rate on answers, and I do not believe that increasing the rep penalty would make perceived psychological impact so great a motivator that only people who want to hurt people would downvote.

Comment: @TinyGiant agreed that the cost would need to increase - which drives up loss aversion as point 2 states. There may come a point however that the answer is deleted at which point you get your reputation back. I wonder what would happen when in case the answer is deleted, you get more back than you lost. Say - lose 2 points but gain 4 back. There is still loss aversion as you have a chance to not get them back at all, but it is still sort of an investment that can pay out which lowers the bar.

Comment: _" For such an extremely minor cost, users with 20k+ rep are still hesitant to cast downvotes for fear of losing reputation!"_ I'm usually very happy to downvote stuff :D Who cares about single-digit rep ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus again, you and I are fine with it, that does not mean that there are no users out there that are not fine with it. The meta crowd is not representative of any group other than the group of users that frequent meta.

Comment: @user2357112 questions are another story because askers ask primarily for their own gain. There's no way to interpret anything well-meant into a “gimme teh codez” post, so people won't hesitate to downvote it even – and perhaps particularly – if it's seen as actual punishment. But an answer that attempts to help, even if it does a horrible job, will by many be seen with pity more than contempt, so they might not hesitate to downvote the _content_ but, because it's also linked to rep punishment, hesitate to downvote the actual post.

Answer (score 0):

- The focus of voting is to push great content to the top and to push bad content to the bottom but both do not have equal weight as can be understood by the fact that,

  > [The up-vote privilege comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)
- A LQ posting user's reputation is not the focus.
- Further, the purpose of -2 penalty is to discourage someone from posting unhelpful content. If a user continues to contribute LQ posts, they eventually get Q or A banned, which completely bans the user from posting LQ content.

The current focus and implementation of voting seems fine to me.

---

Yes, users may make points with negatively voted answer, but so what? Let them. When users post unhelpful content, they inevitably get down-voted. An overall negatively scored answer doesn't bypass a good quality and highly up-voted answer, even if the answerer made some imaginary currency in the process.

And if you think that they think that they are successfully making some reputation at a Q&A website, understand that being able to increase an imaginary number, without improving their own knowledge and the quality of knowledge, is a futile "success" in the long run.

---

<sup>**UPDATE:**</sup>

<sup>*Because I said that I'm ok with current voting process, readers have concluded that I am ok with LQ content on SO. It is not true. I'm not supporting LQ content on SO, rather I'm saying that LQ content is currently being handled on SO just fine. The right way to improve the quality of content posted on SO is to educate the LQ posters, while keeping the Qs and As ban in place, which kick in when LQ material is posted by someone too frequently.*</sup>

Comment: @displayName You personally may not have a problem with lots of people posting low quality content, but some of us *do* have a problem with people providing low quality content, and don't want them to continue repeating that same bad behavior or refraining from rectifying their mistakes.

Comment: @Servy: I *do* have problem with low quality content _and_ my focus is always on the useful content. I also feel that trying to control the behavior of other users can only be done to limited extents when trying to keep the community open. Best is to educate the low quality content posters.

Comment: @displayName If you have a problem with low quality content then why is your response to people posting low quality content to say, "Yeah, but so what? Let them."  You very clearly said you *don't* have a problem with it, and that you see no need to either discourage it from being posted or to incentivise its improvement/removal.

Comment: @Servy: "Yeah, but so what?" is in regards with OP's concern that some users make rep even after posting low quality stuff. In regards to the problem that I have with LQ posters, I feel the right way is their education.

Comment: @displayName And you think rewarding people for posting bad content teaches them to *stop* posting more bad content, and that having them actually be penalized (very minimally) for posting bad content is problematic because...you haven't actually stated why, actually, you have a problem with that, only that you don't care at all that people are rewarded for bad behavior.

Comment: @Servy: I don't think any such thing. These are all unwarranted conclusions drawn in a manner that _because I don't say A you conclude that I say B_. A user who posts LQ stuff frequently, gets banned and I don't have any objection with that.

Comment: @displayName You said specifically in your answer that you don't' care at all if people continue to post bad content and get rewarded for doing so.  If you actually have a problem with people posting bad content, and if you actually have a problem with people being rewarded for posting bad content, then don't say the exact opposite.

Comment: @Servy: LQ content _may_ get rewarded with points and frequent LQ posts will get rewarded with posting ban. I don't have any problem with either.

Answer (score -11):

I'm bothered by the idea that we're trying to force people to remove content or, worse, not participate at all, based on the influence of a small number of people.  I get it, you want better answers, better participation, better quality, but when has that *ever* happened due to punishment?

Worse, some answers have relevant insight despite being lower quality answers.  The loss of that commentary, no matter how insignificant the percentage of participation, is in my mind a high cost for trying to enforce "better behavior."

Therefore, I ask in return, is there an actual problem we're trying to solve with this, or are we simply discussing the matter based on the principle of "it doesn't seem completely fair?"

My vote: I'd rather suffer a higher percentage of lower quality answers to encourage greater participation knowing that some will become quality participants on the site, than to discourage participation by quickly punishing lower quality answers and potentially lose those who learn to be better.

*And, on a side note, I agree completely with Jeff Atwood's insight.  Vindictive people would downvote just to get their answer higher on the list.  I've been the victim of that as the rules stand.  Adding greater weight against the answerer would only make the situation imeasurably worse.*

My comment tree has exposed an interesting issue.  What, really, is the problem we're trying to address?  Objectively, are there people with consistently downvoted answers gaining reputation privileges such that we have correspondingly low quality behavior in, for example, the review queues?  If we do, then there is an argument for increasing the answerer's downvote penalty.

But that isn't the problem my commenters are raising.  They're complaining that the perceived imbalance is "unfair."  Unfair to whom, unless there is a problem like the one I just mentioned?  Who cares unless there is an issue?  Are we so petty, do we have such low self-esteem, are we so snobbish, that we're willing to remove reputation points without a problem in evidence?  Because the consequence will be a loss of participation.

Comment: "Vindictive people would downvote just to get their answer higher on the list". I've posted 2200 answers, and I think I got tactical-downvoted once or twice. Not even sure it happened at all. Also, if a question has 55 answers, 45 of which are low quality, it just adds pollution to the site and makes SO look like any stupid "try this, try that" LOL forum. Contributing is ok, but not with crap.

Comment: also, tactical downvote can backfire: 1) other users see the downvote for a perfectly ok answer 2) they comment / answerer comments (why the downvote/dunno, looks ok) 3) users make up the downvote by an upvote because they think it's unfair and possibly 4) everyone figures out that the other answerer downvoted and he doesn't get any upvotes for that... (coming from a proud owner of the "sportmanship" badge).

Comment: Is elitism what this site is about?  Then the problem is better solved by setting a minimum reputation level before answers can be submitted.  Like many people, I've used SO for years and it never once crossed my mind that there was too much "crap."  I've even found answers amongst what you'd likely call "crap."  There must be a better reason than website aesthetics to do this or we're acting against the site's purpose.

Comment: having higher reputation clearly isn't a good indication of being able to present high quality answers.

Comment: not elitism: everyone can answer. In real life (ex: at work), you can answer, but if you're incompetent, people will also let you know. How can you know which answers I would call "crap". I'm not elitist.

Comment: Based on the "Shore, there is always gold" answer, you are certainly correct, but heavy-handedness is more likely to drive users away than it is to improve users.  Otherwise, corporal punishment would still be the norm.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, that's fair, I do not actually know how you stand on this issue.  But, reducing the number of people needed to make answering a question valueless in the hopes that it will teach the answerer to do a better job is elitist ... especially when the majority of downvoters are unlikely to be doing it for the humanist reason of teching someone to do it better.  That's what bothers me about the answer, it gives too much power to too few few people for highly questionable reasons.

Comment: downvotes aren't for punishment, they're for rating quality, just like upvotes. However, to encourage users to provide high quality content, we give them rep when they get upvoted. The opposite action is a downvote when the content *isn't* high quality. it only makes sense that the opposite should occur, and the user lose rep. In the current setup, that opposite is offset several times over by a single upvote, but I don't think that's necessarily a bad thing, and agree that increasing it could have a negative overall effect.

Comment: @KevinB, the answerer does lose rep.  What this discussion is proposing is that he/she should lose more rep.  Why? because, we hope, it will lead to the answerer providing higher quality answers.  Is there evidence of that?  There isn't in "real life."  On the other hand, I suspect there's clear evidence of downvotes leading to lost participation.  It's like the author of a textbook complaining that the 6-year-olds who use it don't give good enough answers and should be cracked with a ruler to give better ones.

Comment: eh, no, i think the reason was more just to make it more fair. Why should someone be able to on average provide bad content, but have a net gain of reputation? to me, that should be possible because we have a hell of a lot of questions that need answers, and if a portion of those answers are good, we can handle/delete a few bad ones.

Comment: @KevinB, we're back to elitism.  How many people should be required to determine "bad content?"  Do we have any evidence of people who provide consistently downvoted answers building up reputation to the point they have access to features they shouldn't have?  In the end, unfair to whom?  What is the balance to encourage participation while being "fair" (whatever that actually means).

Comment: @JBH there is no point where a piece of content is objectively "good" or "bad". the content's score gives us a subjective evaluation of it's value, whether that score was created by 1 person or 2000.

Comment: The argument is more along the lines of, why should you have a very large positive gain on an answer that received, say, 10 upvotes *and* 10 downvotes? Why should the net rep change be closer to 50 and not 0?

Comment: And my argument is, why should anyone care unless there are a large number of people with consistently downvoted answers who are gaining reputation privileges such that problems are occuring (e.g., in the review queues)?  What is the actual problem, other than a philisophical discussion of what "fair" means?

Comment: Exactly my point. :) but calling it elitist is dismissive. it isn't elitist in the least bit, the argument does have merit, it just... doesn't matter at the end of the day.

Comment: I do think there needs to be *some* penalty to reputation when you receive a downvote, but i don't think it needs to be equal. We want to encourage answering more so than discourage, unlike questions.

Comment: @JBH You personally may be more interested in attracting bad content than good content, and that's fine, some people aren't interested in good content, and to each their own, but SO was built on the premise of being a place to find quality answers to quality questions, not a place where low quality answers are posted to low quality questions because people were too afraid of actually telling someone that they posted bad content out of fear that they'd stop posting more of it.

Comment: @Servy, that attitude is deplorable.  It's nothing more than, "we don't want beginners, learners, students, or foreigners, we only want people who speak the Queen's English and learned to program at someone else's expense."  If that's all SO is worth, then it's worth nothing.  People come here to find answers.  Heaven help us that some don't speak English as a first language, or picked up their first programming book yesterday.  I'm not looking to fill the world with bad content.  I'm looking to give the world a chance to learn.

Comment: People continuously post poor quality answers on duplicates of duplicates of duplicates, because they know it's easy rep. I'm talking 50k+ users answering duplicates of the most popular questions in their tag of choice. This isn't out of the kindness of their hearts. When I see answers like that, I downvote them after closing the question. Imo, that downvote can have a larger impact on the rep they gained, than it does now.

Comment: @JBH It means none of those things.  Beginners, learners, students, and foreigners are more than capable of asking great questions.  They do so constantly.  Likewise, experts in their field who speak fluent English regularly ask *terrible* questions.  Accusing people who are interested in quality questions, rather than low quality questions, of being racist, when that has nothing to do with question quality, is simply *deplorable*.  It is *you* who are asserting that foreigners and students are incapable of asking acceptable questions, so it is *you* who are treating them unacceptably.

Answer (score -17):

### Against. -2 for answer downvote is fine.

**Bad questions** are bad in that they take up space/attention from everybody, from people who'd like to spend their time on better stuff. That warrants making a real **negative rep score** easy to get, both to encourage deleted-by-owner and better asking in the future.

**Bad answers** are, in the worst case, bad in that they purport misinformation, but more typically they just fail to help the OP. In the former case, the most important thing is to add a warning sign *for people reading the answer*, hopefully in form of a comment but also a **negative vote balance**. The side-effect of punishing the answerer is less necessary – often this will actually feel a bit unfair, because they did after all attempt to help. That also means that big negative score for a downvote might discourage people from pushing that button even when it's in order: “-1 doesn't hurt me, but that poor soul only has 135 rep, I don't want to inflict -4 on them...”.
Sure, bad answers also take up space and time, but mostly the question-OP's time, and they did of course bring it all up in the first place and thus shouldn't complain. Furthermore, even a bad answer may actually help the OP because it gives rise to some new thoughts. Heck, even a *wrong* answer (with neg-votes / comments) can be helpful, namely show up a possibly-common misconception! Thus I also don't think we should that strongly encourage deleting answers.

Comment: Providing misinformation is *much, much* worse than just taking up space, and deserves a worse penalty.

Comment: Yup, pretty much everything I'd have written. Most important: the vote _score_ is what matters most to the community, and while maybe it'd be better to encourage posters to delete bad posts (especially since all too often, bad posts still get a number of up-votes), there's too much revenge voting, and higher-impact down-votes would tend to discourage contributions overall, because contributions just provide a bigger attack surface for revenge downvoters.

Comment: @user2357112 _wantonly_ providing misinformation is completely unacceptable, but that's beyond votes – it's flagging domain. Inadvertently providing misinformation is bad, but nothing you can really punish. Everybody makes mistakes sometimes, that's why peer review is always needed. And again, the most important thing about that peer review is to _point out_ wrong information, which works best if downvoting is _not_ associated with any strong hurting-connotation.

Comment: Most of the "fail to help the OP" cases I see fall into one of two categories. Either the answer is wrong, in which case we shouldn't be encouraging the poster to post more wrong answers even if they're trying to help, or the question was missing vital information and the answer was right for the question as it was when the answer was posted, in which case the answer shouldn't be downvoted at all.

Comment: Inadvertently providing misinformation is no better than inadvertently posting bad questions. People who do either don't usually intend to do it. It's hard to argue that posting bad questions deserves punishment, but posting bad answers, which does far more harm, doesn't deserve punishment. If we want to encourage better asking from bad askers, shouldn't we encourage better answering from bad answerers?

Comment: @user2357112 well, the point is that posting bad answers does _not_ do more harm, as long as there are enough other answers and reviewers to comment / balance the scores. A wrong answer with -2 score beneath a couple of decent answers won't mislead anybody. And the less these potential answers and reviewers are busy with bad questions, there more likely that is. IOW, we should generally try to keep the answers/question ratio high, and that's facilitated by generally scoring answers more positively than questions.

Comment: An accepted wrong answer will never get buried, and a buried but rep-positive wrong answer will encourage continued bad answering habits, possibly leading to wrong answers that accumulate too many upvotes to bury before someone who knows their stuff comes along. We do not need wrong answers to demonstrate misconceptions; right answers can do that, with an explanation of the misconception in the answer itself instead of in an argument in the comments that might get nuked by the mods.

Comment: Accepted wrong answers are horrible, but again that's really the asker's fault (and fortunately very uncommon, at least in the tags I'm active in). Wrong answers that accumulate early upvotes are a bigger problem, but what are you going for here? Unless you punish downvotes with >10 points, an answer that can't be pushed below 0 will also always have a net positive score. So the best weapon remains to _not discourage downvoting_. And, repeating myself, that means we should not associate it with much score, because most people are friendly and hesitate from actively causing anybody harm.

Comment: Furthermore, for an answer that's inadvertently wrong but well-phrased (which tend to be the ones that get upvoted) there's also a good chance that upon comment, the poster will amend it, or agree with an edit by somebody else. And then it's no problem anymore that the originally-wrong answer remains on top!

Comment: @user2357112 I don't know where you got that asking bad questions is a punishable offense. The system does not "punish" users. Users who have a history of posting questions that are not received well by the community will be rate limited or prevented from asking further questions, but this is not about the user, it is about the content they provide. This is the same with answers, users who have a history of posting answers that are not well received by the community may also be rate limited and prevented from providing further answers, but again this is not about the user, rather the content.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: What I was going for is that bad answers *do* cause harm in common cases. Ideally, increasing the weight of downvotes would reduce the incentives for the behavior patterns that lead to wrong answers, reducing the number of cases where they end up in a position where they can't be buried.

Comment: @TinyGiant well, that's the closest you get to “punishment” in a system that's all about rubber points... of course the word is a bit out of place. But there's a difference between questions and answers in regard to “about the use vs. about the content”, namely, questions tend to be about a concrete problem the OP has, i.e. this _starts out_ as a personal thing, whereas answers are always about the given problem / about the content itself. Hence a bad answer is self-punishment by itself (“what did I waste my time for writing this?”), whereas bad questions can still reward the OP with answers.