# What is the ground of earning reputation with overall negative scored vote questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation

With the reputation earning system, a question with score +2/-4 or a response +1/-4 will give +2 reputation.

Why is the reputation system unbalanced on questions/answers? What is the motivation behind this choice?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion

Comment: Downvotes are perceived as extremely painful already with just -2 points.

Comment: Or do you mean why do answers earn more rep? Because we want/value answers more than questions.

Comment: check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7322/should-the-weight-of-downvotes-be-increased/7344

Comment: related as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356164/increase-the-downvote-penalty-for-downvotee-on-answers-from-2-to-4

Answer (score 15):

I can name a few reasons from the top of my head:

- **To keep people motivated in contributing**

  Downvotes are perceived as extremely painful with -2 rep already because receiving one carries the message: "Go away, you're not welcome here". With the imbalance, if the person receives at least some upvotes, they will still see some gained reputation, carrying the message that their efforts were judged to have at least *some* worth, and they should keep trying.

  For the same reason, downvotes are not notified of on the reputation toolbar button.
- **Downvotes are actually the next best thing to upvotes**

  The actual social "quality scale" is like this: *like -- dislike -- ignore*. If a post attracted downvotes, this means it incited at least *some* response in people, and they went to the trouble to spend their time and do something.

  If it's an answer, this counts double because downvoting an answer also takes your *own* reputation, forcing you to think twice if it's really so harmful to just be let be that you must warn others even at the cost of your own contribution score.

  Besides, people could dislike something not only if it's of low quality but because it's *controversial* (e.g. [if they feel it shows nefarious intent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent)). If anything, this speaks *in favor* of the quality of such a post because it managed to attract such a strong response. Controversial posts will likely attract both upvotes and downvotes, and the imbalance gives the person a chance to at least break even in such a case.

  This is even more critical at sites which discuss more subjective topics since a downvote there could mean mere disagreement with the advice.

Comment: It's just soooo tempting to not vote on this post. :-)

Comment: Downvoted because ivan would prefer downvote to no vote. Turns out it works either way in this case.

Comment: The concept is called [loss aversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion), and more than anything the inequality between up and downvote, and the lack of notification about negative reputation changes are set up the way they are to prevent people from whining on meta about downvotes as much as possible.

Comment: @TinyGiant I considered referring to the psychlogical phenomenon but ultimately decided against it. First, I've got a hunch there's more than one factor at play, so cliche'ing it to a single phenomemon would be inaccurate. Second, and foremost, psyche is irrelevant on itself: what is important is how this hooks with the site's goals and core values. So I chose to present things from that standpoint instead.

Comment: @Joshua That's oversimplification. I said I prefer downvote to no _attention_, vote or no vote. There's no "meh" vote, or "absolutely no idea" vote, or "wtf is that" vote, after all. I can live with you downvote though, dw.

Answer (score 7):

An upvote typically means that the post helped someone solve a real life programming problem, likely saving hours or days of work.  A downvote just means someone disagreed with the post, wasting only seconds or at most minutes reading it.  Therefore, from the standpoint of helping the programming community, an upvote represents more of a gain than a downvote does a loss.

Even if all downvotes represented people who used a post and found it didn't work, trying something that doesn't work costs less than the benefit from trying something that does work.

Comment: I really like your comparision of time and votes

Comment: Not necessarily. Trying an approach and finding that it doesn't work can take just as long -- if not longer due to trying variations, too, to make sure it's not just me getting it wrong.