# Why should the answerer lose if asker deletes a question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Imagine a situation where someone asks a question and I, after thoroughly putting in my effort, get 3-4 upvotes on the answer, but unfortunately it turns out that the question was not well-received by the community, and the question gets 2 downvotes.

If the asker deletes the question, in order save 4 points, then why should I lose my 30-40 points? Should not there be some penalty for deleting questions with one or more answers? On deleting many questions you may be banned from asking more, but I am talking about a single question.

Comment: Did you search the meta for similar questions before posting? And where is the _feature-request_?

Comment: The situation you describe can not possibly happen.

Comment: related: [Shouldn't we revert reputation gains for answers to closed questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255782/shouldnt-we-revert-reputation-gains-for-answers-to-closed-questions)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometimes we do lose, and that's just part of life.  We can minimise our losses by recognizing question askers likely to pull a BS move like this.

These people typically ask very low quality questions.  Questions where they haven't bothered debugging, or where they haven't done any research on their own.  Your answer may embarrass them, so they delete as soon as they realize their stupid mistake.

Another big red flag are users who don't spend any time asking a well-formed question.  Have they littered their questions with cheezburgerspeak?  Ur can haz 2 b carefuls of deez fokes.  Have they spent more than a second making sure their code is formatted correctly?  Have they crapped out a big block of text, or have they formatted their question well?  *Do they give you the impression that they haven't spent more than the absolute minimum amount of time to create the question?* If so, be leery, as they have already demonstrated that they don't, at a minimum, care about the community.

And stay far away from people who post off topic questions.  You can spend a good deal of time answering them only to have the community downvote, close and delete it.  You waste your time feeding these people information, just as they waste our time vomiting off topic questions everywhere.

Just keep your head about you and be reluctant to spend time helping people who refuse to spend time asking a decent question, and you'll find you get screwed over this way rarely, if at all.

Comment: When the question is in cheezburgerspeak, I (maybe incorrectly) assume that their code is going to be in the spaghettiprogramming language, and tend to move on

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro darn you, now I'm hungry

Answer (score 23):

The question author cannot delete a question that has answers with a positive score.

So either the answer *isn't* a quality answer because it doesn't have a positive score, or the question was deleted by a mod or many community members because they felt that the entire Q/A was not of value, and should be deleted.  Note that reputation is not reversed for deleted answers with a score over 3 that are older than 60 days, meaning if the content was considered notably valuable once, but then the values of the site change over time, the contribution is still acknowledged (in the form of rep).

Comment: "Positively scored" --> only a score of +3 preserves rep for old deleted posts, I believe?

Comment: It should be noted that if you're spending a lot of time answering a bad question that is likely to be closed and/or deleted, you have no one to blame but yourself.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen *pre-emptively goes to sit in the corner and wait for this meta question to be deleted

Comment: 122,388 is @Servy's rep! Whatever you do is presumably correct!