# Nullify reputation earned from votes on answers while their question is closed as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, answers, duplicate-questions, reputation

Answering duplicate questions has been an ongoing controversy on meta, and I've found that the central divisions over previous suggestions often boil down to the following points:

- Discouraging answers to duplicate questions is undesired by some because:

  - It assumes bad intentions, or at least assumes that reputation is the only incentive.
  - It goes against evaluating posts solely on merit.
- Discouraging answers to duplicate questions is desired by others because:

  - These posts correlate strongly with high levels of noise.
  - They have the appearance of bad intentions, so voters wish to avoid rewarding them on principle.

So it seems that an ideal suggestion would be, rather than to *discourage answers to duplicate questions*, we need to *enable the evaluation of answers based solely on merit*.

We can achieve this by nullifying reputation earned from answers to duplicate questions. This relieves voters from the burden of deciding whether their vote gives the impression of encouraging bad intentions, and allows them to start voting based only on the merit of the answer.

#### This potentially solves four problems:

- It discourages punishing good answers with good intentions. This will *encourage*, rather than discourage, potential answerers with good intentions that otherwise wouldn't post in order to avoid punishing downvotes.
- It will stop the common practice of answering duplicate questions in comments before closing them. This is a fundamental misuse of comments caused by the stigma of answering a potential duplicate question. This feature request will remove that stigma.
- It will encourage answerers seeking reputation to consider posting on the *original* question instead. In the case of canonical duplicate targets, this will lead to more answers that address a broader audience than just the asker of the duplicate question, creating more useful information for more people, with better visibility (because canonical duplicate targets are very easy to find in Google searches).
- It may result in reducing the frequency of ill-intentioned answers that tend to be more noise than information.*

*<sub>The magnitude of this side-effect will depend on how strongly the incentive for reputation correlates to low quality answers on duplicate questions though, which is why I prefaced it with "may".</sub>

**This feature request is *not* an attempt to reduce the volume of incoming duplicate questions**, which was one of the primary objections raised to [a similar feature request several years back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255782/shouldnt-we-revert-reputation-gains-for-answers-to-closed-questions).

Full disclosure, I am guilty of commonly answering duplicate questions with brief comments before closing them as such. **If this feature request were implemented, I would start posting more thorough and complete answers to duplicate questions before closing them**, knowing that it wouldn't have the appearance of bad intentions anymore. *Marking my answers to duplicate questions as a "wiki" post is not a good enough solution*, because I would not want other authors to edit my answers under such circumstances.

Some details I suggest for this feature request (willing to edit any of these if there is strong consensus on adjustments):

- No retroactive removal of reputation for existing answers
- If a question is closed as a duplicate, only the reputation earned from an answer, which counts towards the answerer's current daily limit at the time of the closure, will be removed
- Further votes will not affect the user's reputation
- If a duplicate question is re-opened, only reputation earned from the answer, which would count towards the answerer's current daily limit at the time of re-opening, will be added
- Further votes will count towards reputation as normal

One thought that I considered while writing these details was to continue counting downvotes, but I believe that only allowing downvotes to count towards reputation for an answer of a duplicate question would lead to more potential for abuse. In addition to downvotes, we still have the ability to flag and delete bad answers that don't need to be there, and I believe those tools are sufficient for accomplishing that.

#### Rationale

- If you are expecting the question you are answering to quickly be closed as a duplicate, then you already know you should be looking for the duplicate target rather than spending time writing a quick answer before the closure.
- If you believe that your answer is truly very useful to a lot of people and deserves the reputation for upvotes, then you should be posting your answer on the original question instead of the duplicate question.
- If your answer is only useful in the context of the duplicate question, and would be too specific or out of context in the original question, either:

  - **The original question is not a good duplicate target and the closed question needs to be re-opened** (I do see this happen with canonical duplicate targets that don't cover an edge-case which prevents more general answers from being applicable), in which case your answer may be useful to a broader audience and deserves the reputation earned from upvotes
  - Your answer really is only worth the +15 reputation from being accepted and no more, because you're only trying to help one person and the information you've provided is not reusable enough for a broader audience.

As a reminder, this feature request is specifically for *duplicate* questions only, not for other close vote reasons.

Comment: as I suggested previously this can be made by converting the Q (and answers) to a wiki one which will nullify all the new Rep

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm given to understand that marking answers as a wiki is non-reversible, and it also has the implication that the answer invites contributions from other authors, neither of which is compatible with this feature request.

Comment: it doesn't need to work *exactly* like wiki but using the wiki feature plus some adjustment can make this possible. From a Dev perspective it can be an argument that such feature isn't difficult to implement since we will be using some existing stuff.

Comment: @TemaniAfif fair enough, I misunderstood your initial comment then. Yes, implementation details of the "wiki" feature may be useful to reuse for this feature request.

Comment: I'm very curious to learn what the objections are to this feature request, the downvotes seem to suggest I've overlooked something important.

Comment: I mostly use Stack Overflow to learn. When I've already learned about something, I tune my learning here. I quite like duplicates because more often than not they give different varieties of the same thing. When I have an actual issue, duplicates are especially helpful. I'm not referring to identical answers, which are irritating to me. I'm not comfortable broadly nullifying the reputation of Answers to those Questions. I'd like people to want to answer, not be hesitant.

Comment: @Scratte I understand your concern. In my opinion, this will encourage a larger portion of answers to duplicate questions to be informational and not just noise. I do not believe that good answers to duplicate questions will be stopped by this feature. Answerers will be reassured by incentivizing voters to vote based on the merit of the answer, rather than downvote it because it answers a duplicate question. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Scratte thanks for the feedback though. I've adjusted the wording in my feature request to emphasize my belief that potential _good_ answers to duplicate questions will be encouraged rather than discouraged.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You're relying solely on the answerers altruism and satisfaction that their work in a great Answer has value to others. But I don't think it is. Personally, I'd just stop answering anything that was less than a week old, just in case the new Question turns out to be a duplicate of some sort. We're already answering even though the votes never move on our answer. To see a great answer with moving votes as if it's a meta-post, would be.. discouraging.

Comment: @Scratte `We're already answering even though the votes never move on our answer.` This is _exactly_ why this feature request will be incentivizing in the right way.

Comment: I hate to go hunting for a perfect duplicate (the SO search function is ... not very useful for that) and return wiv a good 'un, only to find someone already *answered*, got upvotes, and the Green Tick. That said: "the common practice of answering duplicate questions in comments before closing them" does not earn rep so it doesn't belong in that list.

Comment: @usr2564301 but it's a practice that's caused by the stigma of answering a question that's about to be closed as a duplicate. That's why it's in that list. With this feature request, answering a potential duplicate question is no longer a stigma.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts There is a difference in my opinion. To answer a low traffic Question where the poster cannot be bothered to say "Thank you" does not mean votes will never move. We all know this, but hope that maybe someone else will find our work useful. Green bubbles make us happy. To know that our work was **very** useful, but we're still at 51 reputation points, is not encouraging in my opinion.

Comment: @Scratte here's the thing. We still don't want to encourage duplicate questions. Your answer's votes will count towards your rep until the question is closed as a duplicate. If you are expecting that to happen quickly, then you already know you should be looking for the duplicate target rather than spending time writing a quick answer before the dupe hammer comes down. If you believe that your answer is truly very useful to a lot of people, then you should be posting on the original question instead. If it's useful only to that asker, the answer is not worth rep besides the +15 green tick.

Comment: What's the chance of the answerer deleting their Answer and re-posting it on the duplicate target as soon as the first tick comes in? The variety gets lost because now the Answer is modified and targeted at another Question. I also think you're missing  that new users are probably not very good at finding duplicates. Even if I find an interesting Question that I cannot find a duplicate target for, once I answer it, it will hit the home page.. and it'll be closed the same day.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Answer box is below, folks. The question has been re-opened. Please don't use comments for extended discussion.

Comment: @CodyGray sorry for the ping but I don't know who else to ask. Do you know if it's possible to [create a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and find out how much reputation has been earned under the criteria I'm proposing to amend? Just a yes or no is sufficient, I just don't want to put in the effort and find out later that it's impossible.

Comment: Duplicate of [Shouldn't we revert reputation gains for answers to closed questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255782/shouldnt-we-revert-reputation-gains-for-answers-to-closed-questions)

Comment: @TylerH perhaps you weren't around at the time but if you look at the edit history, this was initially closed as a duplicate of that and Cody reopened it after I added "This feature request is not an attempt to reduce the volume of incoming duplicate questions"

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I disagree that the question is not a duplicate. While the driving reason may be different, the question being asked is still the same.

Comment: I'm not the right person to ask about queries, unfortunately. I'm sure it is possible. Rene would probably be your go-to person for crafting an SEDE query. Post a new Meta question about it, or perhaps edit this one.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to address the symptom of the problem rather than the cause... and you even say this in bold in your request:

> If this feature request were implemented, I would start posting more thorough and complete answers to duplicate questions before closing them

Which is... well... wrong.

The main reason we don't want people to post answers to duplicate questions is not reputation gain. It is **duplication of content** across multiple questions. There's a reason closing a question as a duplicate *points to the duplicate target*: signposts are helpful. People gaining reputation from duplication of content is just an unfortunate side effect.

Comment: Maybe my personal opinion is not widely shared, but answering a specific question with a specific answer is not duplication of content, even if answers on the duplicate target are compatible with the question being closed. I feel that these sorts of answers are well-intentioned, but that they don't deserve the same reputation for tailoring to one person as the answers to unclosed questions that are intended for a more general audience.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I don't think one can square "*I can answer this in a way that's not a duplicate*" with "*the question should be closed as a duplicate*". Any differences between a duplicate question & the target are just details. If you'll notice, there's not many questions that are marked as duplicates that are *literal, exact* duplicates; they're different questions, but they're all posing the same question or problem. What you're doing is sitting down for an hour and catching a nice fish for someone. We'd rather you just sat down for a minute and teach them how to fish for themselves.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts There are two primary issues with 'giving a man a fish' on Stack Overflow: First, it's not scalable. There are *wayyy* more people here with questions than there are experts/knowledgeable people to answer them. If we spend time trying to answer every question, we don't get anywhere; we won't be able to grow or help nearly as many people. Second, the point of content on the site is not just for the person asking (or answering), but also (and mostly) for the people *to come*. We want nice, polished, comprehensive content because that's what helps the most future readers.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The optimal way to provide that content is to put it in one place and link to it anywhere interested parties may land. You may provide a useful answer for one person, but that answer isn't as useful if it's on its own. It would definitely be more valuable at the canonical location, where readers can see the root cause of their problem and all of the best potential ways to fix it to learn and decide for themselves which to apply. It is for that reason that the community wants you to provide your answer to a duplicate question *on the target* rather than on the duplicate.

Comment: Those are all good points, but the problem I'm trying to address is that the current model encourages these "giving a man a fish" answers for one person, that aren't even necessarily useful to _them_ as long as they can earn one or two upvotes. At least with my feature request we can discourage these kinds of answers that are posted with incentive for quick reputation, since it will be nullified when the question is closed anyway, and people who aren't posting the answers for reputation will most likely continue to post _anyway_, regardless of whether you think it's a good idea or scalable.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Right, my answer addresses the point in your post that says if we remove reputation you will be *more encouraged* to pursue the "give a man a fish" behavior. By posting my answer, the hope is that you will come to understand such behavior is not desirable whether there is rep to be had or not. We don't *want* people to give others fish. We *want* them to *teach others* to fish.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is you would rather continue to incentivize answers to duplicates with reputation, than to remove the incentive of reputation for answering duplicate questions, and make votes on answers to duplicate questions more accurately reflect their merit alone (since votes won't count towards reputation), because a handful of people like me exist that don't mind giving a fish for free once in a while in addition to following the standard procedure. Got it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No, that's not what I'm saying at all. I'm not sure how you got "we should reward dupe answerers with rep" from "don't answer duplicate questions".

Comment: Because that's what's happening with the current system

Answer (score -3):

I don't like it for this primary reason: *We want answerers!*

Your proposal may get rid of:

- Users that deliberately posts on a duplicate Question.
- Users that post their identical answers on duplicate Questions. (Usually in quick succession. They're very good at finding those duplicates. But there's already systems in place to handle this. Yet, it still happens.)

Your proposal may also get rid of:

- Users that post with good intentions without realizing that there is a duplicate target.
- Users that tried but didn't find the duplicate target. (Finding them is easier for seasoned tag users.)

I don't like the idea that we should discourage answers because of a few bad apples. I find this especially worrying, because it seems to be making the "bad intentions" assumption:

> If you are expecting the question you are answering to quickly be
>   closed as a duplicate, then you already know you should be looking for
>   the duplicate target rather than spending time writing a quick answer
>   before the closure.

- Even when the Question is closed soon after the answer is posted, the user could still very well be in the second group. There's no way to tell.
- Slow answerers would not be spared.

Reputation points is **the** main reward mechanism on the site. I don't think it's a good idea to take that away. Once a users feels punished, they are less likely to take the same risk. A few hateful downvotes (aimed at the user, not the post) is less discouraging than the loss of 100 upvotes for a great Answer.

---

I **used to** flag for duplicate targets, but unfortunately there have only been one of these two outcomes:

- The Question author accepts it. (Happens very rarely)
- My flag ages away. (**This** is making me feel like I'm wasting my time.)

---

On a personal note: I don't have a long list of Answers on duplicates, but if this ever got implemented, I'd hope for my Answers to not get a green tick. At least then I'd be able to remove my Answer once I realized that it was redundant. Apart from that when I read other people's posts, I quite prefer variation in Answers.

Comment: Protip, start a google search with `site:stackoverflow.com` and some keywords from the question you're searching duplicate targets for; you'll find them much faster that way than by searching through Stack Overflow directly.

Comment: No, we don't just want answers. We want a repository of quality Q&A without duplicated content.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't think we want to turn **good** answerers away before they learn the routine was my point.

Comment: I’d argue that someone answering dupes isn’t a good answerer.

Comment: The first two bullet points are good things; the second two I don't think would happen. Either way, I think this answer is concerned for the wrong reason: reputation.

Comment: @TylerH The Question was aimed at reputation. While it would be preferable that everyone didn't care at all for reputation, it's there. It's there as an incentive. I don't see the point of pretending no one is concerned with it.

Comment: On a side note: I find it quite amusing that this Question in particular was closed as a duplicate. I would not have answered it, if I had know ;)