# Get more rep for answering questions the longer it goes without an answer

Tags: feature-request

This site seems to generally look like a swarm of rep-hunting vultures trying to answer the easiest questions the fastest.

There are obvious reasons for this. Easier questions are easier and faster to answer. The faster you answer, the more likely you are to be the accepted answer and given thumbs up.

So this feature request is to fix the problem of worthwhile questions being actively discouraged from being answered because you get far fewer reps per hour if you focus on answering them.

The settings of this feature can be tweaked in various ways. I'm not pretending these are the best settings, but just to help stoke your imagination, it could be something like:

- an accepted answer is worth 75% less if you answered in the first 5 minutes,
- a thumbs up is worth 75% less for the first 5 minutes
- an accepted answer is worth 100% more if you answer after 12 hours

It would be nice if it was on a sliding scale, and maybe only questions with thumbs up are worth more after a long period of time.

Comment: Vultures are scavengers, they would rarely hunt for prey. And a group of vultures would be a "flock", not a "swarm".

Comment: "an accepted answer is worth 100% more if you answer after 12 hours" - so you're now instead encouraging waiting. Answering first doesn't mean anything if the new FGITW is delayed for 12 hours after the question is posted. In fact, at twice the rep, it'll make waiting lucrative instead. This won't actually encourage better answers or discourage FGITW-ing, it'll encourage delayed FGITWing, and end up discouraging anyone answering between 5 minutes and 12 hours instead. This is _not_ a good idea

Comment: This is also what the bounty system is for. If your question isn't answered in a suitable-to-you amount of time, you may stake own reputation for an answerer to score by providing a quality answer. The more rep you put up, the more likely an answerer will go above and beyond. I can't speak to others' experiences, but I haven't had problems with how bounties work. I think this feature request would diminish bounties today, which don't have the problem of encouraging late answers; bounties are offered when the asker or another interested user creates one.

Comment: If you're going this way, then perhaps it's better to go further by [nullifying the rep if (easy) questions are closed as a dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396627/2821954)... Also, "upvote", not "thumbs up"..

Comment: Otherwise, if someone who is an expert can write a very detailed answer in just 5 minutes, why should they be penalized for posting it too quickly?

Comment: Vultures, [like corvids](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0ulEaYcV5g&t=1m57s), have an undeserved bad rap (not helped by *[Lucky Luke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Luke)* et al). They [are extremely valuable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_vulture_crisis#Consequences) - *"The carcasses formerly eaten by vultures rot in village fields leading to contaminated drinking water. The disappearance of vultures has allowed other species such as rat and feral dog populations to grow."*

Answer (score 7):

There is a better solution for what you want:

### Close questions as duplicate

> .. answer the **easiest** questions the **fastest**.
>
> There are obvious reason for this. **Easier** questions are **easier** and **faster** to answer ..

Easy to answer and fast to answer means that the question is more likely to be a duplicate. Let's not focus on Rep but focus on curation. We already have the tools for this.

Comment: Though that behavior should be encouraged by some gamification incentives, which could even be considered _"attractive"_ for higher rep users (e.g. gold tag badge holders) having that privilege.

Answer (score 4):

If it's not in the HNQ then I can count on one finger the number of times I've answered a 12-hour old question.

If your idea was implemented then there would coincide a highly-upvoted feature request to add a filter to see questions which are 11 hours and 55 minutes old.

I fail to see why you think a quick and good answer isn't worthy of a full score.

People should be voting on quality and accurateness. If this is not being upheld then I'd rather hear your idea for educating voters instead of shifting the FGITW problem 12 hours into the future.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a discontinuity. It could be like a [Dutch auction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_auction).