# Why is the quality of PHP questions, on Stack Overflow, in decline?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I've been on Stack Overflow since 2012 and have seen a fairly steady decline in the quality of questions asked in the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag over the years. However, I noticed a significant **incline** in the sheer volume of these questions in the last couple of years.

A lot of the very **low-quality** questions stem from every-day problems like syntax/parse errors, *why isn't this code working PEBKACs*, and other poorly-researched questions that could have been better answered by a quick Google search or just spending a little more time playing with the code, or even just searching Stack Overflow for similar questions that provided useful answers.

Sometimes even closing a question as duplicate led the OP to re-ask the same question with "this did not answer my question" in the title/body, when the duplicate clearly did. It seems that if the answer is not specifically tailored to their use-case/code, a general answer is unacceptable from their point-of-view.

I developed a theory that the majority of these questions come from students or hobbyists that have been misguided, to believe that Stack Overflow is a general help forum, where anyone can ask for and get some quick help with their code.

So I decided to head over to [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to see if there was any data to support my theory. Sure enough, I dug some interesting data, but I'm still not quite sure what to make of it yet.

#### The Hourly Trends

Looking at a histogram of when [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) questions are asked, it seems that historically, the peak hours are usually between 8 AM and 4 PM UTC.

[image]

So far it seems that, generally, day-light hours bring in the most [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) questions, which if we go by the theory that the bulk of these questions come from students spending their days looking for help with their projects/homework, it might make sense.

#### The Daily Trends

[image]

Looking at a histogram of [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) questions by days of the week supports this notion even further. There're almost twice as many questions asked during week days as there are during weekends.

#### The Monthly Trends

[image]

Looking at a histogram of [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) questions by month further supports this theory as you can spot a significant ~20% drop, *historically*, during the start of the school year, and 5-10% upticks during holidays and summer months.

#### The Yearly Trends

[image]

Looking at the data by year, you can clearly see that question scores are tending downwards, while the amount of questions are trending upwards very quickly.

In 2011, the amount of questions asked that were tagged [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), nearly doubled from the previous year in 2010. By 2012 we can see that aggregate question scores start to suffer and trend downwards as the amount posted questions rise and trend upwards.

[image]

Even though [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) is the 4th most popular tag on Stack Overflow, it's oddly the 7th highest scoring tag out of the top 10, lagging way behind less popular tags like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Which leads me to believe that the quality of scores that the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag suffers from must be the result of a lack of precedence.

Most people tag their questions as [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) just because PHP is involved in virtually every aspect of their stack in their web development process. So while the question might really be about JavaScript or Apache httpd, or even just HTML/CSS, the fact that PHP is somehow involved means the question likely gets tagged under php as well. Meaning that PHP tagged questions share in a lot of cumulative blame as well.

If it's not the result of masses being misled to believe that they can turn to Stack Overflow whenever they run into a problem with their PHP code, then what is it? What can be done to improve the overall quality of the PHP tag score on Stack Overflow?

Should I even care? Is this really a sign of a bad trend in the works that's detrimental to the PHP ecosystem on Stack Overflow or just typical behavior that's to be expected as the site grows?

---

## Update

I'm including the monthly standard deviations scatter chart based on further discussion in the comments to see if there is any more meaningful data there that contradicts or strengthens my theory. It's come to my attention that the histogram of question distribution by month may not be as meaningful as it is presented to be.

So this scatter only includes data for complete years (2009 - 2015).

[image]

#### Showing my math

[Here's a gist with the CSV dump of the data in the chart](https://gist.github.com/srgoogleguy/605ec4e7e16a4bc8f5bcde6096e61e35).

[Here's a gist with the CSV dump of the aggregate monthly question data](https://gist.github.com/srgoogleguy/2cc23689b8e6acaac9c386bf044ae249)

A **standard deviation** is calculated as the square root of the variance. The **variance** is the average of the squared differences from the mean. The **mean** is sum of all members in the set divided by the number of members in the set.

So, for example, during the year of 2009, there are 12 months. The total number of questions asked are `20548`. This is given from `s = [645, 775, 909, 976, 1189, 1586, 2042, 2205, 2279, 2385, 2714, 2843]`. Thus the mean of of the set `s` is `20548 / 12` which gives us `1712.333`.

The variance is then calculated by the following function.

```
function variance(set, mean) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i in set) {
        value = set[i];
        sum += (value - mean) ** 2;
    }
    return sum / set.length;
}
```

So `variance(set, 1712.333)` gives us `575158.222`

The standard deviation is then the square root of the variance giving us `Math.sqrt(575158.222) == 758.391`.

So on each month of 2009 if we take the number of questions asked, subtract the number of questions asked from the previous month, we can see how many standard deviations removed the current month is from its previous month.

Of course, for the first month we have no previous month so it's `(645 - 0) / 758.391` for January of 2009. Then `(775 - 645) / 758.391` for February of 2009... so on and so forth.

So far this shows there are some months that tend to be further from the standard deviation then others, but not consistently enough. There's probably some math error in my calculations here that I'm not aware of... So please do feel free to point out where I might have gone wrong.

I'm by no means a data scientist or have any advanced mathematical skills beyond the average Joe. *So constructive criticism is both valued and welcomed*.

Comment: Those patterns are not just limited to [php].  And those users are not being mislead either, it is the inevitable side-effect of the CEO's efforts to make SO more accessible.  More about that in [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for sharing that post. It was very insightful. Glad to know I'm not crazy and that this is a fluidly evolving trend. Still not quite sure what to make of all of this. Is it a good thing? Is it a bad thing? But at least I can be sure it's a *thing*.

Comment: (*"I noticed a significant incline in the sheer volume"* - can *incline* be used in that context?)

Comment: @Kaiido It is _not_ an issue when less good questions are asked. The issue is the questions being _less good_. The main cause are these _too localized_ questions. Code dump of something complex including frameworks and unrelated code, why doesn't it work, and - with a bit luck - perhaps what's the expected behavior/output. People aren't investing much effort into reducing code to the smallest possible reproduce case. They don't even really attempt to show that they see where the problem comes from. I _really_ wished I could close these more effectively … Perhaps give silver badges 3 CV weight.

Comment: @Sherif: "*which if we go by the theory that the bulk of these questions come from students spending their days looking for help with their projects/homework, it might make sense.*" You could also go by the theory that these questions are from non-students looking for help with their work. The time of day, and day of week of the questions ultimately tells you little about who's asking.

Comment: @Sherif: "*Looking at a histogram of php questions by month further supports this theory as you can spot a significant ~20% drop, historically, during the start of the school year, and 5-10% upticks during holidays and summer months.*" If your theory is that students are the majority asking such new questions, then we would see an *increase* during school periods and a decrease outside of them. But that's not what your graph shows. It's far more likely that we simply have had more questions recently, since the falloff happens when you started to count Sept '15 against Aug '16.

Comment: @Sherif: That is, it's not a 20% falloff; it's a 20% increase over last year at this time.

Comment: You should run these queries on the 40 mayor tags and then against the entire site... the trend is general.

Comment: "day light hours" is rather judgmental.  The sun never sets on . . . places where people use Stack Overflow, and there are large user bases in many time zones.  The rest of your observations about quality are probably true, though.

Comment: I'm unsure how daylight hours strengthens the theory that students are causing the trends. I work during the day and typically ask questions during the day, whereas when I was in university I did my studying in the evenings...is this not typical?

Comment: Those trends I would wager are related to the perceived domain space of PHP (primarily web) as well as the language's overall maturity and relative ease of picking it up.  Comparing PHP to other language tags is irrelevant.  Each language has its own strengths and weaknesses.  You also have to consider that StackOverflow is strictly for direct Q&A while PHP can frequently be more of a conversation these days.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the conclusions drawn from your data--questions during the working day are unlikely to be from students in lecture. And if the number of questions on particular days of the week were driven by students, I'd expect to see an influx on Sunday (homework crunch), fewer questions in July/August and more questions in the fall semester months.

Comment: Related posts http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252443/4099593, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324072/4099593

Comment: @Braiam Yes, but PHP is just exceptionally bad. [All-time](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382180/post-scores-per-tag), it has the lowest average question score of the top 25 tags, and ranks 4th in the top 50 only behind `[vb.net]`, `[excel]` and (behold!) `[wordpress]`. [In 2015](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382321/post-scores-per-tag-2015) it looks similar, except that sql-related tags like `[mysql]`, `[sql]`, `[sql-server]` and `[database]` rank even lower, making PHP only the worst on the top 10.

Comment: The stats here are pretty dubious, but so far no one has mentioned the [troublesome choice of a non-zero base on many of the graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misleading_graph#Truncated_graph).

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think a log10 based graph would be better

Comment: People always forget the roomba when looking at trends over time. There's a big drop-off at september because recently-posted rubbish is still around, whereas crud from last year has been removed. You also haven't accounted for the fact that posts gather upvotes over time, so it's inevitable that older posts score higher. But, subjectively at least, there has indeed been a huge decline in the quality of content all over SO in recent years (and meta is full of people asking if anyone else has spotted it).

Comment: @Dave I know I don't forget Roomba. Feeding that thing is a focus. And why didn't it run today at 1330 hours UTC like it always does.

Comment: This is a really fun question and I do like charts and graphs but fundamentally this mini-study isn't as meaningful as it could be because it doesn't draw any comparisons to other tags. Also it has some reasonable spin on it. You might want to dig up some stats to show that [tag:php] is in decline rather than e.g. *everything* being in decline, or say *web technologies* being in decline, or server-side programming, or whatever categories are relevant. That is, [tag:php] might not be special. Personally I see similar trends in [tag:java], [tag:android], [tag:c++], [tag:javascript], etc.

Comment: This question could be asked about just about any tag.

Comment: 8 am to 4 pm UTC is **not** daylight hours for most of the world's population, nor for most of SE's users. That's the middle of the night and early morning in the Americas and afternoon/evening in central and Eastern Asia.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Completely agree with you, thye are quite misleading. Also the comment *you can clearly see that question scores are tending downwards, while the amount of questions are trending upwards very quickly.* is completely false. In that graph it is **extremely hard** to see the upwards line since they are almost white over a white background...

Comment: @reirab 9-11 UTC overlaps though with central Europe and Africa and (+1) worktimes and India (+5.5) [and Middle East also] and 13-16 UTC with Europe and large parts of America. It's definitely when the largest share of worlds population (apart from China - which I guess - is thanks to GFW not very active on SO) is at work at the same time. It's not the whole time overlapping, but parts of it.

Comment: Students in general are not particularly likely to be doing homework, during business hours. As compared to workers, who are nearly certain to be doing work during business hours.

Comment: @ARich `I'm unsure how daylight hours strengthens the theory that students are causing the trends.`, well... I suppose in general more people are active during the day than at night. Perhaps it doesn't strengthen the theory by itself. It was just one of many things I looked at, laterally, when trying to support the theory with data. *The idea that activity historically increases during the day and periodically rises during school holidays and summer time.*

Comment: @NicolBolas This is possibly a biased in the data, however, StackOverflow started in August 2008, and my data ends early September 2016. That should be an even number of months over all. Any margin of error there in overlap should be fairly negligible. Historically the data does show an increase during those months. The data seems fairly correct to me, but sure there could be a biased in there somewhere I missed. I'm not data scientist. I definitely could be off here.

Comment: @NathanTuggy @Bakuriu `The stats here are pretty dubious` .. not sure what's dubious. This data comes from StackExchange Data Explorer directly. It can be independently verified. It's not like I can make anything up here. Also, I didn't chose non-zero base intentionally. I generated the charts via Google charts. Does that matter here? I'm pointing out the percentages and it's not like you can't see the figures in question. Sorry if the trend line colors were faded, also automatically generated by Google charts. But I can see the trend lines clearly myself. Maybe open image in new window?

Comment: @Sherif: The raw data is not in question. The statistical inferences and graphical representations *are* (for reasons given by others), and throwing data into a charting tool is unfortunately likely to give misleading results much of the time.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Not really sure how a visual representation of the data can give misleading **results**. The data remains the same. So the results are axiomatic. Attacking the charts or the representation of the data seems moot. Attack the data instead. That's why I'm posting this here. I want to find out what the data means. Not what you like or dislike about the charts.

Comment: It's more meaningful to me that claims are supported with data. That's one of the things I love about StackOverflow, actually. Have a theory or a claim to lay down? Support it with data. Have an opinion? Well... everyone's got those :)

Comment: @Sherif: See the WP link for some of the misleading trends in charts. Statistics is a much harder field than you appear to believe, and remaining blithely ignorant of the traps that have claimed many others is not the way to make a sound argument.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I did see your link and responded to it earlier. So really not sure why you're just making a circular argument there. Also, I didn't make any appearance or claim of having any fluency in the field of statistics. So that's just a silly response that plays on emotion. Trying to call me ignorant and relying on intimidation by how many people you can get to shout with you is also a play on emotions and a totally unfair assessment of me in general. You don't know anything about me or my skills. Let's not devolve to personal attacks. Show me data. That's what I'm here for.

Comment: @Sherif: That's *not* a personal attack. This post does not demonstrate a sound grasp of statistics and is making probably-invalid conclusions from the data and giving misleading impressions with its choice of presentation. I only know enough statistics myself to be dangerous, so I can't easily correct all the errors, only point out their general existence.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm OK with that since this post was never intended to demonstrate a sound grasp of statistics. It was intended to gather more feedback about whether or not the data supports the theory. Yes, it's a *theory*. It could be true or it could be false. I'd love to know what data can prove or disprove it either way. But, I guess what you're saying is you don't really have anything further to contribute.

Comment: @Sherif: "*Historically the data does show an increase during those months.*" If so, then it is on you to *present* that data. The data you presented does not support the conclusion that there is a statistically significant increase in PHP posts during the off-school months.

Comment: @NicolBolas ummm, actually I did present that data. That's a histogram you're looking at. It's the aggregate count of all questions tagged php on a given month. So January is the total number of questions asked on every January since Stack Overflow went public until today.

Comment: @Sherif: First, that doesn't change the March/April/May findings, which are statically identical to the summer findings. Second, let's say that the number of questions being asked is substantially increasing each year. Wouldn't that mean that Aug16 would be much higher than Aug15? The source of the discrepancy between Aug and Sept therefore *primarily* is that we haven't seen Sept16, not that there is a falloff every September. If we're getting 20% more questions asked this year than last year, than an aggregate that doesn't include this year will *naturally* be lower than one that does.

Comment: I have been thinking about this issue while observing new PHP questions every day. It leads to remember words from Zeev Suraski: *PHP's simplicity, while being a very positive thing, also created an unexpected negative side effect. It was so simple to use - that people without any background in computer science and no experience in development, could pick it up quickly and become ’dangerous’ in a very short time.*

Comment: @NicolBolas Not sure how you got there from that. But [here's the raw data in a gist](https://gist.github.com/srgoogleguy/2cc23689b8e6acaac9c386bf044ae249) if that helps.

Comment: @Sherif: That data only proves my point: there is no consistent change in the number of questions asked between August of a year and September of the *same year*. There is no consistent change between May of a year and June of the *same year*. Therefore, there is no correlation between school months and the number of PHP questions asked. Your charts are mis-representing the data.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't think looking for consistency proves anything either. But looking at patterns you can see regular increases during summer months and holiday months, which is all I said. Charts didn't **miss**-representing a thing. There's obvious fluctuation there from year to year. Maybe finding a standard deviation would be more helpful.

Comment: @Sherif: "*But looking at patterns you can see regular increases during summer months and holiday months, which is all I said.*" There are no regular increases. Jun-Aug16 are *lower* than Mar-May16. Dec15-Jan16 are *lower* than Feb-Mar16. Jun-Aug15 are flat relative to Sept-Nov15 and slightly *lower* than Mar-May15. Dec14-Jan15 is *much lower* than the months preceding or following it. The data does not support your interpretation of it.

Comment: Ummm... hold a second here. First of all, Mar/Apr counts as holiday months, because spring break. So you're comparing the wrong stuff there in the first place. Compare Mar-Aug with Sep - Feb, for example. When you add up all Mar-Aug totals and all Sep-Feb totals, the histogram gives you exactly what I have in the post. There is a 10% difference on average looking across all years. It might fluctuate a bit from year to year, but that's not my interpretation of anything. That's just the raw data. My interpretation of what it means might be wrong, but the data is not wrong.

Comment: What you just stated is basically when you compare the one half of X to the other half of X for a single year you disprove that X is greater than or less than Y. Which makes no sense at all. @NicolBolas

Comment: @Sherif: OK, this is the statement I take issue with: "*Looking at a histogram of php questions by month further supports this theory as you can spot a significant ~20% drop, historically, during the start of the school year, and 5-10% upticks during holidays and summer months.*" The data does not support the statement that, there is a drop of questions during school months, or an uptick in the number of questions during holidays or summer.

Comment: @Sherif: "*First of all, Mar/Apr counts as holiday months, because spring break.*" ... Spring break is a *single week*. Calling that a "holiday month", let alone *two months* is simply incorrect. At this point, you are cherry picking your data. "*When you add up all Mar-Aug totals and all Sep-Feb totals*" That is the wrong way to interpret the data. There are other year-over-year things happening, which would bias your results towards the months of 2016 that have completed already. If you want to find out if there is a yearly-event happening, you look at each year *independently*.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not cherry picking anything. I'm just looking at the data and trying to find out if it supports my hypothesis. Isn't that the entire point? But **fine** let's do it your way. Taking Mar-Aug of 2015, the standard deviation is `402.497`. Now look at the standard deviation of September through February of 2015-2016 and it's `636.486`. A higher standard deviation means the numbers are further from the mean. Do the math yourself for each year. Same pattern. Numbers are more spread out during Spring/Summer months. It's like I can make this up. ***It's right there in the data!***

Comment: @NicolBolas Also "*There are other year-over-year things happening, which would bias your results towards the months of 2016*" what are these things you speak of exactly? Please explain.

Comment: Rather than just tell me I'm wrong because you said I'm wrong explain where I went wrong. I'm not infallible, but telling someone this is wrong because this is wrong isn't helpful. Which is all you've done at length. Please provide supporting arguments so I can discover my errors.

Comment: @NicolBolas Also, "*Spring break is a single week. Calling that a "holiday month", let alone two months is simply incorrect.*" events can have ripple effects. I'm not trying to confuse causation with correlation here. I'm simply seeking supporting evidence for a theory in the data. The beginning of a school year is a dramatic shift for most people. It can disrupt the normal flow of behavior. Just like spring and seasonal change can disrupt the normal behavioral patterns. They can extend and blur in the data. You have to look at them over long time otherwise you can't see them clearly.

Comment: "Should I even care?" Of course, but Spolsky doesn't, so the end result is that SO will inevitably end up as YAEE (Yet Another Expert's Exchange). This is hugely ironic if you know one of the reasons SO was founded.

Comment: @Sherif: "*Taking Mar-Aug of 2015, the standard deviation is 402.497. ... A higher standard deviation means the numbers are further from the mean.*" What average are you measuring the deviation from? The average from within the Mar-Aug15 time period? The yearly average? Something else entirely?

Comment: @Sherif: "*I'm simply seeking supporting evidence for a theory in the data.*" That's not the right way to test a theory. First, you use that theory (school causes a drop in questions) to make a hypothesis ("If school causes a drop in questions, I should see a decrease in new questions when schools are open.") Then you test this hypothesis by looking at the data, comparing the question rate relative to when schools are open. You seem to be trying to fudge the definition of "when schools are open" in order to make the data support your theory. That's not how science works.

Comment: I'm afraid those are not averages but sums. *Total* PHP questions per month goes: 80668, 81305, 89878... So the reason September-December numbers are low is that... well, we haven't observed September-December 2016 yet. With all due respect, whole analysis seems flawed. It starts with a *trend line* fitted on, what, hours? You are making regression analysis on a variable that doesn't have meaningful greater/smaller relationships. You are connecting categories in a line plot. You are ignoring the fact that the earth is rotating. These are fundamentals; not advanced stuff.

Comment: @NicolBolas For each set, yes. I calculated the standard deviations at 6 month intervals starting from September through Feb (2008) and Feb through August and stopped at Aug 2016.

Comment: @NicolBolas [sharing results](https://gist.github.com/srgoogleguy/605ec4e7e16a4bc8f5bcde6096e61e35) feel free to double check my math here. Ignore the theory for a moment. What does this tell us?

Comment: @NicolBolas update, I included a standard deviation by average of year in the gist. That one probably makes more sense to look at anyway. I calculated how far removed each month is from the standard deviation.

Comment: You should add the term "in quality" to your post title. Also, is it not worth pointing out that the 6am-2pm peak times are basically working hours in India, where they map to 11:30am (Indians tend to come into work late) to 7:30pm?

Comment: Aside from the time zone issue, the time-of-day data is also committing base rate fallacy. Are PHP questions notably different from *the rest of the site* in terms of when questions are asked?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There comes a point where a resource like [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) has reached the full *breadth* of what it can cover within the constraints of what Stack Overflow considers to be on topic. What remains is a *lot* of noise throwing itself at the wall, with a tiny bit of signal occasionally emerging and bringing more *depth* to the resource. This problem isn't at all surprising, and I'm not even certain that the cause itself is problematic - any encyclopedic resource should have completeness as a big part of its definition of success.

What remains is what to do with that extremely irritating cloud of noise from which a tiny bit more signal *occasionally* emerges. That's something that we're going to be spending a significant amount of time studying and building around as we kick off the second iteration of the Stack Exchange quality project (highlights from the last one [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project) and [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project), though there's more that unfortunately wasn't tagged as such). This project is perennial, it doesn't really end, we just take a look at the impact of major efforts every 1.5 or so years and then start planning new ones.

Since I'm about to get a little windy, here's a `tl;dr;` of the first things we hope to focus on:

- ***Much more intelligent duplication detection***: We're not showing people the *right* duplicate even though we probably have it.
- ***Better stating our expectations of questions in the interface***: We don't do a very good job of helping brand new users ask questions with all of the ingredients that we expect. We also don't do a very good job of providing incentive to bother with any of that at all. We're looking at testing a more explanatory and guided interface for brand new accounts (it would be optional, but strongly encouraged).
- ***Better ways of filtering out noise***: Let's come up with better ways of not showing total noise to our most engaged and knowledgeable users until we can better determine that there's some signal in there to mine.

#### All of this is still in planning and subject to change. But I wanted to put it out there now so folks know we're working on it. Now, here comes the wind:

Sometime later this week, I'm going to be announcing a special collaboration effort with the University Of Melbourne. A graduate project focused on *fast* analysis of questions in order to determine not only if they're duplicates, but quickly determine the *best* duplicate given the context of what's being asked. Interestingly, and unsurprisingly, the method also requires very quickly being able to determine if something *isn't* a duplicate.

They've gone as far as being able to validate their model through human analysis of many non-academic questions, but the expertise of our math, science and programming communities is needed in order to vet the rest of the data. They'll be going to 15 or so individual meta sites and providing a link to a tool where users with close privileges can say if any given questions are duplicates, similar but not duplicates, or in no way duplicate each other. This will help to validate the method, and we'll see what we can learn from it.

Even if we don't get the validation of the data that we expect, we're going to have learned a *heck* of a lot and we'll have many sets of data that have been human reviewed that can be used to test other models.

*If* things look promising, we'll then run Stack Overflow data through it, and open it up for validation. We do not want to do that initially because it essentially means analyzing every single question asked since the dawn of the site and putting folks to a pretty big task. While there's some value in doing it just to have the sets, we'd like a bit more confidence before investing that much time.

Later this week, or early next, I'll be posting something on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) to let folks know when the project is going to kick off, how they can help, what kinds of ideas we're looking to add, and what's in scope to get things started. There's some big stuff, but the majority of it is lots and lots of small things that could make a pretty big difference.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this was a thing. I was actually working on figuring out a way to model the data that could demonstrate the most common duplicates not being marked as duplicate. Glad to know StackExchange is on top of this then. I'd love to see what the results are and any further reading on the modeling is of great interest to me.

Comment: I take it you'll be writing a separate post about this duplicate testing

Comment: Tim, do you plan to do _anything_ this Fall with regards to [increasing amount or impact of close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281818/165773)? Do you intend to focus solely on duplicate questions and ignore the rest of close worthy ones this Fall?

Comment: @gnat That's something we're currently considering, yes. It's going to be on the list of things we want to talk about. While we want to avoid putting even more responsibility on the shoulders of few, we also want the few to be able to be more effective with the amount of time they're willing to give. If we can strike a balance there, I think we can do it.

Comment: @Yvette That'll be a blog post, actually.

Comment: sounds good, thanks. Wonder if [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281985/165773) is on the radar? it's not so much about getting more questions closed but more about decreasing frustration of active users: "so long as somebody is (a) voting well and (b) bumping up against the limit, gradually raise the limit. If those votes aren't being used well, reset. (Possibly also start aging away the extras if they aren't being used...)"

Comment: "*Better ways of filtering out noise: Let's come up with better ways of not showing total noise to our most engaged and knowledgeable users until we can better determine that there's some signal in there to mine.*" This is a bad idea. If you can determine that something truly is noise, it *shouldn't be here*. If you have an automatic filter that is that good, then it ought to be applied to users post when they post them, not to users reading what has been posted. Noise is noise, for both the experienced and the inexperienced alike. ***We do not want noise on the site!***

Comment: @NicolBolas I think that battle's been lost. SO (the company) is just not going to risk scaring off the bulk of its user base. As Your Common Sense [said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251897/176646), "Traffic is the king, and while it flows, nobody cares about such trifle matters like answer quality."

Comment: @NicolBolas The problem is, we can't _truly_ determine what's _not_ just noise. Going to be running some numbers soon on the efficacy of the helper queue from three months after it was launched until now in order get a better idea of how accurately _humans_ can separate wheat from chaff, which gives us a more realistic goal of what automated things could be doing (a fraction of the accuracy humans achieve is likely). But not putting 'undecided' stuff in the faces of folks that have clearly expressed disinterest in seeing it _is_ in the realm of possibility, so we're looking at it.

Comment: "**Better ways of filtering out noise**", hmm, sounds a bit like [Allow users to optionally filter out low-quality questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions) and [Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage, phase 1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261138/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-1). ;) I might suggest going back to those two discussions, they seemed to provide a decent amount of feedback.

Comment: @hichris123 I think that is better to reject them outright. Why allow something if you aren't going to show it to anyone?

Comment: @Braiam There's a state in which it's unknown if something should be rejected (some questions pass through the help & improvement queue two or three times, then go on to do very well). Essentially, we want to allow a filter for 'show me only _known_ good, as of this moment'. It's in a _different_ scope to do better about ensuring that the input is better overall, and the parts going into that are still being fleshed out.

Comment: @TimPost Am I missing something, or is this announcement not out yet? (As it's already being 2 weeks)

Comment: "Since I'm about to get a little windy, here's a tl;dr; of the first things we hope to focus on:" Almost 6 years later, I'm not really convinced that anything ever came of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but my answer will definitely NOT be as high quality as the question is.

The trend you are noticing is not limited to PHP tag alone. Other tags suffer the same and the change in quality affects both the questions and the answers.

There are multiple reasons for that, here's a few:

1. The truly-generic questions got asked in the mature tags. Such questions & their respective answers get the most hits from search engines as well and are as a result getting the most upvotes. If you repeat your statistical analysis in a while, you will see that numbers for "older" questions moved up more than the ones for the newer questions.
2. Newer questions being asked are more specific, problem bound, simply because the generic questions have (all) been asked. There are still some being asked about a currently-popular library and are getting upvotes, but generally they don't get the upvotes simply because the audience for the question is much more limited than audience for a question dealing with a basic tag technique.
3. If you adjust your statistical analysis to separate the grain questions from the chaff questions - and adjust that with users in a tag - you will see that chaff percentage in php tag does not significantly deviate from its percentage for the other tags.
4. Continuing with grain vs chaff debate, the general upwards trend in chaff questions is a direct result of (mostly) two factors:

   4.1. - SO has become the primary source of help for pretty much everyone in programming nowadays (increasing user count significantly)

   4.2. - SO's policies allow for such questions and perhaps even encourage them. I'd venture to say that search engines take votes into account when ranking results and generally tend to link the higher-quality questions, resulting in "all being good".
5. Sometimes, it's not the question, but the answer that spoils everything. My experience shows that it used to be "easy" to answer a question, today it's not: in our quest for reputation, we write shorter, less detailed, less fact-based answers (such as this one, perhaps?). I used to go check out the new questions and for the larger part, first page still had no answers. Today, even the newest questions already have answers even when all they should have received is duplicate & close votes.

In summary, I don't think php tag is alone suffering from your conclusions. Even if it compares poorly to other popular tags, that's maybe because it has many new students learning it? Or maybe because it has a steep(er) learning curve.

Comment: PHP definitely doesn't have a *steeper* curve than C++ or Python. If anything, I would expect a lower bar-to-entry would induce worse questions. Set the bar too high and you get no questions at all. Set the bar too lower and get too many questions. Set the bar just right and you tend to find a sweet spot of good questions and good answers.