# Homework statistics

Tags: discussion, homework

This is more a curiosity question.
In the last few years that I've been member I've seen the same trend every year.

Summer ends, and the basic questions start to pour in.
Autumn progresses and the object access questions pour in.
Winter is coming and array permutations start to take hold.

So I'm kinda thinking this is the trend at schools how the classes progress.

Are there any statistics we can couple on this? so we can kinda follow the teaching trends (framework/languages/aspects taught) how such a classes in general, or per region (North America, Europe, Asia, etc..) progress through the year?

I would think one limiting factor could be questions asked by users < 500 rep with account created less than one year ago on moment question asked.

Other limiting factors could be the variables mentioned in [Why is the quality of PHP questions, on Stack Overflow, in decline?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334267/why-is-the-quality-of-php-questions-on-stack-overflow-in-decline?rq=1)

Does anyone else have any other suggestions how we could limit some data to get some sort of tentative insight?

Comment: _Winter is coming_ How very game of thronesy. I don't think you'd be able to get any _good_ statistics on this, as how would you know if the question is actually homework or not?

Comment: Well the thing is, since homework tag suggestions are categorically downvoted, we can't use that. maybe date of creation(less than a year) ago, so we can catch first years. But personally i'd be interested in what is taught at schools world wide, where focus lies, how it changes through the years. There should be trends spottable that return every year. but it might require some serious crunching.

Comment: Maybe also the variables mentioned in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334267/why-is-the-quality-of-php-questions-on-stack-overflow-in-decline?rq=1 can be used as limiting factors.

Comment: Maybe you can use [Stack Overflow Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends) for some relevant information?

Comment: I just want to know when the dragons are going to show up.

Comment: They don't teach dragons any more, banned for safety reasons

Comment: Homework questions tend to get deleted so might be awkward to calculate this data. Also, assuming it's possible, what do you think we could actually do about the results?

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September

Comment: If this is for research on that topic I would rather go the inverse. Look at what schools teach, based on that develop a hypothesis (like "in november we should see an unusual amount of questions asking for ___") and then try to falsify this using the search engine or database queries.

Comment: This is not so much for research, but more for curiosities sake. I've seen the ebb and tide of the homework questions coming and going each year, and this kinda grew into my  mind as "that would be cool to know". So it's more curiosity and is it überhaubt possible to kinda glean that data from the massive amounts of data stack overflow has @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: A homework tag would've been useful here (alas, it was burninated).

Answer (score 2):

Some potential uses for this data:

- Could inform the meta discussion on how to ensure higher quality questions (by analyzing how these 'students'/first years ask their questions - I'd assume folks are already doing similar analysis though)
- Could inform teachers on more effective orders they can teach subjects  (if you can establish some sort of linearity on certain users - e.g. *JohnSnow666* first asks about this, then that, then that, and his questions get better/worse)
- Could be further used to discover 'most effective' answers for common problems, which the community could cite and teachers could use in their courses

see @zwol 's answer to: [Please clarify the policy on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions) 
describing how hard it is to create an answer that will teach, not just answer.

Comment: I take some umbrage to your last line.  It's less about your answer and more about their receptiveness to the answer that determines if they've actually been taught anything.

Comment: @Makoto I definitely agree with that as far as the effectiveness of the whole teaching process - but, if the material isn't there, receptiveness can only do so much (but it can overcome quite a lot, even if the material is sparse)

Comment: I think it's both the student and the teacher in nearly equal portions that determine the efficacy of an answer in teaching something. A good student can manage to learn from a poor teacher, and a poor student can still earn from a great teacher, sure, but on average you need both the student and the teacher to be more or less engaged in the effort.