# Majority of PHP questions downvoted or dupes

Tags: discussion

I'm relatively new to answering questions on SO (been answering PHP questions on another forum for years), and I was noticing a pretty consistent trend in the PHP-tagged questions on here. Almost every one of them is down-voted, even when the question is clear. It also seems like people are eager to try to close questions as duplicates. A few of the dupe-flags have just been pretty broad. For example, someone asks, "I have a specific question about XYZ" and their question gets immediately flagged as a duplicate of "Broad answers about XYZ", even if the "Broad answers..." doesn't really address the specific question.

Granted, not all of the questions are mind-blowing, trailblazing questions that nobody has ever asked before, but the general sentiment seems to be very hostile towards those who ask questions. The down-votes basically say, "Your question is stupid," and the quick-to-flag-as-dupe behavior is sort of like calling a 1-800 number and being pushed through an automated system tries to answer common questions but frustrates the daylights out of people whose question has to reach a human for a good answer.

In the long run, it ends up being a negative, sticky joke on the site's reputation (Person 1: "I should go ask this on StackOverflow..." Person 2: "You mean DupeOverflow?") that can be a killing disease.

I did a query on data on the past 2 weeks of PHP questions and there's a nearly-consistent 2:1 ratio between downvotes to upvotes.

I did read this question from a year ago:
[Why is the quality of PHP questions, on Stack Overflow, in decline?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334267/why-is-the-quality-of-php-questions-on-stack-overflow-in-decline)

...and it just seems like a legitimate observation that got written off. A year later, the problem continues and it makes me wonder if this is just going to be the norm and I should just get used to being the person that still tries to answer questions flagged as dupes. Should I try to upvote "okay" questions to counter the more hostile trends?

Is it just that people don't want to help others fix syntax questions?

What would the ideal PHP tag zone look like if you (whomever is reading this) had your way?

Comment: _"Is it just that people don't want to help others fix syntax questions?"_ Certainly not.

Comment: And that said as a PHP developer dismayed by the general quality of the tag.

Comment: A ratio of 2:1 of downvotes:upvotes doesn't seem extreme at all. If anything, a too generous ratio.

Comment: i mean... a dupe is a dupe. If it's a dupe, closing it as such is good. It doesn't need to be re-answered over and over.

Comment: @yivi It seems pretty extreme to me.  I see way more than 2 bad questions for every good one.

Comment: "(Person 1: "I should go ask this on StackOverflow..." Person 2: "You mean DupeOverflow?")" Yeah, and that's because those people are doing it wrong.  They should be saying, "You should go find an existing answer to this problem on Google" not, "Go ask that question on SO without even doing your research first", then you'll get a response of, "I found the solution in this Stack Overflow question" rather than, "Someone closed my question as a duplicate of a question that has a solution to my problem because I didn't bother to search for it first."

Comment: You've got many misconceptions going on in this question...

Comment: see also: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Comment: I reject many of your premises.

Comment: "Should I try to upvote 'okay' questions to counter the more hostile trends?"  You should upvote quality questions that meet the site's standards, are on topic, well researched, clear, will be useful to the programming community at large, etc.  You shouldn't upvote question that *don't* meet those criteria just because other people have correctly identified that the question doesn't meet those criteria.  Also note that indicating that a question is not well researched, useful, clear, on topic, etc. is *not* hostile.  It's *extremely* helpful.  You saying that it's hostile, is hostile.

Comment: More [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-using-an-up-vote-to-balance-out-a-down-vote-wrong) on @Servy's comment..

Comment: A downvote most emphatically does *not* mean "your question is stupid".

Comment: This... it's like a suspension honeypot for me.  I dare not try to make any useful contribution:(

Comment: I feel like "DupeOverflow" would be a compliment -- It means we have so many useful questions on Stack Overflow that it's hard to have a question that you can't find the answer to here already.

Comment: I'm not seeing exactly what you claim irt to your [stats](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/783505).

Comment: Interesting. So not only did my question get 3 downvotes, but it got marked as a duplicate of a very loosely-related question that's not really a true duplicate.

Comment: When I say that a downvote says that a question is stupid, perhaps that's not the technical intention and it might not seem like that to veteran users - I'm just saying that's how it's perceived by a relatively new user.

Comment: The suggested duplicate appears to answer "Is it just that people don't want to help others fix syntax questions?". The downvotes are also natural, because the community disagrees with many of your statements and perspectives on the matter.

Comment: I'm confused on your post - on one hand you link to "quality of PHP questions is low" but you seem to propose to upvote more questions presumably to improve quality of posts that way... Not really sure what you want...

Comment: @E_net4 - Exactly - the suggested duplicate answers one particular facet of a discussion, but that's not really an accurate duplicate of the question as a whole. Perhaps it's a semantics issue - the usage of the term "duplicate" rather than "related".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I disagree with the premise that the quality of the questions are low. The linked-to question was simply related information. I think there are legitimate questions that seem to be down-voted, presumably because they're just too basic.

Comment: @jhilgeman That of course points out a major problem with your question.  You're asking a bunch of different unrelated questions.  That's not how SO works.  You're expected to ask a *single* question, among other reasons, so that when there's a duplicate it can be closed as such.  Trying to avoid having your questions closed as a duplicate by just smashing 5 different duplicate questions into one is not helpful.

Comment: @Servy - When I talk about hostility, I'm talking about the general perception from a relatively new user. I think that "well researched" and "will be useful to the programming community" are pretty subjective concepts. If everyone researched their question enough, they'd answer every single question themselves and would never ask a question on SO. They'd read books and find all of their answers elsewhere. Is usefulness to the programming community the key goal?

Comment: @Servy - This particular discussion isn't intended to be one specific question, hence the "discussion" tag. I'm not comparing this question to the PHP questions I'm referring to.

Comment: @jhilgeman Not all questions have answers that can be found by the question author doing their research.  Lots of them can.  *Lots*.  Those questions are bad questions, and we don't want them here.  But yes, whether or not a question can be found with a reasonable amount of research effort is indeed subjective, as is whether a question would be useful.  Votes are subjective.  "Is usefulness to the programming community the key goal?" Yes, it is.  As for hostility, you didn't say, "votes cast will good intentions that are erroneously perceived as hostile by the post author".

Comment: @jhilgeman "This particular discussion isn't intended to be one specific question" Yes, and  *that's part of what makes it a bad question*.  That you *intended* it to be a bad question doesn't change that.  It makes it worse, in fact.

Comment: @Servy - I assumed that the point of a discussion on meta was to be open - to have a broader context versus being an individual question that might miss out related context.

Comment: @jhilgeman You can add context for why you're choosing to ask your question (and it's very often helpful), but you still need to be asking one specific question.  It's no more appropriate to ask a bunch of different questions, or to not ask a specific question at all, than it is on main.

Comment: Okay, well if everyone disagrees with my premises, let's just delete the question, ignore it and move on.

Comment: @jhilgeman :) you really should not ask for discussion if you only accept the case when everyone agrees with you... There are other sites which don't support disagreement - SO is not one of them.

Comment: @rene - Regarding stats, adjust the timeframe in your query. The closer you get to today, the more downvotes there are.

Comment: @Alexei - I'm suggesting that if I'm so wrong (everyone seems to disagree with my premises and thus downvotes the question), then having this question exist seems to contradict the goals stated here, so the question should be deleted. It's not about expecting everyone to agree with me. Everyone's been saying don't take downvotes personally, and that's exactly the guidance I'm following - I'm not taking it personally and suggesting that it be deleted for the sake of the site.

Comment: You do not need to delete anything _"for the sake of the site"_. It can take, (and did take, and will take) plenty contrasting opinions. Yours is in the minority, but **someone** is always in the minority. I tried to address most of the points raised in your "question" in my answer, but didn't get any feedback from you there, so I'm not sure what to think of that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> The down-votes basically say, "Your question is stupid,"

No, they do not say that. Although in many times the question does look a bit on the stupid side, the downvote simply means that the voter found that the question "lacked research effort, was unclear, or was not 'useful'".

The perceived hostility is not there. You may not like being downvoted, but it is not an aggression.

**I don't like to be downvoted either**. But it happens. If we didn't want downvotes, we'd only have an upwards pointing arrow. That wouldn't be too useful in the long term.

> and the quick-to-flag-as-dupe behavior is sort of like calling a 1-800 number and being pushed through an automated system tries to answer common questions but frustrates the daylights out of people whose question has to reach a human for a good answer.

"Quick-to-close" is how we try to keep the site useful and relevant. The reason people do come as often as they do to Stack Overflow, is because of the tight focus on topicality and quality control.

And while asking a dupe is not *necessarily* a bad thing, many dupes can be a bit too much. When you paste the title of the question in Google and find the target of the dupe in 2''... is rather depressing.

> I did a query on data on the past 2 weeks of PHP questions and there's a nearly-consistent 2:1 ratio between downvotes to upvotes.

This is a matter of opinion, but I think that if you browse the site and try to look critically at our content, you'll see there are many more bad questions (poorly researched, stated, with the wrong problem barely described, etc) than good questions. A 2 to 1 ratio doesn't seem extreme at all. In my opinion, it looks too generous.

> Is it just that people don't want to help others fix syntax questions?

No, we do not want that. At all. Good questions shouldn't be about fixing syntax errors. IDEs, interpreters, debuggers are for that. And for those questions that come around about syntax errors... we have a close reason in waiting.

> Majority of PHP questions downvoted or dupes

And finally, addressing the specific [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag part, which is the only thing that differentiate your post from many others complaining about down-votes and closures...

I imagine that this title could apply to almost any tag. Good quality, on-topic questions are in the minority. But if that were not the case, the quality control mechanics of Stack Overflow wouldn't make much sense.

It is true that the case might be more acute for this tag than for some others, but I reckon something similar occurs in other places around the site. Very popular tags for languages with a shallow learning curve can be like that.

Ideally, the only way I'd like to see less down-votes and close votes/flags would be if the quality on the tag went way up. But the quality on the site kinda reflects what you'd find out there. It's not so easy to find great developers on any technology, and in one so forgiving with beginners it can sometimes feel even harder.

For me, the *fix*, as much as something like this can be fixed, would be going exactly in the opposite direction than what you propose, and be extra vigilant in quality control. Which means: close down more questions, down-vote more posts.

With that, we'd be doing our part in pushing upwards the existing talent pool in the language. And hopefully leaving markers for the developers of tomorrow to learn from, hopefully improving the whole PHP ecosystem in the process.

It can feel like a losing battle, most of the time. But we have to try. Despite the rep PHP has, there **are** competent developers doing great work with the language and technology. At least I think so.

Comment: *You may not like being downvoted, but it is not an aggression.*  .... can't we blame facebook for that?

Comment: [There are no stupid questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question)... Except on Stack Overflow

Comment: ["downvotes are taken so damn personal..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601)

Comment: @rene we should certainly try.

Comment: I think the perception is definitely linked to what rene said about Facebook. I think other sites like FB have created an "attacking" perception that is linked to downvotes. To be clear, I'm not saying that downvotes ARE hostile but rather that they carry that perception. And why shouldn't they be taken personally? There's rarely ever feedback that explains the downvotes, which is behavior encouraged by "When is it justifiable to downvote a question?" that tells people to simply "downvote and move on", leaving askers feeling like their request for help has been rejected without explanation.

Comment: If downvotes were required to have some explanation (a sub-click that explained the downvote as "Lacking sufficient explanation", etc...), it seems like that would at least add a consistent level of feedback for the askers.

Comment: @jhilgeman And now you are entering a whole different discussion, one that we had many, many, many, many times. Read around in meta, you'll find the posts. There even is canonical question for this subject. But try to focus on **one** issue. You are misinterpreting the use of the `discussion` tag. Since you want to give you opinion on how the site _should_ work, you should first try to familiarize with its rules and customs.

Comment: @yivi - I'm just responding to the comments being said.

Comment: @jhilgeman what's funny here is that 'unjustified' downvotes feel hostile to the new users. However explaining your downvotes to new users will, more often than not, turn the situation into a hostile one... for the downvoter :(.

Comment: @Patrice - Why would it be any more hostile to the downvoter than now? It would literally be a second click. Click once on the downvote arrow, then a pop-up comes up to indicate the general category of reasoning, and you click on the appropriate category. The asker simply sees a breakdown of reasons that helps them know how to improve their question. It allows downvoters to "downvote and move on" AND provide valuable aggregate feedback with a simple click.

Comment: @jhilgeman I am not talking about that proposal, which again is a whole different discussion. I am saying that NOW, if a downvoter explains his downvote, he usually gets abused by the downvotee.

Comment: All the more reason to support that proposal.

Comment: @jhilgeman if you want to support that proposal, please find one of the many variants and add your two bits there, instead of here. Here not only is irrelevant, since the discussion was about something else, but every time you add a comment to my answer I get pinged. Thanks for your understanding! :)

Comment: @jhilgeman actually, not really. Amidst all the abuse I realized another thing (back when I was sill fooli.... optimistic enough to comment on every  downvote) that, frankly,  the majority of new users do NOT want to improve. They want their answers nao! They got used to visiting stack and getting answers. So THEIR question now should be answered. Call me cynical but I don't think the time to implement this would be worth the very minimal of people it would help. In any case, yivi's point is 100% true too

Comment: @Patrice - First, I'm not even talking about commenting. Maybe a better way to think about this is simply a couple of different downvote buttons (one for "not enough info", etc...) - so no commenting needed.

As it stands, there's NO feedback at all, and I reject the premise that "the majority of new users do not want to improve". I don't know how you could possibly know that unless you've performed a valid study of new users that were actually challenged to improve. I'd suggest that the users who responded negatively probably hold more focus in your memories.

Comment: And as I was reading through other meta posts on this topic this afternoon, it seems like this is one of the most-discussed feature requests out there. It keeps coming up again and again (which is an indicator of how many people actually WANT the feedback) but apparently people keep rejecting it. Honestly, I don't even care anymore. There's such a stigma on this topic that nothing's going to change unless some other Q&A site becomes large enough to threaten SO's popularity.

Comment: You reject tge premise? Fine @jhilgeman. I challenge you to get REALLY active in moderation then. Downvote, closevote, comment on EVERY ACTION and explain why. I was doing that a while back. Of course it isn't a study. But when you've done this for long enough, you get a good ideaof the willingness of new users. And one thing you wiill also notice if you scour meta: a lot of these requests for feedback are just 'plz upvote my stuff' in disguise. Often on meta people GET the feedback they want, and keep complaining and fight back EVERYTHING, without changing squat.

Comment: And again, I won't address your proposal here. Go back and answer/edit/get activity again on one of the many many many dupes. That's how stack should work :) (btw this is why I m not addressing thw 'I am not talking about commenting'. Frankly doing it anonymously is probably the version of this proposal I can somewhat get. I don't necessarily believe it'll do MUCH good. But out of all the 'plz comment on downvotes', this is the one that actually makes some sense to me)

Comment: @Patrice - I've been active on various code Q&A sites for nearly 2 decades. I've provided the same comments/answers thousands of times to different people. Some wanted to get better and some wanted an easy fix. It's impossible to say what kind of person the next user is going to be, but I always provide as much beneficial commentary as possible in case they (or the next person that reads the discussion) are the "improving" kind. I will say that if I can help one person improve (even if I never hear from them again), then it's worth wasting my words on 10 "easy fix" people. But that's just me.

Comment: @jhilgeman Now please try it on Stack too. I've also navigated my share of Q &A sites (can't say I have 2 decades really, but eventually I'll get there), and honestly nothing gets quite as gruesome as how stack new users react. I grew more cynical so the 1 in 10 ratio now both feels 1) too high considering what I used to get as pushbacks/apathy 2)something I wouldn't be willing to subject myself to such abuse to reach the one person. Is it unfortunate? 100%. Would an anonymous way to leave feedback help? Maybe. I am just unsure of HOW helpful and fear it wouldn't be much

Comment: I'm working on it. Perhaps it's just the newer generation of kids feeling entitled or something. Whatever the case, we'll see how it pans out.